# Can I use vector in a map in STL?

Tags: c++, stl

Can I declare a map like this

```
map<string, vector<string>> mymap;
```

I thought it is applicable.

However, it shows not.

I tried

```
map<string, vector<string>*> mymap;
```

and then it is OK

What's the rule of this?

Answer (score 17):

You need an extra space:

```
map<string, vector<string> > mymap;
                          ^ see the extra space
```

Without the extra space, the `>>` gets parsed as the right shift operator.

The rules have been modified in C++0x, making the extra space unnecessary.  Some compilers (e.g., Visual C++ 2008 and above) already do not require the extra space.

Comment: g++ gives this nice error: `'>>' should be '> >' within a nested template argument list`

Comment: Actually, it's `std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::string> >`, but I realize I'm on a lost crusade here.

Comment: @sbi : while we're being pedantic, how do you know it's `std::`?  Maybe he wrote his own.  Or maybe he has `using namespace std;` or even `using std::string;` and `using std::map;` ;)  Out of curiosity, why 'crusade' for the qualification?

Comment: @Stephen: Someone who fails at the famous (and, admittedly, embarrassing) `>>` of nested templates will not have written their own C++ container matching those of the std lib. (And God help us if they had.) As for `using namespace std`, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2879555/2880136#2880136).

Comment: @sbi : Yes, I was just giving you a hard time ;)  Thanks for the link, the arguments are good.

Answer (score 9):

You can, as James mentioned.  Stupid c++ parsing :)

However, `map<string, vector<string> >` is effectively a 
`multimap<string, string>`.  A [multimap](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Multimap.html) maps a key to multiple values.  It might be more convenient or more efficient, depending on your use case.