# question on string iterators

Tags: c++

I have following code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main(){
  string d="georgia is nice country":
  string::iterator my;
  for (my=d.begin();my!=d.end();my++) {
    cout<<*my<<endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

but it causes a compiler error saying "my is undefined". What is wrong?

Comment: `using namespace std;` This is saving you to type five characters every time you type an identifier from the standard library. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2879555/c-stl-how-to-write-wrappers-for-cout-cerr-cin-and-endl/2880136#2880136) for why this is _not_ a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put a semicolon instead of a colon after the string.

```
string d="georgia is nice country"; // <-- semicolon!
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string d="georgia is nice country"; // <-- semicolon, not colon
```

Comment: I thought for a moment there you were saying georgia is not a nice country.

Comment: just  here is a little poor live  bit everything will be ok  soon