# C++: declaring a class with functions, that handle string

Tags: c++, class, declaration, definition

I haven`t found answer to my question using search, though I thought it is simple and popular. Anyway, my question is:
I have got a header file, which declares a class and functions in it. It looks like that:

```
#ifndef SOME_CLASS_H
#define SOME_CLASS_H

#include <string>

class mySomeClass
{
    public:

    bool a_func(string & myString, unsigned long int & x);
    void b_func(string & myString, unsigned long int & x);
    void c_func(string & myString, unsigned long int & x);

    void another_func(string & myString, string & myString2);

    }

#endif // SOME_CLASS_H
```

I think function definitions do not actually matter now.

When compiling, compiler tells that *'string' has not been declared*, even though I have added `#include <string>` . How can I solve this except for rewriting functions to use `char*` instead. Thank you in advance.

Done. Thanks everybody.

Comment: Unless the functions really modify the strings, you should declare the parameters as `const std::string &`. That allows you to call them with string literals.

Comment: There's also no need to pass native types, like ints, as reference unless you plan to modify them in the function.

Comment: @Pontus and @DanDan are absolutely right. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139224/how-to-pass-objects-to-functions-in-c/2139254#2139254) for a set of rules of thumb for to passing function arguments in C++.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`string` is declared in the namespace `std`, so you have to change the function declarations to

```
bool a_func(std::string & myString, unsigned long int & x);
```

Answer (score 10):

Problem: the `string` class resides in namespace `std`.

Solutions:

1. Best solution: simply use `std::string` instead of
   `string` in your function declarations.
2. Another, less optimal solution: add `using namespace std;` after the
   include directive (for an explanation of the drawbacks/dangers of `using`, see the link in sbi's comment).

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2879555/c-stl-how-to-write-wrappers-for-cout-cerr-cin-and-endl/2880136#2880136) for why I don't think `using namespace std` is a good idea.

Comment: @sbi: you're absolutely right, edited to reflect that `using` in a header is bad practice.

Comment: I only use `using std::something;` in a cpp file, safest thing to do. I leave the prefixes in all headers.

Comment: Oh, and in the topic of `using namespace std;`. I am using QT combined with standart C++ (I actually prefer standart `fstream`, maybe I will get used to QT`s stuff later). So, when I include `fstream`, on compiliation I get an error that it says:
`expected unqualified-id before 'namespace'` on iostream`s on 43`rd line (if I include both `iostream` and `fstream`) or the same error on codecvt.h 42`nd line (if I only include `fstream`). So am I forced to use QT`s stuff, or I still ould get fstream working?

Comment: @EdgeLuxe: Well, iostreams certainly work for us, so you must be doing something wrong. You might want to boil this down to 20 lines and post it as a new question so that we can look at it.

Answer (score 3):

The type `string` that you're willing to use is declared in a namespace called `std`.

Use `std::string`

Answer (score 3):

The type defined in <string> is called std::string, not just string.

```
#ifndef SOME_CLASS_H 
#define SOME_CLASS_H 

#include <string> 

class mySomeClass 
{ 
    public: 

    bool a_func(std::string & myString, unsigned long int & x); 
    void b_func(std::string & myString, unsigned long int & x); 
    void c_func(std::string & myString, unsigned long int & x); 

    void another_func(std::string & myString, std::string & myString2); 

    } 

#endif // SOME_CLASS_H
```

Answer (score -2):

put

```
using namespace std
```

under

```
#include <string>
```

Comment: Almost 15mins before you posted your answer, I commented to [Greg's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3307866/c-declaring-a-class-with-functions-that-handle-string/3307877#3307877) why I think that's a bad idea.

Comment: -1 It is a bad habit to have namespace-level `using` directives in header files. Additionally your code is broken...(you are missing a semicolon).