# C++ can't create vector

Tags: c++, vector

This is weird. I created a vector just fine in one class but can't create it in another class. He's a representation of what I have:

***main.h***

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <ShellAPI.h>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

#include "taco.h"

class MyClass
{

public:
    int someint;
    vector<int> myOrder;
};
```

***taco.h***

```
#include <vector>

class OtherClass
{

public:
    vector<int> otherOrder;
};
```

And I get compile errors regarding the vector declaration in taco.h:

```
error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'
error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
```

What am I missing here? I can uncomment out that second vector declaration and it compiles fine.

Comment: This suggests to me that some .h file has `using namespace std;` in it somewhere, which is generally a Bad Idea.  `using` should never be done in headers, as it messes up namespaces for any .cpp file that directly or indirectly includes that header.  Leave `using` for the source files only, where the effects are local.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try:

```
std::vector<int> otherOrder;
```

`vector` is part of the `std` namespace.  This means that whenever you use a `vector` in a header file, you should include the `std::` prefix.

The reason that you can sometimes get away with forgetting it is that some included files may have `using namespace std;` in them, allowing you to leave off the prefix.  However, you should avoid the `using` keyword in header files, for it will pollute the namespace of any files that `include` it.

For a more detailed explanation of the dangers of `using namespace ...`, see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265039/using-std-namespace).

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2879555/c-stl-how-to-write-wrappers-for-cout-cerr-cin-and-endl/2880136#2880136) is another argument against `using namespace std`.

Comment: Hmmm for some reason I thought my "using namespace std" in main.h would cascade down to taco.h. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @Jakobud: If you had the reverse (`using namespace std;` in `taco.h` but not `main.h`), it would.  The only way for it to "cascade" is through `#include`.

Answer (score 4):

Try `std::vector<int>`. You're supposed to use the namespace --- I'm assuming you have

```
using namespace std;
```

in the `main.h` someplace. There's a lot of talk on SO as to why using `using` is bad practice ; I'd recommend that you check it out.

Answer (score 4):

All C++ standard library objects live in the `std` namespace. Try

```
class MyClass
{

public:
    int someint;
    std::vector<int> myOrder;
//  ^^^^^
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
std::vector<int> ?
```