# Implement complex number's class in C++

Tags: c++

Here I am trying to implement a class for complex numbers using books and the Internet. Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
using namespace std;
class  Complex{
    private:
        float re,im;

    public:
        Complex(float x,float y){
            re=x;
            im=y;
        }

        float Re() const{
            re;
        }

        float Im() const {
            return  im;
        }

        Complex&  operator*=(const Complex& rhs){
            float t=Re();
            re = Re()*rhs.Re()-Im()*rhs.Im();

            im = t*rhs.Im()+Im()*rhs.Re();
            return *this;
        }
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream& t,const Complex& c){
    t << c.Re() << " " << c.Im(); 
    return t;
}

int main(){
    Complex s(3.45,23.12);
    return 0;
}
```

It compiles fine, but I can't find a way to print the real and imaginary parts of the number on the screen?

Comment: In main, just before you return, put "cout << s << '\n';".  std::cout is the "standard output" / terminal / screen / tty device.  '\n' represents a newline, saying the line is complete and please move to the next one.  It's always best to end your output with a newline, so some other program that moves the cursor back to the start of the line doesn't overwrite and hide it (UNIX/Linux shells tend to do this).

Comment: Did you take a look at `std::complex` ?

Comment: @Ian: There's an `operator<<()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>

// ...

Complex s(3.45,23.12);
std::cout << s;
```

See **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2879555/c-stl-how-to-write-wrappers-for-cout-cerr-cin-and-endl/2880136#2880136)** for why I think `using namespace std;` is a bad idea.

Also, I suppose implementing a class for complex numbers is an exercise? Because the standard library already has one.

Answer (score 0):

See the header `<complex>` which implements `std::complex`… which you might want to use, unless you want to implement this as an exercise.

Here is [a link](http://espec.ppgia.pucpr.br/doc/gnu/libstdc++/complex-source.html) to the GCC header file; all the basic operations are pretty simply implemented.

As for printing on screen, what is going wrong? Your `operator<<` looks fine.

Comment: That task is very likely an exercise in implementing your own class.

Answer (score 0):

The solution above will work. I would however change the << implementation to be the following  to get a more readable output (if that's what you want):

```
t<<c.Re()<< "  + i"<<c.Im(); return t;
```

In my opinion, this will show the representation in a clearer way.

Comment: 2 things: I would the `i` after the imaginary part and I would use only one statement.