# Are there any real cases proving that 'sizeof...' is necessary?

Tags: c++, c++11, keyword, sizeof, variadic-templates

I wonder about the advantages of the new operator `sizeof...` (not to be confused with the `sizeof` operator). I searched the web and found a few examples that seem all like the following one:

```
template<class... ArgTypes>
std::size_t GetLength()
{
    return sizeof...(ArgTypes);
}
```

I think the examples are not illustrative.

Are there any real examples to illustrate that `sizeof...` is very useful?

**Updates:**

I found another examples from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3651499/read-arguments-from-variadic-template) that seem more meaningful:

```
template<class ...A> void func(A ...args){
   typedef typename common_type<A...>::type common;
   std::array<common, sizeof...(A)> a = {{ args... }};
}

template<typename... A> int func(const A&... args)
{
  boost::any arr[sizeof...(A)] = { args... };
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I use it all the time...

Comment: @KerrekSB how? I didn't know such a thing even existed.

Comment: @Kerrek, could you give me some convincing examples? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `sizeof...(T)` provides actual functionality. Sure it can be implemented with the rest of the language, and look like `size_of<T...>()` but having it built-in does not hurt (it gives opportunity for better performance and adds no new keywords)

Comment: It's of such a common use that they actually provided a keyword for doing something that is easily done with trivial template metaprogramming. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14261183/how-to-make-generic-computations-over-heterogeneous-argument-packs-of-a-variadic) is a use case, but you could find zillions.

Comment: I am confused as to what your "more" is referring to. more elegant than what? more expressive than what? The only other way to count the number of elements in a parameter pack I know is a recursive metafunction...

Comment: More concise, more elegent, and more expressive than what? As far as I know, it's the only sensible way to get the number of arguments in a variadic pack. Or are you asking why you might want to know the size at all?

Comment: @AndyProwl "trivial template metaprogramming" lol

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: `sizeof...`? You kidding me :D

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: Just look at any kind of variadic index-expanding code. Anything that takes a pack and does like a for-each or `get<I>...` thing....

Comment: Not everyone uses variadic templates...

Comment: @PlasmaHH, for example, there are two methods to do the same thing, A is with 'sizeof...', B is without 'sizeof...'. If B is obviously more complicated and tedious than A, then we can say A is more concise, more elegant, and more expressive than B.

Comment: @xmllmx: Well, the question is what are those A and B for you. I would say sizeof... and a template metafunction. And for me the metafunction is obviously much more work. So since this is obviously not obvious for you, I am wondering what your B is...

Comment: The question needs clarification IMO. What would you expect to be offered *instead* of `sizeof...`?

Comment: @NikosC. `template<typename... Ts> struct sizeer{enum{value=0};}; template<typename T, typename... Ts> struct sizer<T, Ts...>{enum{value=1+sizer<Ts...>::value};};`, with similar ones for various types, is what I'd expect to use instead of `sizeof...` if it didn't exist.  Note that it requires an O(N) recursion depth to find the size of a list of N parameters, while `sizeof...` does it in O(1) depth.  As for a use of `sizeof...`, whenever you want to build an indexing to shove variardic parameters into a tuple or extract same you end up using it.

Comment: Major reasons 1) it is readable. 2) it is more efficient than alternatives (compiling speed). Example ... you want to raise compile time noise when sizeof...(X) > 42. What you do?

Comment: Here is [an example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15014171/596781)...

Answer (score 4):

Here is my example of what you can do with `sizeof...`:

```
/// Transform a single boolean value into a number
constexpr unsigned int boolCode(bool value) {
    return value;
}

/// Transform a sequence of booleans into a number
template <typename... Args>
constexpr unsigned int boolCode(bool value, Args... others) {
    return value << sizeof...(others) | boolCode(others...);
}
```

And this handy function could be used in a switch statement, like this:

```
switch (boolCode(condition1, condition2, condition3)) {
case boolCode(false,false,false): //...
case boolCode(false,false,true): //...
case boolCode(false,true,false): //...
case boolCode(false,true,true): //...
case boolCode(true,false,false): //...
case boolCode(true,false,true): //...
case boolCode(true,true,false): //...
case boolCode(true,true,true): //...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you probably want to read discussion between STL and CornedBee in the comments:
http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/C9-Lectures-Stephan-T-Lavavej-Core-C-/Stephan-T-Lavavej-Core-Cpp-8-of-n#comments

Important bit:

> sizeof... is not just syntactic sugar, though. A manually implemented
>   sizeof... would have linear "runtime" (number of instantiations),
>   whereas the built-in sizeof... is O(1). (One big issue of variadics as
>   they are is that compilation tends to be very slow, due to lack of
>   random access into arguments packs. Some guy (I think from Boost)
>   studied this and found that compilation speed of Boost.Tuple (a
>   preprorcessor-powered non-variadic tuple) compiled significantly
>   faster than a naive variadics-based version.)

Answer (score -3):

The first and foremost reason `sizeof` was introduced into C++
was because it was present in C, where it is necessary in order
to know how much memory to allocate, e.g. `malloc(
n * sizeof(struct MyClass) )`.  In C++, it's used in similar
cases, where allocation and initialization are separate, for
example in container classes, or variants, or maybe classes.

It's also been known to be used in template meta-programming, in
conjunction with function override resolution.  Things along the
lines of: `sizeof( discriminatorFunction( someArgs ) ) == sizeof(
TrueType )`.

Comment: The question refers to `sizeof...`, not `sizeof`. These are different things (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof...) And the question right now is unclear anyway, since the OP doesn't state what he would expect as an alternative to `sizeof...`.

Comment: OP meant `sizeof...` not `sizeof`.