# Implementation C++14 make_integer_sequence

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, c++14

I tried to implement the [C++14](http://isocpp.org/blog/2013/05/new-paper-n3690-programming-languages-c-committee-draft) alias template `make_integer_sequence`, which simplifies the creation of the class template [`integer_sequence`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence).

```
template< class T, T... I> struct integer_sequence
{
    typedef T value_type;
    static constexpr size_t size() noexcept { return sizeof...(I) ; }

};

template< class T, T N>
using make_integer_sequence = integer_sequence< T, 0,1,2, ... ,N-1 >; // only for illustration.
```

To implement `make_integer_sequence` we need a helper structure `make_helper`.

```
template< class T , class N >
using make_integer_sequence = typename make_helper<T,N>::type;
```

Implementing `make_helper` isn't too difficult.

```
template< class T, T N, T... I >
struct make_helper
{
   typedef typename mpl::if_< T(0) == N,  
                  mpl::identity< integer_sequence<T,I...> >,
                  make_helper< T, N-1, N-1,I...> 
               >::type;
};
```

To test `make_integer_sequence` I made this main function:

```
int main()
{
    #define GEN(z,n,temp)   \
     typedef make_integer_sequence< int, n >  BOOST_PP_CAT(int_seq,n) ;

   BOOST_PP_REPEAT(256, GEN, ~);
}
```

I compiled the program with GCC 4.8.0, on a quad-core i5 system with 8GBs of RAM.
Successful compilation took 4 seconds.

But, when I changed the GEN macro to:

```
int main() {

#define GEN(z,n,temp) \
typedef make_integer_sequence< int, n * 4 > BOOST_PP_CAT(int_seq, n) ;

BOOST_PP_REPEAT(256, GEN, ~ );
}
```

The compilation was unsuccessful and outputted the error message:

> virtual memory exhausted.

Could somebody explain this error and what caused it?

EDIT:

I simplified the test to:

```
int main()
{
   typedef make_integer_sequence< int, 4096 > int_seq4096;
}
```

I then successfully compiled with GCC 4.8.0 -ftemplate-depth=65536.

However this second test:

```
int main()
{
    typedef make_integer_sequence< int, 16384 > int_seq16384;
}
```

Did not compile with GCC 4.8.0 -ftemplate-depth=65536, and resulted in the error:

> virtual memory exhausted.

So, my question is, how do I decrease template deep instantiation?

Regards,
Khurshid.

Comment: In a talk by S.T.Lavavej I think I heard that Microsoft compiler has a hook to generate `make_integer_sequence` automatically, (basically?) in O(1). The irony is that one works a lot to implement this for something that a compiler may produce by itself.

Answer (score 126, accepted):

Here's a `log N` implementation that doesn't even need an increased max-depth for template instantiations and compiles pretty fast:

```cpp
// using aliases for cleaner syntax
template<class T> using Invoke = typename T::type;

template<unsigned...> struct seq{ using type = seq; };

template<class S1, class S2> struct concat;

template<unsigned... I1, unsigned... I2>
struct concat<seq<I1...>, seq<I2...>>
  : seq<I1..., (sizeof...(I1)+I2)...>{};

template<class S1, class S2>
using Concat = Invoke<concat<S1, S2>>;

template<unsigned N> struct gen_seq;
template<unsigned N> using GenSeq = Invoke<gen_seq<N>>;

template<unsigned N>
struct gen_seq : Concat<GenSeq<N/2>, GenSeq<N - N/2>>{};

template<> struct gen_seq<0> : seq<>{};
template<> struct gen_seq<1> : seq<0>{};
```

Comment: Very nice! I would just precise that the depth of instantiations is `O(log N)` (the number of operations is `O(N)`). In any case, this is a very fast implementation.

Comment: Should that really be called `Concat`?

Comment: And for generally( not only for unsigned, for general type T), you couldn't specialization with N = 0, and N=1. 
Compiler shows following error:
error: non-type template argument depends on a template parameter of the partial specialization.

Comment: @Xeo I would read `Concat` as "take two lists and put them one after the other".  Adding "and add the the length of the leftmost list to the contents of the rightmost list" to what `Concat` does would surprise me.  `template<class S, unsigned I=1> struct inc; template<unsigned... Is, unsigned I> struct inc<seq<Is...>, I>:seq<(Is+I)...> {}; template<class S, unsigned I=1> using Inc=Invoke<inc<S,I>>;` then `template<unsigned N>struct gen_seq:Concat<GenSeq<N/2>, Inc<GenSeq<N-N/2>,N/2>>{};`, where `Concat` doesn't add anything to second list, would decouple that operation from concatenation.

Comment: template<unsigned N>struct gen_seq:Concat<GenSeq<N/2>, Inc<GenSeq<N-N/2> ,  N/2>>{};
         \
here last N/2  should be N%2, may be !

Comment: filed as [gcc bug 66059](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=66059), since 4.9.0 through current trunk have an O(N) implementation.

Comment: I had trouble using this code, and then realized I should be using `GenSeq`, not `gen_seq`, for `make_index_sequence`.

Comment: From experiments with a similar implementation I found that the `sizeof...(I1)` in `concat` is quite inefficient (at least for g++) and it can be improved by passing that number into `concat` instead of recalculating it.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: Interesting. Seems kinda weird for that to be inefficient. Shouldn't it be some kinda constant-time check?

Comment: It's surprising to me too. See the code at https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-bugs/2015-11/msg01615.html -- the #ifdef DUP one is very slow when using `sizeof...`, the #else one which is similar to yours is quite fast with `sizeof...` but even faster without it.

Comment: Can I put in a plea for an example of how to use this!

Comment: Even if value is passed directly instead of `sizeof...(I1)`, this implementation is ~2x times slower than Apple Clang.

Answer (score 28):

This is basically me hacking around Xeo's solution: Making community wiki - if appreciative, ***please upvote Xeo***.

...just modified until I felt it couldn't get any simpler, renamed and added `value_type` and `size()` per the Standard (but only doing `index_sequence` not `integer_sequence`), and code working with GCC 5.2 `-std=c++14` could run otherwise unaltered under older/other compilers I'm stuck with.  Might save someone some time / confusion.

```
// based on http://stackoverflow.com/a/17426611/410767 by Xeo
namespace std  // WARNING: at own risk, otherwise use own namespace
{
    template <size_t... Ints>
    struct index_sequence
    {
        using type = index_sequence;
        using value_type = size_t;
        static constexpr std::size_t size() noexcept { return sizeof...(Ints); }
    };

    // --------------------------------------------------------------

    template <class Sequence1, class Sequence2>
    struct _merge_and_renumber;

    template <size_t... I1, size_t... I2>
    struct _merge_and_renumber<index_sequence<I1...>, index_sequence<I2...>>
      : index_sequence<I1..., (sizeof...(I1)+I2)...>
    { };

    // --------------------------------------------------------------

    template <size_t N>
    struct make_index_sequence
      : _merge_and_renumber<typename make_index_sequence<N/2>::type,
                            typename make_index_sequence<N - N/2>::type>
    { };

    template<> struct make_index_sequence<0> : index_sequence<> { };
    template<> struct make_index_sequence<1> : index_sequence<0> { };
}
```

Notes:

- the "magic" of Xeo's solution is in the declaration of `_merge_and_renumber` (`concat` in his code) with exactly two parameters, while the specilisation effectively exposes their individual parameter packs
- the `typename`...`::type` in...

  ```
  struct make_index_sequence
    : _merge_and_renumber<typename make_index_sequence<N/2>::type,
                          typename make_index_sequence<N - N/2>::type>
  ```

avoids the error:

```
invalid use of incomplete type 'struct std::_merge_and_renumber<std::make_index_sequence<1ul>, std::index_sequence<0ul> >'
```

Comment: Why is this `index_sequence` rather than `integer_sequence`?

Comment: @einpoklum: because `integer_sequence` is obliged to have the data type be a template parameter, whereas I've hardcoded `size_t`, which suited me just fine at the time....

Comment: @einpoklum To add a little detail to Tony's response: you can't partially specialize on a template argument of a template type. You can't implement integer_sequence this way. The best you could do to get integer_sequence this was is to but fully specialize for every integer type. (this code length for each integer type)

Answer (score 11):

I found very fast and needless deep recursion version of implementation of `make_index_sequence`. In my PC it compiles with N = 1 048 576 , with 2 s. 
(PC : Centos 6.4 x86, i5, 8 Gb RAM, gcc-4.4.7 -std=c++0x -O2 -Wall).

```
#include <cstddef> // for std::size_t

template< std::size_t ... i >
struct index_sequence
{
    typedef std::size_t value_type;

    typedef index_sequence<i...> type;

    // gcc-4.4.7 doesn't support `constexpr` and `noexcept`.
    static /*constexpr*/ std::size_t size() /*noexcept*/
    { 
        return sizeof ... (i); 
    }
};


// this structure doubles index_sequence elements.
// s- is number of template arguments in IS.
template< std::size_t s, typename IS >
struct doubled_index_sequence;

template< std::size_t s, std::size_t ... i >
struct doubled_index_sequence< s, index_sequence<i... > >
{
    typedef index_sequence<i..., (s + i)... > type;
};

// this structure incremented by one index_sequence, iff NEED-is true, 
// otherwise returns IS
template< bool NEED, typename IS >
struct inc_index_sequence;

template< typename IS >
struct inc_index_sequence<false,IS>{ typedef IS type; };

template< std::size_t ... i >
struct inc_index_sequence< true, index_sequence<i...> >
{
    typedef index_sequence<i..., sizeof...(i)> type;
};



// helper structure for make_index_sequence.
template< std::size_t N >
struct make_index_sequence_impl : 
           inc_index_sequence< (N % 2 != 0), 
                typename doubled_index_sequence< N / 2,
                           typename make_index_sequence_impl< N / 2> ::type
               >::type
       >
{};

 // helper structure needs specialization only with 0 element.
template<>struct make_index_sequence_impl<0>{ typedef index_sequence<> type; };



// OUR make_index_sequence,  gcc-4.4.7 doesn't support `using`, 
// so we use struct instead of it.
template< std::size_t N >
struct make_index_sequence : make_index_sequence_impl<N>::type {};

//index_sequence_for  any variadic templates
template< typename ... T >
struct index_sequence_for : make_index_sequence< sizeof...(T) >{};


// test
typedef make_index_sequence< 1024 * 1024 >::type a_big_index_sequence;
int main(){}
```

Answer (score 4):

You are missing a `-1` here:

```
typedef typename mpl::if_< T(0) == N,  
              mpl::identity< integer_sequence<T> >,
              make_helper< T, N, N-1,I...> 
           >::type;
```

in particular:

```
typedef typename mpl::if_< T(0) == N,  
              mpl::identity< integer_sequence<T> >,
              make_helper< T, N-1, N-1,I...> 
           >::type;
```

Next, the first branch shouldn't be `integer_sequence<T>`, but rather `integer_sequence<T, I...>`.

```
typedef typename mpl::if_< T(0) == N,  
              mpl::identity< integer_sequence<T, I...> >,
              make_helper< T, N-1, N-1,I...> 
           >::type;
```

which should be enough to get your original code to compile.

In general, when writing serious `template` metaprogramming, your main goal should be to keep the depth of `template` instantiation down.  A way to think about this problem is imagining you have an infinite-thread computer: each independent calculation should be shuffled off onto its own thread, then shuffled together at the end.  You have a few operations that take O(1) depth, like `...` expansion: exploit them.

Usually, pulling of logarithmic depth is enough, because with a `900` depth, that allows `2^900` sized structures, and something else breaks first.  (To be fair, what is more likely to happen is 90 different layers of `2^10` sized structures).

Answer (score 4):

Here is another slightly more general variation of [Xeo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17426611/4618482)'s logarithmic answer which provides `make_integer_sequence` for arbitrary types. This is done by using `std::integral_constant` in order to avoid the dreaded "template argument involves template parameter" error.

```
template<typename Int, Int... Ints>
struct integer_sequence
{
    using value_type = Int;
    static constexpr std::size_t size() noexcept
    {
        return sizeof...(Ints);
    }
};

template<std::size_t... Indices>
using index_sequence = integer_sequence<std::size_t, Indices...>;

namespace
{
    // Merge two integer sequences, adding an offset to the right-hand side.
    template<typename Offset, typename Lhs, typename Rhs>
    struct merge;

    template<typename Int, Int Offset, Int... Lhs, Int... Rhs>
    struct merge<
        std::integral_constant<Int, Offset>,
        integer_sequence<Int, Lhs...>,
        integer_sequence<Int, Rhs...>
    >
    {
        using type = integer_sequence<Int, Lhs..., (Offset + Rhs)...>;
    };

    template<typename Int, typename N>
    struct log_make_sequence
    {
        using L = std::integral_constant<Int, N::value / 2>;
        using R = std::integral_constant<Int, N::value - L::value>;
        using type = typename merge<
            L,
            typename log_make_sequence<Int, L>::type,
            typename log_make_sequence<Int, R>::type
        >::type;
    };

    // An empty sequence.
    template<typename Int>
    struct log_make_sequence<Int, std::integral_constant<Int, 0>>
    {
        using type = integer_sequence<Int>;
    };

    // A single-element sequence.
    template<typename Int>
    struct log_make_sequence<Int, std::integral_constant<Int, 1>>
    {
        using type = integer_sequence<Int, 0>;
    };
}

template<typename Int, Int N>
using make_integer_sequence =
    typename log_make_sequence<
        Int, std::integral_constant<Int, N>
    >::type;

template<std::size_t N>
using make_index_sequence = make_integer_sequence<std::size_t, N>;
```

Demo: [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a3e426cc235ec2d7)

Answer (score 2):

Simple implementation O(N). Probably not what you want for large N, but my application is only for calling functions with indexed arguments, and I wouldn't expect an arity of more than about 10. I haven't filled in the members of integer_sequence. I'm looking forward to using a standard library implementation and nuking this :)

```
template <typename T, T... ints>
struct integer_sequence
{ };

template <typename T, T N, typename = void>
struct make_integer_sequence_impl
{
    template <typename>
    struct tmp;

    template <T... Prev>
    struct tmp<integer_sequence<T, Prev...>>
    {
        using type = integer_sequence<T, Prev..., N-1>;
    };

    using type = typename tmp<typename make_integer_sequence_impl<T, N-1>::type>::type;
};

template <typename T, T N>
struct make_integer_sequence_impl<T, N, typename std::enable_if<N==0>::type>
{ using type = integer_sequence<T>; };

template <typename T, T N>
using make_integer_sequence = typename make_integer_sequence_impl<T, N>::type;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another implementation technique (for `T=size_t`), it uses C++17 fold expressions and bitwise generation (i.e. `O(log(N)`):

```cpp
template <size_t... Is>
struct idx_seq {
  template <size_t N, size_t Offset>
  struct pow2_impl {
    using type = typename idx_seq<Is..., (Offset + Is)...>::template pow2_impl<N - 1, Offset + sizeof...(Is)>::type;
  };
  template <size_t _> struct pow2_impl<0, _> { using type = idx_seq; };
  template <size_t _> struct pow2_impl<(size_t)-1, _> { using type = idx_seq<>; };

  template <size_t Offset>
  using offset = idx_seq<(Offset + Is)...>;
};

template <size_t N>
using idx_seq_pow2 = typename idx_seq<0>::template pow2_impl<N, 1>::type;

template <size_t... Is, size_t... Js>
constexpr static auto operator,(idx_seq<Is...>, idx_seq<Js...>)
  -> idx_seq<Is..., Js...>
{ return {}; }

template <size_t N, size_t Mask, size_t... Bits>
struct make_idx_seq_impl {
  using type = typename make_idx_seq_impl<N, (N >= Mask ? Mask << 1 : 0), Bits..., (N & Mask)>::type;
};

template <size_t N, size_t... Bits>
struct make_idx_seq_impl<N, 0, Bits...> {
  using type = decltype((idx_seq<>{}, ..., typename idx_seq_pow2<Bits>::template offset<(N & (Bits - 1))>{}));
};

template <size_t N>
using make_idx_seq = typename make_idx_seq_impl<N, 1>::type;
```

Comment: Brilliant. I came up with a very similar technique , around the same time; even the same `decltype((idx,...))` trick. It is the superior solution. Keeps the number of template instantiations lower too; `M*log(N)` is  a generous upper bound, where `M` is the number of user requested instantiations, and `N` is the maximum among the values for which the user requested instances. Later, however I found a way to get rid of the fold expression and perform a simple concatenation. So unfortunate ☹️ this answer showed up at the bottom of the list. It could just be the top-rated accepted answer.

Comment: By the way `Bits...` in `make_idx_seq_impl`, must become shift counts instead of binary powers; because `idx_seq_pow2` works with shift counts(not binary powers).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a *very* simple solution implemented with recursion based on tag dispatching

```
template <typename T, T M, T ... Indx>
constexpr std::integer_sequence<T, Indx...> make_index_sequence_(std::false_type)
{
    return {};
}

template <typename T, T M, T ... Indx>
constexpr auto make_index_sequence_(std::true_type)
{
    return make_index_sequence_<T, M, Indx..., sizeof...(Indx)>(
            std::integral_constant<bool, sizeof...(Indx) + 1 < M>());
}

template <size_t M>
constexpr auto make_index_sequence()
{
    return make_index_sequence_<size_t, M>(std::integral_constant<bool, (0 < M)>());
}
```

However, this solution can not be extended to C++11.