# C++ functional & generic programming [with MySQL connector example]

Tags: c++, templates, functional-programming, generic-programming

I am going to use MySQL connector. They provide functions to access the result row. Some examples are `getString(1)`, `getInt(1)`, `getDate(2)`. The number inside the parenthesis is about the index of the result.

So that I have to use the following code to access this example row: `'John', 'M', 34`

```
string name = row.getString(1);
string sex = row.getString(2);
int age = row.getInt(3);
```

I would like to try generic programming for various reasons (mainly for fun). But it was quite disappointing that I can't make it happens even with much time used.

The final result that I want:

```
std::tie<name, sex, age> = row.getResult<string, string, int>();
```

This functions should call the corresponding MySQL API.

It is also good to see any answer similar to below, although the syntax is wrong.

```
std::tie<name, sex, age> = row.getResult([string, string, int]);
```

Please don't suggest using for-loop. Let's try something more generic & functional ;-)

Comment: `string age` should be `int age`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
struct Row
{
   template <int N, typename ... Args> struct Helper;

   template <typename Arg1> struct Helper<1, Arg1>
   {
      static std::tuple<Arg1> getResult(Row& r)
      {
         return std::make_tuple(r.getResult<Arg1>(0));
      }
   };

   template <int N, typename Arg1, typename ... Args>
      struct Helper<N, Arg1, Args...>
      {
         static std::tuple <Arg1, Args ...> getResult(Row& r)
         {
            return std::tuple_cat(std::make_tuple(r.getResult<Arg1>(N-1)),
                                  Helper<N-1, Args...>::getResult(r));
         }
      };

   template <typename Arg> Arg getResult(int index)
   {
      // This is where the value needs to be extracted from the row.
      // It is a dummy implementation for testing purposes.
      return Arg{};
   }

   template <typename ... Args>
      std::tuple <Args ...> getResult()
      {
         return Helper<sizeof...(Args), Args...>::getResult(*this);
      }
};
```

Example usage:

```
Row r;
auto res1 = r.getResult<std::string>();
auto res2 = r.getResult<int>();
auto res3 = r.getResult<int, double, int>();
auto res4 = r.getResult<int, int, double, double>();
auto res5 = r.getResult<std::string, std::string, int, int, double, double>();
```

Working code: http://ideone.com/6IpJ8q

Comment: Woow it works like magic! Thanks! I will accept your answer after I review all other answers.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to write these:

```
template<class T> T get( MySQLRow const& row, unsigned index);
template<>
int get<int>( MySQLRow const& row, unsigned index) { return connector.GetInt(index); }
// etc
```

Then, add some template meta programming tools:

```
template<class...>struct types{using type=types;};
```

the above could probably be replaced with `std::tuple<?>*` instead of `types<?>`.  Maybe.  But the above is clearer anyhow.

Next, this can be replaced with C++14's `integral_sequence`:

```
template<unsigned...>struct indexes{using type=indexes;};
template<unsigned max, unsigned...is>struct make_indexes<max-1, max-1, is...>{};
template<unsigned...is>struct make_indexes<0,is...>:indexes<is...>{};
template<unsigned max>using make_indexes_t=typename make_indexes<max>::type;
```

Finally, stuff:

```
namespace details {
  template<unsigned... Is, class... Types>
  std::tuple< Types... >
  getResult( indexes<Is...>, types<Types...>, MySQLRow const& row ) {
    return { get<Types>( row, Is+1 )... };
  }
}

template<class... Types>
std::tuple<Types...>
getResult( MySQLRow const& row ) {
  return details::getResult( make_indexes_t<sizeof...(Ts)>{}, types<Types...>{}, row );
}
```

syntax is:

```
getResult<int, double, std::string>( row );
```

assuming you write the various `get` functions and fix the type of `MySQLRow` to whatever it really is, and assuming the 1st row is `1`.

Comment: I am still digesting your answer :-/ It is really hard to understand LOL. One more question: How come the `...` can exist in statement `return { get<Types>( row, Is+1 )... };`. I read several sites but no one talk about that.

Comment: @hktonylee I am constructing the `tuple` return value there using `return {}` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create the set of function `Get` overloads which implement unified interface to `GetX` methods of row:

   ```
   #define DEFINE_GET_FOR_TYPE(Type, TypeName) \
   void Get(Type& arg, const MySQLRow& row, std::size_t index) \
   { \
       arg = row.Get##TypeName(index); \
   }

   DEFINE_GET_FOR_TYPE(int, Int)

   DEFINE_GET_FOR_TYPE(std::string, String)

   // ...
   ```

   Here the macro `DEFINE_GET_FOR_TYPE` is used to create the necessary set.
2. Implement `GetResult` function template using C++14 `std::index_sequence` and `std::make_index_sequence` ([they can be implemented in C++11 program, too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17424477/implementation-c14-make-integer-sequence)):

   ```
   struct Iterate
   {
       Iterate(...) {}
   };

   template <std::size_t... indices, typename... Types>
   void GetResultImpl(const MySQLRow& row, std::index_sequence<indices...>, Types&... args)
   {
       Iterate{(Get(args, row, indices + 1), 0)...};
   }

   template <typename... Types>
   void GetResult(const MySQLRow& row, Types&... args)
   {
       GetResultImpl(row, std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Types)>(), args...);
   }
   ```
3. Use `GetResult` function template to get values from the row:

   ```
   std::string name;
   std::string sex;
   int age;

   GetResult(row, name, sex, age);
   ```

[**Live demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f4841b87cdb186d7)

Comment: Thank you very much... But macro is hard to understand for a C++ learner ;-)

Comment: @HKTonyLee Macro is not a key thing here. You can simply write `Get` function overloads `void Get(X& arg, const MySQLRow& row, std::size_t index) { arg = row.GetX(index); }` manually if you want.