# Delay return type resolution for a recursive metafunction in C++11

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, template-meta-programming

I am trying to write a simple sequence generator in C++11, that takes in some start & end indices and generates a sequence of integers at compile-time. Since integer_sequence is not available until C++14, I use a custom variadic templated container to store the integer sequence:

```
template <int...>
struct IntSequence {};
```

Now I would like to call a `sequence_generator` function that returns to me an IntSequence container templated on the range of integers I requested.

```
auto t = sequence_generator<3, 5>();
```

Here I would expect `t` to be an `IntSequence<3,4,5>`. I unroll the sequence generator recursively and use enable_if to stop the recursion:

```
template <int S, int E, int... Seq>
auto sequence_generator() -> enable_if_t<(S <= E), IntSequence<Seq...>> {
// Pack S into the variadic sequence and increment to S+1.  
return sequence_generator<S + 1, E, S, Seq...>();
}

template <int S, int E, int... Seq>
auto sequence_generator() -> enable_if_t<!(S <= E), IntSequence<Seq...>> {
  return IntSequence<Seq...>{};
}
```

However the constructor of my enable_if is not right, since I am declaring a return type using the variadic pack available at the current recursive step. Instead I would like the compiler to unroll the entire recursive chain and select the return type of the base case (which would be `IntSequence<3,4,5>`. I do not know how to achieve that.

Comment: [mcve] Please. It appears your arguments to the template may be out of order.

Comment: This is minimal, complete and verifiable! What would you have me strip out?

Comment: I suppose I got lazy and wanted it all in one spot, or a link to an online example.

Comment: How are you using `enable_if_t` without C++14? MSVC?

Comment: I just added this in my source: `using enable_if_t = typename std::enable_if<b, T>::type;`

Answer (score 3):

First, let us split SFINAE from return type deduction

```
template <int S, int E, int... Seq, std::enable_if_t<(S <= E), int>* =nullptr>
auto sequence_generator() -> ???
```

Next, the body of the function should be just `return {};`:

```
template <int S, int E, int... Seq, std::enable_if_t<(S <= E),int>* =nullptr>
auto sequence_generator() -> ???
{
  return {};
}
```

because why repeat ourselves.

The functions visible at the point we synthesize the return type are those declared *before* this function template, plus any found via ADL.

This set does not include ourselves.

So we'll make a details namespace, and force ADL as follows:

```
namespace details {
  struct helper {};

  template <int S, int E, int... Seq, std::enable_if_t<(S <= E), int>* =nullptr>
  auto sequence_generator(helper, IntSequence<S,E,Seq...>)
  -> ???
  {
    return {};
  }
  ???
}
template<int S, int E, int...Seq>
auto sequence_generator()
-> decltype( sequence_generator(details::helper{}, IntSequence<S,E,Seq...>{}) )
{
  return {};
}
```

which amusingly removes the need to actually have a body for `details::sequence_generator`.

```
namespace details {
  struct helper {};

  template <int S, int E, int... Seq, std::enable_if_t<(S <= E), int>* =nullptr>
  auto sequence_generator(helper, IntSequence<S,E,Seq...>)
  -> ???

  template <int S, int E, int... Seq, std::enable_if_t<(S > E), int>* =nullptr>
  auto sequence_generator(helper, IntSequence<S,E,Seq...>)
  -> ???
}
template<int S, int E, int...Seq>
auto sequence_generator()
-> decltype( sequence_generator<S,E,Seq...>(helper::details{}) )
{
  return {};
}
```

we now have to implement those two functions.

```
  template <int S, int E, int... Seq, std::enable_if_t<(S <= E), int>* =nullptr>
  auto sequence_generator(helper, IntSequence<S,E,Seq...>)
  -> decltype( sequence_generator(helper{}, IntSequence<S + 1, E, S, Seq...>{}) );

  template <int S, int E, int... Seq, std::enable_if_t<(S > E), int>* =nullptr>
  auto sequence_generator(helper, IntSequence<S,E,Seq...>)
  -> IntSequence<Seq...>;
```

[and done (live example).](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a8e00c32dc8025f1)

Note that I pass everything as a parameter, deducing template parameters from it.  This allows the adl to work properly.

Another approach would be to directly construct the type without helper functions; I assume you are using functions to construct the type for your own reasons.  There are advantages to function-based template metaprogramming; see boost hana to see how far you can go.  There are also disadvantages, like the ADL hoops you have to run through for recursion of return types.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can deduce the actual type of integer sequence:

```
#include <cstddef>

template <size_t... Ints> struct integer_sequence { };

template <size_t begin, size_t end, size_t... ints>
struct integer_sequence_type { 
  using type = typename integer_sequence_type<begin+1, end, ints..., begin>::type;
};

template <size_t begin, size_t... ints>
struct integer_sequence_type<begin, begin, ints...> { 
  using type = integer_sequence<ints..., begin>;
};

// below part is for verification - compiler will tell you exactly the type :)
void foo(int );
void foo(char );

void test() {
  foo(integer_sequence_type<4, 8>::type());
}
```

Now you can use this construct to figure out return type of your function. (NOTE: I didn't look into your function as you didn't ask for it)

Answer (score 0):

Best way is start with a normal index_sequence implementation for example from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17426611/1918154) and transfrom the sequence:

```
template<class Seq, std::size_t Offset>
struct transform_seq;

template <std::size_t... Seq, std::size_t Offset>
struct transform_seq<seq<Seq...>, Offset>
{
    using type = seq<Seq+Offset...>;
};

template<std::size_t From, std::size_t To>
using sequence_generator = typename transform_seq<GenSeq<To-From+1>, From>::type;
```

The result can be seen [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c84af7748951f70a).