# Find contractions of a variadic pack based on another variadic parameter pack

Tags: c++, c++11, multidimensional-array, template-meta-programming

I am working on a static multidimensional array contraction framework, and I have encountered a problem which is somewhat difficult to explain but I will try my best. Suppose we have a `N` dimensional array class

```
template<typename T, int ... dims>
class Array {}
```

which could be instantiated as

```
Array<double> scalar;
Array<double,4> vector_of_4s;
Array<float,2,3> matrix_of_2_by_3;
// and so on
```

Now we have another class called `Indices`

```
template<int ... Idx>
struct Indices {}
```

I have a function `contraction` now whose signature should look like the following

```
template<T, int ... Dims, int ... Idx, 
typename std::enable_if<sizeof...(Dims)==sizeof...(Idx),bool>::type=0>
Array<T,apply_to_dims<Dims...,do_contract<Idx...>>> 
contraction(const Indices<Idx...> &idx, const Array<T,Dims...> &a)
```

I may not have gotten the syntax right here, but I essentially want the returned `Array` to have a dimension based on the entries of `Indices`. Let me provide examples of what a `contraction` can perform. Note that, in this context, **contraction** means **removal of dimensions for which the parameters in index list is equal**.

```
auto arr = contraction(Indices<0,0>, Array<double,3,3>) 
// arr is Array<double> as both indices contract 0==0

auto arr = contraction(Indices<0,1>, Array<double,3,3>) 
// arr is Array<double,3,3> as no contraction happens here, 0!=1

auto arr = contraction(Indices<0,1,0>, Array<double,3,4,3>) 
// arr is Array<double,4> as 1st and 3rd indices contract 0==0  

auto arr = contraction(Indices<0,1,0,7,7,2>, Array<double,3,4,3,5,5,6>) 
// arr is Array<double,4,6> as (1st and 3rd, 0==0) and (4th and 5th, 7==7) indices contract

auto arr = contraction(Indices<10,10,2,3>, Array<double,5,6,4,4>
// should not compile as contraction between 1st and 2nd arguments 
// requested but dimensions don't match 5!=6

// The parameters of Indices really do not matter as long as 
// we can identify contractions. They are typically expressed as enums, I,J,K...
```

So essentially, given `Idx...` and `Dims...` which should both be of equal size, check which values in `Idx...` are equal, get the positions at which they occur and remove the corresponding entries (positions) in `Dims...`. This is essentially a [tensor contraction rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_contraction).

**Rules of array contraction:**

1. The number of parameters of indices and the dimension/rank of the array should be the same, i.e. `sizeof...(Idx)==sizeof...(Dims)`
2. There is *one-to-one* correspondence bewteen `Idx` and `Dims` i.e. if we have `Indices<0,1,2>` and `Array<double,4,5,6>`, `0` maps to `4`, `1` maps to `5` and `2` maps to `6`.
3. If there are identical/equal values in `Idx`, that means a contraction, meaning the corresponding dimensions in `Dims` should vanish, for example, if we have `Indices<0,0,3>` and `Array<double,4,4,6>`, then `0==0` and the corresponding dimensions that these values map to which are `4` and `4` both need to vanish and the resulting array should be `Array<double,6>`
4. If `Idx` has identical values, but the corresponding `Dims` don't match, then a compile time error should be triggered, for instance, `Indices<0,0,3>` and `Array<double,4,5,6>` is not possible as `4!=5`, similarly `Indices<0,1,0>` would not be possible as `4!=6`, which leads to
5. No contraction is possible for arrays with different dimensions, for instance `Array<double,4,5,6>` cannot be contracted in any which way.
6. Multiple pairs, triplets, quadruplets and so on, is allowed for `Idx` as long as the corresponding `Dims` also match, for instance `Indices<0,0,0,0,1,1,4,3,3,7,7,7>` would contract to an `Array<double,6>`, given the input array was `Array<double,2,2,2,2,3,3,6,2,2,3,3,3>`.

My knowledge of metaprogamming does not go that far to achieve this functionality, but I hope I have made the intent clear, for someone to guide me in the right direction.

Comment: I cannot figure out what your rule is for contraction.  Given `Idx...` and `Dims...`, what should be the output dimensions?  Can you provide a set of rules, rather than a set of examples?

Comment: Essentially, given `Idx...` and `Dims...` which should both be of equal size, check which values in `Idx...` are equal, get the positions at which they occur and remove the corresponding entries in `Dims...`.

Comment: @romeric - you can have only couples of equal values in `Idx` or even triplets, etc? In case of triplets, what's the rule?

Comment: Potentially, you can have as many equal values, for instance for triplets `contraction(Indices<0,0,1,1,2,2,3>, Array<double,3,3,4,4,5,5,6>)` would give `Array<double,6>` as (1st and 2nd, 0==0),  (3rd and 4th, 1==1),  (5th and 6th, 2==2) would all contract and vanish.

Comment: Can I have Indices<0,0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,3> ?

Comment: Yes, that would collapse to `3`, as all other parameters have more than one value appearing in the index list.

Comment: @ romeric - and what about `Indices<0, 0, 0, 5>` with `Array<double, 2, 2, 3, 5>` ? I mean, when you have a triplet in `Indices` and only two of the correspondant indices in `Array<>` are equal?

Comment: That should trigger a compile time error as the corresponding dimensions and the equal indices don't match.

Comment: @ romeric - do you need a solution in C+11 or a C++14 solution is good enough?

Comment: @max66 Ideally, C++11.

Answer (score 3):

A bunch of `constexpr` functions that do the actual checking:

```
// is ind[i] unique in ind?
template<size_t N>
constexpr bool is_uniq(const int (&ind)[N], size_t i, size_t cur = 0){
    return cur == N ? true : 
           (cur == i || ind[cur] != ind[i]) ? is_uniq(ind, i, cur + 1) : false;
}

// For every i where ind[i] == index, is dim[i] == dimension?
template<size_t N>
constexpr bool check_all_eq(int index, int dimension,
                            const int (&ind)[N], const int (&dim)[N], size_t cur = 0) {
    return cur == N ? true :
           (ind[cur] != index || dim[cur] == dimension) ? 
                check_all_eq(index, dimension, ind, dim, cur + 1) : false;
}

// if position i should be contracted away, return -1, otherwise return dim[i].
// triggers a compile-time error when used in a constant expression on mismatch.
template<size_t N>
constexpr int calc(size_t i, const int (&ind)[N], const int (&dim)[N]){
    return is_uniq(ind, i) ? dim[i] :
           check_all_eq(ind[i], dim[i], ind, dim) ? -1 : throw "dimension mismatch";
}
```

Now we need a way to get rid of the `-1`s:

```
template<class Ind, class... Inds>
struct concat { using type = Ind; };
template<int... I1, int... I2, class... Inds>
struct concat<Indices<I1...>, Indices<I2...>, Inds...>
    :  concat<Indices<I1..., I2...>, Inds...> {};

// filter out all instances of I from Is...,
// return the rest as an Indices    
template<int I, int... Is>
struct filter
    :  concat<typename std::conditional<Is == I, Indices<>, Indices<Is>>::type...> {};
```

Use them:

```
template<class Ind, class Arr, class Seq>
struct contraction_impl;

template<class T, int... Ind, int... Dim, size_t... Seq>
struct contraction_impl<Indices<Ind...>, Array<T, Dim...>, std::index_sequence<Seq...>>{
    static constexpr int ind[] = { Ind... };
    static constexpr int dim[] = { Dim... };
    static constexpr int result[] = {calc(Seq, ind, dim)...};

    template<int... Dims>
    static auto unpack_helper(Indices<Dims...>) -> Array<T, Dims...>;

    using type = decltype(unpack_helper(typename filter<-1,  result[Seq]...>::type{}));
};


template<class T, int ... Dims, int ... Idx, 
typename std::enable_if<sizeof...(Dims)==sizeof...(Idx),bool>::type=0>
typename contraction_impl<Indices<Idx...>, Array<T,Dims...>, 
                          std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Dims)>>::type
contraction(const Indices<Idx...> &idx, const Array<T,Dims...> &a);
```

Everything except `make_index_sequence` is C++11. You can find a gazillion implementations of that on SO.

Comment: I never thought of passing around index sequences as constexpr list-initializers.  Neat!

Comment: @T.C. Can't get your solution to work under `-std=c++11`. Compiles fine with `-std=c++14`. I am using [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32223343/2750396) implementation for `make_index_sequence`.

Comment: @romeric That's not a proper implementation, but if you want to use it, you need `typename make_index_sequence<S>::type`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a mess, but I think it does what you want it to do.  There are almost certainly many simplifications that could be made to this, but this is my first pass that passes tests.  Please note that this does not implement contraction, but just determines what the type should be.  If that is not what you needed, I apologize in advance.

```
#include <type_traits>

template <std::size_t...>
struct Indices {};

template <typename, std::size_t...>
struct Array {};

// Count number of 'i' in 'rest...', base case
template <std::size_t i, std::size_t... rest>
struct Count : std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 0>
{};

// Count number of 'i' in 'rest...', inductive case
template <std::size_t i, std::size_t j, std::size_t... rest>
struct Count<i, j, rest...> :
    std::integral_constant<std::size_t,
                           Count<i, rest...>::value + ((i == j) ? 1 : 0)>
{};

// Is 'i' contained in 'rest...'?
template <std::size_t i, std::size_t... rest>
struct Contains :
    std::integral_constant<bool, (Count<i, rest...>::value > 0)>
{};


// Accumulation of counts of indices in all, base case
template <typename All, typename Remainder,
          typename AccIdx, typename AccCount>
struct Counts {
    using indices = AccIdx;
    using counts = AccCount;
};

// Accumulation of counts of indices in all, inductive case
template <std::size_t... all, std::size_t i, std::size_t... rest,
          std::size_t... indices, std::size_t... counts>
struct Counts<Indices<all...>, Indices<i, rest...>,
              Indices<indices...>, Indices<counts...>>
    : std::conditional<Contains<i, indices...>::value,
                       Counts<Indices<all...>, Indices<rest...>,
                              Indices<indices...>,
                              Indices<counts...>>,
                       Counts<Indices<all...>, Indices<rest...>,
                              Indices<indices..., i>,
                              Indices<counts...,
                                      Count<i, all...>::value>>>::type
{};

// Get value in From that matched the first value of Idx that matched idx
template <std::size_t idx, typename Idx, typename From>
struct First : std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 0>
{};
template <std::size_t i, std::size_t j, std::size_t k,
          std::size_t... indices, std::size_t... values>
struct First<i, Indices<j, indices...>, Indices<k, values...>>
    : std::conditional<i == j,
                       std::integral_constant<std::size_t, k>,
                       First<i, Indices<indices...>,
                             Indices<values...>>>::type
{};

// Return whether all values in From that match Idx being idx are tgt
template <std::size_t idx, std::size_t tgt, typename Idx, typename From>
struct AllMatchTarget : std::true_type
{};
template <std::size_t idx, std::size_t tgt,
          std::size_t i, std::size_t j,
          std::size_t... indices, std::size_t... values>
struct AllMatchTarget<idx, tgt,
                      Indices<i, indices...>, Indices<j, values...>>
    : std::conditional<i == idx && j != tgt, std::false_type,
                       AllMatchTarget<idx, tgt, Indices<indices...>,
                                      Indices<values...>>>::type
{};

/* Generate the dimensions, given the counts, indices, and values */
template <typename Counts, typename Indices,
          typename AllIndices, typename Values, typename Accum>
struct GenDims;

template <typename A, typename V, typename R>
struct GenDims<Indices<>, Indices<>, A, V, R> {
    using type = R;
};
template <typename T, std::size_t i, std::size_t c,
          std::size_t... counts, std::size_t... indices,
          std::size_t... dims, typename AllIndices, typename Values>
struct GenDims<Indices<c, counts...>, Indices<i, indices...>,
               AllIndices, Values, Array<T, dims...>>
{
    static constexpr auto value = First<i, AllIndices, Values>::value;
    static_assert(AllMatchTarget<i, value, AllIndices, Values>::value,
                  "Index doesn't correspond to matching dimensions");
    using type = typename GenDims<
        Indices<counts...>, Indices<indices...>,
        AllIndices, Values,
        typename std::conditional<c == 1,
                                  Array<T, dims..., value>,
                                  Array<T, dims...>>::type>::type;
};

/* Put it all together */
template <typename I, typename A>
struct ContractionType;

template <typename T, std::size_t... indices, std::size_t... values>
struct ContractionType<Indices<indices...>, Array<T, values...>> {
    static_assert(sizeof...(indices) == sizeof...(values),
                   "Number of indices and dimensions do not match");
    using counts = Counts<Indices<indices...>,
                          Indices<indices...>,
                          Indices<>, Indices<>>;
    using type = typename GenDims<typename counts::counts,
                                  typename counts::indices,
                                  Indices<indices...>, Indices<values...>,
                                  Array<T>>::type;
};

static_assert(std::is_same<typename
              ContractionType<Indices<0, 0>, Array<double, 3, 3>>::type,
              Array<double>>::value, "");
static_assert(std::is_same<typename
              ContractionType<Indices<0, 1>, Array<double, 3, 3>>::type,
              Array<double, 3, 3>>::value, "");
static_assert(std::is_same<typename
              ContractionType<Indices<0, 1, 0>, Array<double, 3, 4, 3>>::type,
              Array<double, 4>>::value, "");
static_assert(std::is_same<typename
              ContractionType<Indices<0, 1, 0, 7, 7, 2>,
              Array<double, 3, 4, 3, 5, 5, 6>>::type,
              Array<double, 4, 6>>::value, "");

// Errors appropriately when uncommented
/* static_assert(std::is_same<typename */
/*               ContractionType<Indices<10,10, 2, 3>, */
/*               Array<double, 5,6,4,4>>::type, */
/*               Array<double>::value, ""); */
```

Here follows an explanation of what is going on here:

- First I generate, using `Counts`, a list of the unique indices (`Counts::indices`) and the number of times each index appears in the sequence (`Counts::counts`).
- Then I walk over the index, count pairs from `Counts`, and for each index, if the count is 1, I accumulate the value and recurse.  Otherwise, I pass on the accumulated value and recurse.

The most irritating part is the `static_assert` in `GenDims`, which verifies for an index that all matching dimensions are the same.