# Is it possible to interleave parameter packs?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

Is it possible, with C++11/14/1z, to have a templated construct with two parameter packs, and within it, instantiate some other templated construct with the two packs inteleaved? i.e. if the first pack is T1_1, T1_2, T1_3 and the second pack is T2_1, T2_2 and T2_3, the interleaved pack will be T1_1, T2_1, T1_2, T2_2, T1_3, T2_3? My guess would be "no", since an ellipsis should not be able to apply to two parameter pack element designators; but perhaps some kind of tuple-construction or recursive-instantiation trick could work?

**Edit:** Let me be explicit in assuming the packs have equal lengths (`sizeof...` values). A solution for packs of different lengths would be nice provided it doesn't make things much more convoluted.

Answer (score 4):

Using `tuple_cat` is overkill. Not to mention unnecessarily constraining.

Trivial pack class:

```
template<class...> struct pack {};
```

A variadic concat, fairly trivial to write:

```
template<class T = pack<>, class...> 
struct concat { using type = T; };

template<class... T1, class... T2, class... Ts>
struct concat<pack<T1...>, pack<T2...>, Ts...> 
    : concat<pack<T1..., T2...>, Ts...> {};

template<class... Ts> 
using concat_t = typename concat<Ts...>::type;
```

Then interleave itself is equally trivial - expand into pack of two types, then concatenate them:

```
template<class... Us>
struct interleave {
     template<class... Vs>
     using with = concat_t<pack<Us, Vs>...>;
};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/860ddb343173ce52).

Comment: this only handles packs of equal length (any solution relying on paired pack expansion would have this limitation due to 'mismatched argument pack lengths while expanding'). I'd expect a solution that appends the types of the longest pack at the end and it seems it would take compile time integer sequences to achieve that. (+1 for the use of `t1` in the Demo)

Comment: I was suspicious of this code... it doesn't look it it should compile, especially the `(Us, Vs)...` line. But it does, whaddaya know...

Comment: @NikosAthanasiou You just need a `split<N, pack<Ts...>>` if you want to support that. That in turn can be implemented either with integer sequences or simple recursion

Answer (score 3):

All the individual pieces for this have actually already been added to the standard.  I can't test this myself right now but the idea should work.

```
template <class Tuple1, class Tuple2, std::size_t ... indices>
auto interleave(Tuple1 t1, Tuple2 t2, std::integer_sequence<std::size_t, indices...>)
{
    return std::tuple_cat(std::make_tuple(std::get<indices>(t1),
                                          std::get<indices>(t2))...);
}


template <class Tuple1, class Tuple2>
auto interleave(Tuple1 t1, Tuple2 t2)
{
    return interleave(t1, t2, std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size<Tuple1>::value>());
}
```

Comment: Where are the two parameter packs? This looks like just a tuple interleaver.

Comment: @einpoklum Whatever parameter packs you have, just put them in tuples and then interleave the tuples.

Answer (score 2):

With a function and a `decltype`s, you can easily do that.
Here is a working example:

```
#include<tuple>

template<std::size_t... I>
constexpr auto f(std::index_sequence<I...>, auto tup1, auto tup2) {
    return std::tuple_cat(std::make_tuple(std::get<I>(tup1), std::get<I>(tup2))...);
}

template<typename... V>
struct S {
    template<typename... U, std::enable_if_t<(sizeof...(V) == sizeof...(U))>* = nullptr>
    static auto generate() {
        return f(std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(U)>(), std::tuple<V...>{}, std::tuple<U...>{});
    }
};

int main() {
    static_assert(
        std::is_same<
            decltype(S<int, double>::template generate<char, void*>()),
            std::tuple<int, char, double, void*>
        >::value,
        "!"
    );
}
```

Comment: I'd mention `std::integer_sequence` is C++14.

Comment: @einpoklum Yes, it is, but you can find a C++11-implementation of it on the web, thus the solution still applies. Let me search it and integrate the answer. Can [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17424477/implementation-c14-make-integer-sequence) help?

Comment: @T.C. Right, it's known that way indeed. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Sure it's possible.  You can get two different packs via a wrapper:

```
template < typename L0, typename L1 >
struct interleave;

template < typename ... Pack >
struct pack {};

template < typename ... P0, typename ... P1 >
struct interleave<pack<P0...>, pack<P1...>>
{
   using type = ???;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <typeinfo>

template<class T1, class T2>
struct interleave
{
  static constexpr std::size_t size = std::tuple_size<T1>::value;
  static_assert(size == std::tuple_size<T2>::value, ""); 

  template<class T> struct impl;

  template<std::size_t...Is>
  struct impl<std::index_sequence<Is...>>
  {
    using type = std::tuple
      <
      std::tuple<std::tuple_element_t<Is, T1>,
      std::tuple_element_t<Is, T2>>...
      >;
  };

  template<class T> struct dedup;
  template<class...Ts>
    struct dedup<std::tuple<Ts...>>
    {
      using type = decltype(std::tuple_cat(std::declval<Ts>()...)); 
    };

  using dups = typename impl<decltype(std::make_index_sequence<size>())>::type;

  using type = typename dedup<dups>::type;
};


int main()
{
  using t = interleave<std::tuple<int, char, float>, std::tuple<unsigned, double, const char*>>::type;
  std::cout << typeid(t).name() << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Aim:**

Get a type alias to:

```
Foo<int, double, char, const char*>
```

using 2 parameter packs:

```
using Pack1 = Pack<int, char>;
using Pack2 = Pack<double, const char*>;
```

and then interleaving them:

```
typename ToFoo<Pack1, Pack2>::type
```

and performing a `static_assert` that they are equivalent:

```
using T1 = Foo<int, double, char, const char*>;
using T2 = typename ToFoo<Pack<int, char>, Pack<double, const char*>>::type;

static_assert(std::is_same<T1, T2>::value, "passed");
```

**Solution:**

We can interleave 2 tuples into 1 as follows:

```
template <class Tuple1, class Tuple2, std::size_t ... indices>
auto interleave(Tuple1 t1, Tuple2 t2, std::integer_sequence<std::size_t, indices...>)
{
    return std::tuple_cat(std::make_tuple(std::get<indices>(t1),
                                          std::get<indices>(t2))...);
}

template <class Tuple1, class Tuple2>
auto interleave(Tuple1 t1, Tuple2 t2)
{
    return interleave(t1, t2, std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size<Tuple1>::value>());
}
```

We can get the type of the resulting interleaved tuple as follows:

```
template<typename... Ts>
struct Pack 
{
    using type = std::tuple<Ts...>;
};

template<typename T0, typename T1>
struct Interleaved;

template<typename... P0, typename... P1>
struct Interleaved<Pack<P0...>, Pack<P1...>>
{
    using Pack0 = typename Pack<P0...>::type;
    using Pack1 = typename Pack<P1...>::type;

    using type = decltype(interleave(std::declval<Pack0>(), std::declval<Pack1>()));
};
```

We can then take that `std::tuple<Ts...>` type and "convert" it to `Foo<Ts...>` as follows:

```
template<typename T>
struct TupleToFoo;

template<typename... Ts>
struct TupleToFoo<std::tuple<Ts...>>
{
    using type = Foo<Ts...>;
};
```

Finally we wrap it all up an a helper class `ToFoo` which takes 2 `Packs` and defines a type alias:

```
template<typename T0, typename T1>
struct ToFoo;

template<typename... P0, typename... P1>
struct ToFoo<Pack<P0...>, Pack<P1...>>
{
    using type = typename TupleToFoo<typename Interleaved<Pack<int, char>, Pack<double, const char*>>::type>::type;
};
```

Full working example: ([coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/81a8703b174928a9))

```
#include <tuple>

template <class Tuple1, class Tuple2, std::size_t ... indices>
auto interleave(Tuple1 t1, Tuple2 t2, std::integer_sequence<std::size_t, indices...>)
{
    return std::tuple_cat(std::make_tuple(std::get<indices>(t1),
                                          std::get<indices>(t2))...);
}

template <class Tuple1, class Tuple2>
auto interleave(Tuple1 t1, Tuple2 t2)
{
    return interleave(t1, t2, std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size<Tuple1>::value>());
}

template<typename... Ts>
struct Pack 
{
    using type = std::tuple<Ts...>;
};

template<typename T0, typename T1>
struct Interleaved;

template<typename... P0, typename... P1>
struct Interleaved<Pack<P0...>, Pack<P1...>>
{
    using Pack0 = typename Pack<P0...>::type;
    using Pack1 = typename Pack<P1...>::type;

    using type = decltype(interleave(std::declval<Pack0>(), std::declval<Pack1>()));
};

template<typename... Ts>
struct Foo 
{};

template<typename T>
struct TupleToFoo;

template<typename... Ts>
struct TupleToFoo<std::tuple<Ts...>>
{
    using type = Foo<Ts...>;
};

template<typename T0, typename T1>
struct ToFoo;

template<typename... P0, typename... P1>
struct ToFoo<Pack<P0...>, Pack<P1...>>
{
    using type = typename TupleToFoo<typename Interleaved<Pack<int, char>, Pack<double, const char*>>::type>::type;
};


int main()
{
    using T1 = Foo<int, double, char, const char*>;
    using T2 = typename ToFoo<Pack<int, char>, Pack<double, const char*>>::type;

    static_assert(std::is_same<T1, T2>::value, "passed");
    return 0;
}
```