# Unable to use std::bind with variadic template parameters

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, lambda, bind

I'm working on implementing a wrapper for `std::thread` that will allow me retrieve arbitrary return values after the thread is finished executing. While I am using `C++11`, I am using an older `ARM` architecture that does not support fully support atomic int's, which means that I can't use `std::future`, `std::promise`, `std::packaged_task`, and much of the stl threading functionality (I do get `std::thread` at least). I am testing with `gcc 4.8.4`.

While working on my implementation, I ran into [this bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=41933), which makes it impossible for me capture variadic template parameters with a lambda. Unfortunately, I can not upgrade my compiler to 4.9 at the moment.

I'm attempting to implement a workaround using `std::bind`, but am running into quite a few issues. I'm unsure if these are compiler bugs or implementation errors on my part. Here is the source:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <thread>

#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>

class ConcurrentTaskBase
{
public:
   ConcurrentTaskBase(int priority, const std::function<void()>& runTask)
      : m_thread(),
        m_active(true)
   {
      auto wrap = [this](int priority, const std::function<void()>& runTask)
      {
         //Unrelated pthread stuff that I commented out
//         sched_param param{priority};
//
//         int err = pthread_setschedparam(pthread_self(), SCHED_RR, &param);
//         if (err)
//            cout << "failed to set new priority: " << err << endl;

         runTask();
      };
      m_thread = std::thread(wrap, priority, runTask);
   }

   virtual ~ConcurrentTaskBase(void)
   {
      waitForCompletion();
   }

   void waitForCompletion(void)
   {
      if (m_active)
      {
         m_thread.join();
         m_active = false;
      }
   }

private:
   std::thread m_thread;
   bool m_active;
};

template<class R, class... ArgTypes>
class ConcurrentTask;

template<class R, class... ArgTypes>
class ConcurrentTask<R(ArgTypes...)> : public ConcurrentTaskBase
{
public:
   ConcurrentTask(int priority, const std::function<R(ArgTypes...)>& task, ArgTypes&&... args)
      : ConcurrentTaskBase(priority, bindTask(task, std::forward<ArgTypes>(args)...))
   {}

   std::shared_ptr<R> getReturn(void) noexcept
   {
      waitForCompletion();
      return m_storage;
   };

private:
   static std::function<void(void)> bindTask(const std::function<R(ArgTypes...)>& task, ArgTypes&&... args)
   {
      auto action = [task](ArgTypes&&... args) -> void
      {
         //Eventually m_storage = std::make_shared<R>(task(std::forward<ArgTypes>(args)...)); after bugs are fixed
         task(std::forward<ArgTypes>(args)...);
         return;
      };
      std::function<void(void)> bound = std::bind(action, std::forward<ArgTypes>(args)...);
      return bound;
   };

   std::shared_ptr<R> m_storage;
};

int testFunction(int val)
{
   std::cout << "Was given " << val << std::endl;
   return val + 10;
}

int main()
{
   ConcurrentTask<int(int)> task(20, testFunction, 5);
//   shared_ptr<int> received = task.getReturn();
//   testFunction(*received);
   return 0;
}
```

And here is my compiler output:

```
16:31:00 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project TestLinuxMint ****
make all 
Building file: ../src/TestLinuxMint.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -std=c++0x -O0 -g3 -Wall -pthread -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/TestLinuxMint.d" -MT"src/TestLinuxMint.o" -o "src/TestLinuxMint.o" "../src/TestLinuxMint.cpp"
../src/TestLinuxMint.cpp: In instantiation of ‘static std::function<void()> ConcurrentTask<R(ArgTypes ...)>::bindTask(const std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>&, ArgTypes&& ...) [with R = int; ArgTypes = {int}]’:
../src/TestLinuxMint.cpp:58:84:   required from ‘ConcurrentTask<R(ArgTypes ...)>::ConcurrentTask(int, const std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>&, ArgTypes&& ...) [with R = int; ArgTypes = {int}]’
../src/TestLinuxMint.cpp:91:53:   required from here
../src/TestLinuxMint.cpp:76:90: error: conversion from ‘std::_Bind_helper<false, ConcurrentTask<R(ArgTypes ...)>::bindTask(const std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>&, ArgTypes&& ...) [with R = int; ArgTypes = {int}]::__lambda1&, int>::type {aka std::_Bind<ConcurrentTask<R(ArgTypes ...)>::bindTask(const std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>&, ArgTypes&& ...) [with R = int; ArgTypes = {int}]::__lambda1(int)>}’ to non-scalar type ‘std::function<void()>’ requested
       std::function<void(void)> bound = std::bind(action, std::forward<ArgTypes>(args)...);
                                                                                          ^
make: *** [src/TestLinuxMint.o] Error 1

16:31:01 Build Finished (took 319ms)
```

The issue seems to be on `line 76`, where there is a failed conversion from `std::bind(*) to std::function<void(void)>`. This code is definitely still under development, but I need to get past this issue to move forward. I've looked at multiple other posts here on SO, but all of them seem to be able to use std::bind on variadic template parameters without issue.

**SOLUTION**

Here is the final solution (as pertaining to this question) that I came up with thanks to kzraq and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17424477/implementation-c14-make-integer-sequence/17426611#17426611).

Source:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
#include <type_traits>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <tuple>
#include <memory>

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
template <std::size_t... Ints>
struct idx_sequence
{
   using type = idx_sequence;
   using value_type = std::size_t;
   static constexpr std::size_t size() noexcept { return sizeof...(Ints); }
};

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
template <class Sequence1, class Sequence2>
struct _merge_and_renumber;

template <std::size_t... I1, std::size_t... I2>
struct _merge_and_renumber<idx_sequence<I1...>, idx_sequence<I2...> >
   : idx_sequence<I1..., (sizeof...(I1)+I2)...>
{
};

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
template <std::size_t N>
struct make_idx_sequence : _merge_and_renumber<make_idx_sequence<N/2>, make_idx_sequence<N - N/2> >
{
};
template<> struct make_idx_sequence<0> : idx_sequence<> { };
template<> struct make_idx_sequence<1> : idx_sequence<0> { };

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
template<typename Func, typename Tuple, std::size_t... Ints>
auto applyImpl(Func&& f, Tuple&& params, idx_sequence<Ints...>)
   -> decltype(f(std::get<Ints>(std::forward<Tuple>(params))...))
{
    return f(std::get<Ints>(std::forward<Tuple>(params))...);
};

template<typename Func, typename Tuple>
auto apply(Func&& f, Tuple&& params)
   -> decltype(applyImpl(std::forward<Func>(f),
               std::forward<Tuple>(params),
               make_idx_sequence<std::tuple_size<typename std::decay<Tuple>::type>::value>{}))
{
    return applyImpl(std::forward<Func>(f),
                     std::forward<Tuple>(params),
                     make_idx_sequence<std::tuple_size<typename std::decay<Tuple>::type>::value>{});
};

class ConcurrentTaskBase
{
public:
    ConcurrentTaskBase(int priority, const std::function<void()>& task)
        : m_thread(),
          m_active(true)
    {
        auto wrap = [this](int priority, const std::function<void()>& task)
        {
           //Unrelated pthread stuff that I commented out
           sched_param param{priority};

           int err = pthread_setschedparam(pthread_self(), SCHED_RR, &param);
           if (err)
              std::cout << "failed to set new priority: " << err << std::endl;

           task();
        };
        m_thread = std::thread(wrap, priority, task);
    }

    virtual ~ConcurrentTaskBase(void)
    {
        waitForCompletion();
    }

    void waitForCompletion(void)
    {
        if (m_active)
        {
            m_thread.join();
            m_active = false;
        }
    }

private:
    std::thread m_thread;
    bool m_active;
};

template<class R, class... ArgTypes>
class ConcurrentTask;

template<class R, class... ArgTypes>
class ConcurrentTask<R(ArgTypes...)> : public ConcurrentTaskBase
{
public:
    ConcurrentTask(int priority, const std::function<R(ArgTypes...)>& task, ArgTypes&&... args)
    : ConcurrentTaskBase(priority, bindTask(task, std::forward<ArgTypes>(args)...))
    {}

    std::shared_ptr<R> getReturn(void) noexcept
    {
        waitForCompletion();
        return m_storage;
    }

private:
    std::function<void(void)> bindTask(const std::function<R(ArgTypes...)>& task, ArgTypes&&... args)
    {
        auto params = std::make_tuple(args...);
        return [this, task, params](){m_storage = std::make_shared<R>(apply(task, params));};
    };
    std::shared_ptr<R> m_storage;
};

template<class... ArgTypes>
class ConcurrentTask<void(ArgTypes...)> : public ConcurrentTaskBase
{
public:
    ConcurrentTask(int priority, const std::function<void(ArgTypes...)>& task, ArgTypes&&... args)
       : ConcurrentTaskBase(priority, bindTask(task, std::forward<ArgTypes>(args)...))
    {}

private:
    std::function<void(void)> bindTask(const std::function<void(ArgTypes...)>& task, ArgTypes&&... args)
    {
        auto params = std::make_tuple(args...);
        return [this, task, params](){apply(task, params);};
    };
};

// Example stuff
struct MyStruct
{
    int x;
    int y;
};
int testFunction(MyStruct val)
{
    std::cout << "X is " << val.x << " Y is " << val.y << std::endl;
    return val.x + 10;
}

void printMe(int x)
{
    std::cout << "Printing " << x << std::endl;
}
int main()
{
    ConcurrentTask<int(MyStruct)> task(20, testFunction, {5, -21});
    std::shared_ptr<int> received = task.getReturn();
    std::cout << "Return value is " << *received << std::endl;

    ConcurrentTask<void(int)> voidTask(25, printMe, -123);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The CPU architecture should not effect the presence of `std::future` and co. If there is no hardware support the standard library is supposed to emulate it using locks etc.......

Comment: You are correct, locks could be used. However, the C++ library that I use REQUIRES `__GCC_ATOMIC_INT_LOCK_FREE` to be greater then 1 (all ints guaranteed to be lock free). Running the command `echo | arm-linux-g++ -dM -E - | grep -i atomic` returns a value of 1, indicating for my architecture that not all int types are completely atomic. My options are either change my library implementation (quite a bit of work - need to make sure library doesn't grow too big), change my processor (not an option), or write a small wrapper to fix my problem.

Comment: @zeus_masta_funk do you need a separate base class?

Comment: I will eventually need a separate base class for the case of `void(*)`. The base class allows me to avoid duplicate code but to specialize for cases that don't need storage, such as the one I just listed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more or less what Yakk wrote about. Maybe I do not understand your idea well enough, but to me it seems that you've overengineered it and you're using `std::function` too early. Also, `ArgTypes&&` won't be a list of forwarding/universal references, since they're not deduced in `bindTask`.

The following [compiles successfully](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/vEmxs8GjWvAq9Mw7) on gcc 4.8.2:

Get your own `integer_sequence` for C++11. Courtesy of [Xeo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17426611/2456565).

Write `apply` to apply tuple parameters to a function (maybe this could be improved):

```
template<typename Func, typename Tuple, unsigned int... is>
auto apply_impl(Func&& f, Tuple&& params, seq<is...>)
    // -> decltype(f(std::get<is>(std::forward<Tuple>(params))...)) // C++11 only
{
  using std::get; // enable ADL-lookup for get in C++14
  return f(get<is>(std::forward<Tuple>(params))...);
}

template<typename Func, typename Tuple>
auto apply(Func&& f, Tuple&& params)
    // -> decltype(apply_impl(std::forward<Func>(f), std::forward<Tuple>(params),
    //    GenSeq<std::tuple_size<typename std::decay<Tuple>::type>::value>{}))
    // C++11 only
{
    return apply_impl(std::forward<Func>(f), std::forward<Tuple>(params),
        GenSeq<std::tuple_size<typename std::decay<Tuple>::type>::value>{});
}
```

Simplify your `bindTask` (though at this point I'd keep it as a template):

```
auto params = make_tuple(args...);
std::function<void(void)> bound = [task,params]{ apply(task, params); };
return bound;
```

In C++14 do `[task=std::move(task),params=std::move(params)]` to avoid needless copies.

Comment: Thanks for helping! After going through the example I have some questions. I don't understand the `gen_seq` structure. I see it inherits from from `Concat<*>` and applied a test. Say we use `gen_seq<4>`, we inherit from `Concat<GenSeq<2>, GenSeq<2>>`. Each of those then recursively inherits from `Concat<GenSeq<1>, GenSeq<1>>`, all the way down to `GenSeq<1>` (or 0) which inherits from `seq<>` eventually. Why is this tree structure needed?

Comment: Next, what does `struct seq` accomplish, does it just set its `type` member to itself? That doesn't seem very useful at first glance. Again, thanks for the help.

Comment: It's [`index_sequence`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence) for C++11, more or less. It generates a variadic template instantiation `seq<0,1,2....n-1>` for `GenSeq<n>`. This allows you to unpack a tuple with the `get<n>` function template, thus allowing `apply` to pass the parameters to the function

Comment: @zeus_masta_funk I'm not sure if I explained it well enough. Basically, `apply` calls `apply_impl` with the forwarded params + `seq<0...n-1>`. `GenSeq<n>` generates that sequence. `apply_impl` then is capable of getting values `0..n-1` as the variadic pack and use them to expand `get<i>(tuple)...` calls, so that all parameters are passed to the function.

Comment: Thanks, I think I understand it better now and will post the final solution soon. One last comment though: The `apply` and `apply_impl` function use auto as a return type, which is not valid in C++11. I attempted to update this using `std::result_of` but was unsuccessful because `std::result_of<Func(Tuple)>::type` is not valid. `Func` does not normally take a tuple, so the resulting type is unable to be found. For now I just "cheated" and added an extra template parameter for the return type. Is there a better way to do this using just C++11?

Comment: Just copy the expression returned. I'll edit the example.

Comment: @zeus_masta_funk edited the example. In C++11 you could have `auto` return types, but you had to specify them before the function body. In very many cases this ended up with major code duplication, especially since `noexcept(noexcept(expr))` meant yet another copy.

Comment: I see, I simply forgot about specifying the return type with `decltype`.

Comment: removed dependency on `using namespace std;`, set up ADL-enabled `get` to work like how C++17 structured binding extension of tuple-likes works.  @zeus_masta_funk avoid `using namespace std;`, search the internet if you don't trust me why.

Comment: @Yakk that may be my fault, my code testing template uses namespace std and I must've left that in.

Comment: @krzaq OP's code has `using namespace std;` as well, so...  :)

Comment: @Yakk: Of course :) I'm well aware of why, and yes I'm guilty of trying to push this out quick and taking a shortcut. Will update momentarily...

Answer (score 2):

As a guess, bind presumes it can be called repeatedly (esp when called in an lvalue context!), so does not turn rvalue parameters into rvalue parameters to its bound function as rvalue parameters.  Which your code demands.  That lambda is not perfect forwarding!

You are also capturing `const&` `std::function`s by reference in lambdas, which just invites dangling reference hell.  But that is a runtime problem.  As a general rule never `&` capture unless lifetime of lambda and all copies ends in the current scope; definitely don't do it during prototyping even if "certain" it won't be a problem.

I would consider writing a weak version of `std::apply` and `index_sequence`s and packing the arguments into a `tuple` then doing your `apply` to unpack into the target callable.  But that is a bias, dunno if ideal.

Comment: I see, thanks for the advice, I will likely follow this idea.