# how to write a fold /sum function for C++ tuple?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17, stdtuple

I wanted to write a `fold` function for `std::tuple` that can compute e.g. the sum (or product) of all the elements in a given tuple. For example, given

```
std::tuple<int,double> t = std::make_tuple(1,2);
```

I'd like to compute

```
auto s = sumT(t); //giving 3
```

I tried but couldn't get my template programming (c++11/1z) code below to compile. I also tried to adapt the accepted answer for my other question ([How to perform tuple arithmetic in C++ (c++11/c++17)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47209672/683218)), but can't figure out how to use `std::index_sequence` in this case.

The issues I have are:

1) I can't figure out the types, e.g. how to use the type of the first element as the return type. Currently, I use a `_res` type in the template, but I don't know if that will block c++'s auto type-inferencing.

2) I'd like to program this without using an explicit initial element `0`, so that this can be used for other kinds of `fold` operations.

Currently, the recursion ends at the last element. I'd like to end the recursion at `_size - 1` so that I can directly perform the operation on the last element without resorting to `0`.

The code I have below tries to do this by recursion. But I don't know template programming well, and how the loops work for tuples.

*Can someone help fix the code or come up with a better solution?*

My code so far is:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

// helper class for fold operations
template<typename Op,typename _res, typename _Tp, size_t _i, size_t _size>
struct _tuple_fold  {
    static constexpr _res _op(Op const & op, const _Tp& _t) {
      return _res(op(std::get<_i>(_t),
                _tuple_fold<Op, _res, _Tp, _i + 1, _size>::_op(op,_t) ));
    }
};

template<typename Op,typename _res,typename _Tp, size_t _size>
struct _tuple_fold<Op, _res,_Tp, _size, _size> {
  static constexpr _res _op(Op const &, const _Tp&) { return 0; }
};

template <typename ... Ts>
auto sumT (std::tuple<Ts...> const & t1)  {
  return _tuple_fold::_op(std::plus<>{}, t1);
}

int main () {
  std::tuple<int,double> t = std::make_tuple(1,2);
  auto s = sumT(t);
  std::cout << s << std::endl;
}
```

The error messages for compiling with `g++ -std=c++17 tuple_sum.cpp`:

```
tuple_sum.cpp: In function ‘auto sumT(const std::tuple<_Elements ...>&)’:
tuple_sum.cpp:21:10: error: ‘template<class Op, class _res, class _Tp, long unsigned int _i, long unsigned int _size> struct _tuple_fold’ used without template parameters
   return _tuple_fold::_op(std::plus<>{}, t1);
          ^
tuple_sum.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
tuple_sum.cpp:27:19: error: ‘void s’ has incomplete type
    auto s = sumT(t);
                   ^
```

I'm not sure how to supply the type parameters for `_tuple_fold` on the call site, especially the type for `std::plus`.

Comment: [std::accumulate](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate) with a lambda should do nicely I think.

Comment: @JesperJuhl nope, you cannot take usual iterators from an etherogeneous container ( like tuple<int,double> )

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/40700181/305118

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thankfully, `if constexpr` in C++17 allows us to avoid complicating things by introducing partially specialized helper structs, and makes it easy to terminate the recursion on whatever condition we want:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>

template <size_t index, class Op, class... Ts>
constexpr auto tuple_fold(Op op, const std::tuple<Ts...>& t) {
    if constexpr(index == sizeof...(Ts) - 1) {
        return std::get<index>(t);
    } else {
        return op(std::get<index>(t), tuple_fold<1 + index>(op, t));
    }
}

template <typename ... Ts>
constexpr auto sumT (std::tuple<Ts...> const & t1)  {
  return tuple_fold<0>(std::plus<>{}, t1);
}

int main () {
  std::tuple<int,double> t = {1, 2.0};
  auto s = sumT(t);
  static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(s), double>);
  std::cout << s << std::endl;
}
```

Coliru link: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1e7051b8652fb942

This will perform a right fold, `a + (b + (c + ...))` but it's easy to rewrite it to perform a left fold instead, if you want.

Answer (score 24):

note that in c++17 we can *apply()* and *fold*:

```
auto t = std::make_tuple( 1, 2. );
auto sum = std::apply([]( auto... v ){ return ( v + ... ); }, t );
```

this will work for any tuple-like type and follows usual promotion/conversion rules for '+' out of the box ( this may or may not be desirable ). In the above I pass by value because we're dealing with arithmetic types, but you can apply your preferred forwarding strategy of course...

Comment: This works great when you know and can hard-code the folding operator +.

Answer (score 4):

We can leverage [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17)'s left and right fold builtins to fold over any binary operation.

```
template<class F, class Lhs=void>
struct invoke_by_times_t {
  F& f;
  Lhs lhs;
  template<class Rhs>
  auto operator*( Rhs&& rhs )&&
  ->invoke_by_times_t<F, std::invoke_result_t< F&, Lhs, Rhs >>
  {
    return {
      f,
      f(std::forward<Lhs>(lhs), std::forward<Rhs>(rhs))
    };
  }
};

template<class F>
struct invoke_by_times_t<F, void> {
  F& f;
  template<class Rhs>
  invoke_by_times_t<F, Rhs> operator*( Rhs&& rhs )&&{
    return {f, std::forward<Rhs>(rhs)};
  }
};

template<class F>
auto fold_over( F&& f ) {
  return [f=std::forward<F>(f)](auto&&...args)mutable{
    return ( invoke_by_times_t<F>{f}*...*decltype(args)(args) ).lhs;
  };
}
```

now given any binary function we can create a function object that folds over it without doing any recursion.

Together with `std::apply` we are done.

```
template <typename ... Ts>
auto sumT (std::tuple<Ts...> const & t1)  {
  return std::apply( fold_over(std::plus<>{}), t1);
}
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0719ba4b659ad52f)

This is a left fold.  A right fold simply involves changing the `fold_over` function.  If you try to pass an empty pack to this, it will fail to compile.  If you pass it one element, it will return that element.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>

namespace detail {

template<class F, class T>
struct foldable : std::pair<const F&, T> {
    using std::pair<const F&, T>::pair;

    template<class V>
    constexpr decltype(auto) operator&&(foldable<F, V>&& x) {
        return detail::foldable {
            this->first,
            this->first(this->second, x.second),
        };
    }
};

template<class F, class T> foldable(const F&, T&&) -> foldable<F, T>;

}

// Folds left a parameter pack
template<class F, class... Args>
constexpr decltype(auto) fold_left_pack(const F& f, Args&&... args) {
    static_assert(sizeof...(Args) > 0, "Cannot fold an empty pack.");
    return (... && detail::foldable { f, std::forward<Args>(args) }).second;
}

// Folds right a parameter pack
template<class F, class... Args>
constexpr decltype(auto) fold_right_pack(const F& f, Args&&... args) {
    static_assert(sizeof...(Args) > 0, "Cannot fold an empty pack.");
    return (detail::foldable { f, std::forward<Args>(args) } && ...).second;
}

// Folds left a tuple
template<class F, class Tuple>
constexpr decltype(auto) fold_left(const F& f, Tuple&& tuple) {
    return std::apply(
        [&](auto&&... args) -> decltype(auto) {
            return fold_left_pack(f, std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);
        },
        std::forward<Tuple>(tuple));
}

// Folds right a tuple
template<class F, class Tuple>
constexpr decltype(auto) fold_right(const F& f, Tuple&& tuple) {
    return std::apply(
        [&](auto&&... args) -> decltype(auto) {
            return fold_right_pack(f, std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);
        },
        std::forward<Tuple>(tuple));
}
```

A test:

```
constexpr auto divide = [](auto x, auto y) { return x / y; };
constexpr auto tuple = std::make_tuple(8, 4, 2);
static_assert(1 == fold_left(divide, tuple));
static_assert(4 == fold_right(divide, tuple));
```