# std::forward_as_tuple to pass arguments to 2 constructors

Tags: c++, c++11, tuples

I would like to pass multiple arguments in order to construct two objects inside a function, the same way `std::pair<T1, T2>(std::piecewise_construct, ...)` works.

So I wrote

```
template <typename Args0..., typename Args1...>
void f(std::tuple<Arg0> args0, std::tuple<Args1> args1) {
   Object0 alpha(...);
   Object1 beta(...);
   ...
}
```

so I can call

```
f(std::forward_as_tuple(..., ..., ...), std::forward_as_tuple(..., ...))
```

But I don't know how to construct `Object0` and `Object1`. I have checked the source code of my standard library for `std::pair` and they seems to use complicated internal functions to get the indices of args0 and args1. Do you have any idea on how to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C++17 will have `make_from_tuple` for doing this, but you can write this in C++11. Here's a C++14 version  stolen from [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/make_from_tuple) (for C++11 you can use the implementation of `std::index_sequence` from [Implementation C++14 make_integer_sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17424477/implementation-c14-make-integer-sequence)).

```
namespace detail {
template <class T, class Tuple, std::size_t... I>
constexpr T make_from_tuple_impl( Tuple&& t, std::index_sequence<I...> )
{
  return T(std::get<I>(std::forward<Tuple>(t))...);
}
} // namespace detail

template <class T, class Tuple>
constexpr T make_from_tuple( Tuple&& t )
{
    return detail::make_from_tuple_impl<T>(std::forward<Tuple>(t),
        std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size<std::decay_t<Tuple>>::value>{});
}
```

With this utility, the implementation of `f` is a breeze:

```
template <typename... Args0, typename... Args1>
void f(std::tuple<Args0...> args0, std::tuple<Args1...> args1) {
   auto alpha = make_from_tuple<Object0>(args0);
   auto beta = make_from_tuple<Object1>(args1);
}
```

To make it more generic, I'd recommend just deducing the types of those tuples and perfect-forwarding them:

```
template <typename T0, typename T1>
void f(T0&& args0, T1&& args1) {
   auto alpha = make_from_tuple<Object0>(std::forward<T0>(args0));
   auto beta = make_from_tuple<Object1>(std::forward<T1>(args1));
}
```

[Live C++11 demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/859b956248e783a9)

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, I need to be compatible with gcc 4.8.5 provided by RHEL 7. So I guess, I need to implement make_index_sequence in C++11 which is exactly what I found in the standard library for std::pair.

Comment: @InsideLoop Cool, I added a live demo working in C++11.