# std::forward cannot convert brace-enclosed initializer list

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, variadic-functions, forward

Why can't struct screen not initialize the frame struct properly?

What I want is to initialize the screen struct and directly initialize the 2 frame structs as well.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <cstring>

#define ESC "\033"

struct frame {
  public:
    frame(unsigned int w, unsigned int h) :
      m_w(w),
      m_h(h) {}

  private:
    unsigned int m_w, m_h;
};

struct screen {
  public:
    template<typename ... Args>
      screen(Args && ... args0, Args && ... args1) :
        m_f0(std::forward<Args>(args0)...),
        m_f1(std::forward<Args>(args1)...) {}

  private:
    frame m_f0, m_f1;
};

int main() {
  frame f = {16, 16};

  screen s = {f, {16, 16}};

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: *braced-init-list* do not have a type so they cannot be given to a template without specifying the type you want it to represent.

Comment: @NathanOliver `screen s = {f, f};` does not work either.

Comment: @DanielLangr Correct.  `{f, f}` is one object so it trys to deduce `Args` with it and can't because `{f, f}` doesn't have a type.

Comment: @NathanOliver And what about `screen s(f, f)`? My point is that the OP's problem is in my opinion not about _braced-init-list_, as you suggest in the duplicate. It's about multiple parameter packs.

Comment: I recommend looking at how [`std::pair`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/pair) forwards two sets of arguments to its two data members' constructors.

Comment: @DanielLangr Okay.  I've reopened.

Comment: In a function template, a parameter pack which is not at the end of the parameter declaration list is a non-deduced context. So the type of `args0` cannot be deduced.

Answer (score 3):

`{16, 16}` has no type.  If used in a context to initialize something with a type, it initializes that thing.

Constructor arguments have a type.  Deduced template constructor arguments get their type from the argument passed.  But `{16,16}` has no type, so it cannot deduce a type from something that lacks a type.

Your second problem is this:

```
  template<typename ... Args>
  screen(Args && ... args0, Args && ... args1) :
    m_f0(std::forward<Args>(args0)...),
    m_f1(std::forward<Args>(args1)...) {}
```

C++ won't deduce `Args...` for you here.  It will only deduce an argument pack if it is the last arguments in the function call, and here `Args...` is both the last and not the last, so it won't be deduced.

Now you can use [make from tuple](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/make_from_tuple) to some extent:

```
template<class...Args0, class...Args1>
screen( std::tuple<Args0...> args0, std::tuple<Args1...> args1 ):
  m_f0(std::make_from_tuple<frame>(std::move(args0))),
  m_f1(std::make_from_tuple<frame>(std::move(args1)))
{}
```

which gets you a touch closer (but not close enough).  At the call site you'd do:

```
screen s = {std::forward_as_tuple(f), std::forward_as_tuple(16, 16)};
```

and it should now work.

This uses [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17), but `make_from_tuple` can be implemented as far back as [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) or [in C++14](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41439982/1774667).

Comment: Wouldn't be better to use two template parameter packs, for each function parameter a separate one? In your case, you are actually not forwarding `16, 16` perfectly, since a temporary `frame` is created and forwarded.

Comment: Thi answer is related if you don't have C++17: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41439982/580083.

Comment: @DanielLangr Fixed.  Note that in C++17, `make_from_tuple` returns a prvalue which isn't a temporary object.  So the forwarding is perfect.  In C++14/11 it isn't perfect, and making it perfect is a really big hassle.