# Iterate with constexpr

Tags: c++, c++11

I'd like to write something like that :

```
template<int i> void f() {}

for (constexpr int i : {1,2,3})
{
    f<i>();
}
```

Is it possible to iterate on constexpr ?

Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you probably understand, you cannot do the like of:

```
for (constexpr int i : {1,2,3})
{
    f<i>();
}
```

because, if `i` is to vary from 1 through 3 in a loop, then it is a *variable* and
not a compiletime constant. And a variable cannot be a template argument,
as in `f<i>`: only a compiletime constant can be a template argument.

In C++11 and later, thanks to [variadic templates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_template),
you can effectively iterate over an arbitary sequence of compiletime constants
by using compiletime recursion of a template function that accepts a suitable arbitrary sequence
of template arguments.

That will hardly mean anything to you if you don't already know how to do it.
Here is a C++11 example that does what you want to express:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

template<int i> void f()
{
    std::cout << i << '\n';
}

// This overload is chosen when there is only 1 template argument.
template<int First, int ...Rest>
typename std::enable_if<sizeof...(Rest) == 0>::type
for_each_f()
{
    f<First>();
}

// This overload is chosen when there is > 1 template argument.
template<int First, int ...Rest>
typename std::enable_if<sizeof...(Rest) != 0>::type
for_each_f()
{
    f<First>();
    for_each_f<Rest...>();
}

int main()
{
    for_each_f<2,3,5,7,11>();
    return 0;
}
```

[See it live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/621a97aa2cfb0ead)

Besides variadic templates, this technique depends on the very important C++ meta-programming 
principle of [SFINAE](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae), and on [`std::enable_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if),
which is the tool that the Standard C++ library provides for exploiting SFINAE.

101010's answer demonstrates a more sophisticated and powerful style of
solution that is available in C++14 (and easy enough to implement in C++11
if you write some supporting boilerplate).

Comment: TBH I prefer this approach. There is _so_ much horrid hackery around that initialisation of `int t[]` (C++'s fault, not 101010's) that I would have to be given a lot of money before I chose to go down that route!

Comment: you can get rid of the `enable_if`s if you change the template signatures to  `template<int First> for_each_f();` and `template<int First, int Second, int ...Rest> for_each_f();`

Answer (score 5):

No you can't use a for loop to iterate over at compile time. The for control structure in C++ is used for runtime control flow.

However, you could use other compile time facilities. For example in C++ 14 you could achieve what you want in the following manner:

1. Define a template wrapper class that's gonna call your function.

   > ```
   > template<int i>
   > struct wrapper {
   >   void operator()() const { f<i>(); }
   > };
   > ```
2. Use [std::index_sequence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence) to generate compile time indices.

   > ```
   > template<template<int> class W, std::size_t... I>
   > void caller_impl(std::index_sequence<I...>) {
   >   int t[] = { 0, ((void)W<I>()(), 1)... };
   >   (void) t;
   > }  
   >
   > template<template<int> class W, std::size_t N, typename Indices = std::make_index_sequence<N>>
   > void call_times() {
   >   caller_impl<W>(Indices());
   > }
   > ```
3. Then call as

   > ```
   > int main() {
   >   call_times<wrapper, 42>();
   > }
   > ```

   [**Live Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/26e9e67d47edd418)

If C++14 is not an option you could take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17424477/implementation-c14-make-integer-sequence) of how you could implement `std::index_sequence` your self.

Comment: What is `(void) t` for?

Comment: @DeanSeo suppress compiler warning for unused variable.

Comment: If you have c++17, then the `caller_impl` function body can be `(W<I>()(), ... );` Much easier to understand.