# How to initialize an array in constructor by the argument?

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc

How to initialize an array in constructor by the argument? I think `type (&name)[size]` syntax is pretty good and compiler maintainers can implement this easily. Is there a paragraph in the standard prohibiting such initialization?

#### Code:

```
struct Test
{
    char characters_[3];
    Test(char (&characters)[3]) : characters_(characters) {}
};
```

#### GCC version:

```
gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 5.4.0 20160609
```

### GCC output:

```
FAILED: /usr/bin/c++     -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wfloat-equal -std=c++11 -pg   -m32 -std=gnu++11 -MMD -MT CMakeFiles/Test.dir/test.cpp.o -MF CMakeFiles/Test.dir/test.cpp.o.d -o CMakeFiles/Test.dir/test.cpp.o -c /home/user/Desktop/programms/test/Test/test.cpp
In file included from /home/user/Desktop/programms/test/Test/test.cpp:1:0:
/home/user/Desktop/programms/test/Test/test.h: In constructor ‘Test::Test(char (&)[3])’:
/home/user/Desktop/programms/test/Test/test.h:38:54: error: array used as initializer
  Test(char (&characters)[3]) : characters_(characters) {}
                                                      ^
FAILED: /usr/bin/c++     -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wfloat-equal -std=c++11 -pg   -m32 -std=gnu++11 -MMD -MT CMakeFiles/Test.dir/main.cpp.o -MF CMakeFiles/Test.dir/main.cpp.o.d -o CMakeFiles/Test.dir/main.cpp.o -c /home/user/Desktop/programms/test/Test/main.cpp
In file included from /home/user/Desktop/programms/test/Test/main.cpp:4:0:
/home/user/Desktop/programms/test/Test/test.h: In constructor ‘Test::Test(char (&)[3])’:
/home/user/Desktop/programms/test/Test/test.h:38:54: error: array used as initializer
  Test(char (&characters)[3]) : characters_(characters) {}
                                                      ^
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps the simplest solution is to use `std::array` instead:

```
std::array<char, 3> characters;
Test(std::array<char, 3> characters) : characters(characters) {}
```

Prior to C++11, one would have copied the argument array in the body of the constructor:

```
Test(char (&characters)[3]) {
    std::copy(characters, characters + sizeof characters, this->characters);
}
```

Or would have used a custom `std::array`-like wrapper.

---

> Is there a paragraph in the standard prohibiting such initialization?

There sure is (standard draft):

> [dcl.init]/17 The semantics of initializers are as follows. The destination type is the type of the object or reference being
>   initialized and the source type is the type of the initializer expression. [snip]
>
> - (17.1) — If the initializer is a (non-parenthesized) braced-init-list or is = braced-init-list, the object or reference is
>     list-initialized (8.6.4).
> - (17.2) — If the destination type is a reference type, see 8.6.3.
> - (17.3) — If the destination type is an array of characters, an array of char16_t, an array of char32_t, or an
>     array of wchar_t, and the initializer is a string literal, see 8.6.2.
> - (17.4) — If the initializer is (), the object is value-initialized.
> - (17.5) — **Otherwise, if the destination type is an array, the program is ill-formed.**
> - [snip]

As you can see, only a braced-init-list, string literal (for char arrays only), or an empty initializer are valid for arrays. Source type of an array is not allowed if destination is an array.

Answer (score 2):

In c++14 you could also make use of `std::integer_sequence` and constructor dedicated to initialize array:

```
#include <utility>

struct Test
{
    char characters_[3];

    Test(char (&characters)[3]) : Test(characters, std::make_index_sequence<3>{}) {}


    private:
    template <std::size_t N, std::size_t... Is>
    Test(char (&characters)[N], std::index_sequence<Is...>): characters_{characters[Is]...} {}
};

int main() {
    char abc[] = {'a', 'b', 'c'};
    Test test(abc);
}
```

[[live demo]](https://wandbox.org/permlink/zje9awlneu0ve4cp)

To apply it in c++11 you'd need to use one of the `std::integer_sequence` [c++11 implementations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17424477/implementation-c14-make-integer-sequence)