# std::get on std::tuple results in variadic args reducing to nothing with incomplete type error

Tags: c++11, gcc, variadic-templates, stdtuple

The following code produces a huge list of compiler errors:

```
/// Uses template recursion to bind all args
template<std::size_t N, typename... Args> class Binder
{
public:
    Binder(Sqlite3StatementBase &s, std::tuple<Args...> &tup)
    {
        Binder<N - 1, Args...> b(s, tup);
        s.bind(N + 1, std::get<N, Args...>(tup)); // Line 182
    }
};

/// Specialization of Binder to end recursion at 0
template<typename... Args> class Binder<0, Args...>
{
public:
    Binder(Sqlite3StatementBase &s, std::tuple<Args...> &tup)
    {
        s.bind(1, std::get<0, Args...>(tup));
    }
};
```

The first batch of errors consists of:

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/6/bits/unique_ptr.h:37:0,
             from /usr/include/c++/6/condition_variable:43,
             from /home/tony/htpc/Dev/logi/src/db/logi-db.h:22,
             from /home/tony/htpc/Dev/logi/src/db/logi-sqlite.h:26,
             from /home/tony/htpc/Dev/logi/src/db/logi-sqlite.cpp:24:
/usr/include/c++/6/tuple: In instantiation of ‘class std::tuple_element<1ul, std::tuple<unsigned int> >’:
/usr/include/c++/6/tuple:1228:12:   recursively required from ‘class std::tuple_element<2ul, std::tuple<unsigned int, unsigned int> >’
/usr/include/c++/6/tuple:1228:12:   required from ‘class std::tuple_element<3ul, std::tuple<unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int> >’
/usr/include/c++/6/utility:106:69:   required by substitution of ‘template<long unsigned int __i, class _Tp> using __tuple_element_t = typename std::tuple_element::type [with long unsigned int __i = 3ul; _Tp = std::tuple<unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int>]’
/usr/include/c++/6/tuple:1270:5:   required by substitution of ‘template<long unsigned int __i, class ... _Elements> constexpr std::__tuple_element_t<__i, std::tuple<_Elements ...> >&& std::get(std::tuple<_Elements ...>&&) [with long unsigned int __i = 3ul; _Elements = {unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int}]’
/home/tony/htpc/Dev/logi/src/db/logi-sqlite.h:182:47:   required from ‘logi::Sqlite3Database::Binder<N, Args>::Binder(logi::Sqlite3Database::Sqlite3StatementBase&, std::tuple<_Elements ...>&) [with long unsigned int N = 3ul; Args = {unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int}]’
/home/tony/htpc/Dev/logi/src/db/logi-sqlite.h:238:71:   required from ‘void logi::Sqlite3Database::Sqlite3Statement<Args>::prepare_row(logi::Sqlite3Database::Sqlite3Statement<Args>::Tup&) [with Args = {unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int}; logi::Sqlite3Database::Sqlite3Statement<Args>::Tup = std::tuple<unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int>]’
/home/tony/htpc/Dev/logi/src/db/logi-sqlite.h:231:28:   required from ‘void logi::Sqlite3Database::Sqlite3Statement<Args>::execute(typename logi::Sqlite3Database::Sqlite3Statement<Args>::Parent::ArgsVector&) [with Args = {unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int}; typename logi::Sqlite3Database::Sqlite3Statement<Args>::Parent::ArgsVector = std::vector<std::tuple<unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int>, std::allocator<std::tuple<unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int> > >]’
/home/tony/htpc/Dev/logi/src/db/logi-sqlite.cpp:354:1:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/6/tuple:1228:12: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class std::tuple_element<0ul, std::tuple<> >’
```

So it seems as if the `std::get` call is causing other parts of the system libraries (not directly related to `std::get` or `std::tuple`) to recursively reduce Args... to nothing, and this is happening independently of my recursion of the numerical template parameter N. Is there something I can fix in my code without fundamentally changing my approach, or is it just not possible to use `std::get` in a context where the tuple's template parameters are variadic?

Comment: You're approaching the problem the wrong way. What you really want is [`std::index_sequence`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence) and a decent `...` invocation. Yes, that's a C++14 tool, but it's not hard to find/write an implementation of it for C++11.

Comment: You are calling `get<3>` on a tuple with three elements - of course that doesn't compile. The three elements are retrieved via `get<0>` through `get<2>`. Yours is a good old-fashioned off-by-one error.

Comment: I didn't spot that off-by-one, thanks. But I've already changed it to a pre-C++11 style, providing individual templates for <T1, T2, T3, T4>, <T1, T2, T3> etc. I don't think I'll need more than 4, it's simpler than variadics and barely more verbose for up to 4.

Comment: @NicolBolas, your suggestion is intriguing, but I can't work out how `index_sequence` would help without also using a pack fold expression; perhaps that's what you meant by 'decent `...` invocation'? The trouble is, the latter is a C++17 feature. That's not a problem for me, but might be for people who want to build my code on conservative LTS/stable Linux distros.

Comment: @realh: `...` is *not* a C++17 feature. It's a C++11 feature. Using `...` for [fold expressions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold) is a C++17 feature, but you can use `...` in [plenty of other ways in C++11](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given [an implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17424477/734069) of the C++14 `make_index_sequence` function (and its associated types), you can do what you want easily enough:

```
template<size_t ...indices, typename ...Args>
void binder_helper(Sqlite3StatementBase &s, std::integer_sequence<size_t, indices...>, std::tuple<Args...> &tup)
{
    auto dump = {(s.bind(indices, std::get<indices>(tup)), 0)...};
}

template<typename ...Args>
void binder(Sqlite3StatementBase &s, std::tuple<Args...> &tup)
{
    binder_helper(s, std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Args)>(), tup);
}
```

With C++17's fold expressions, the oddball stuff in `binder_helper` can be reduced to something much more reasonable:

```
template<size_t ...indices, typename ...Args>
void binder_helper(Sqlite3StatementBase &s, std::integer_sequence<size_t, indices...>, std::tuple<Args...> &tup)
{
    (s.bind(indices, std::get<indices>(tup)), ...);
}
```

Note that in the latter case, the standard does *not* guarantee thatt the calls to `s.bind` will be executed in order. In the former case, because the expressions are wrapped in a braced-init-list, you're guaranteed in-order evaluation.

Comment: I see, C++11/14 also support the essentials of fold expressions as long as you put them in something like an argument list. This suits me very well.

Comment: @realh: No, those are not fold expressions. Please *read* the links I gave you. Pack expansion was part of C++11. Fold expressions are an expansion of pack expansions.

Comment: I did read those links, so please re-read my comment and understand that by, "the essentials of", I meant "an essential subset of features of".

Comment: @realh: And I'm telling you that's not fold expressions! Pack expansions are a *superset* of fold expressions, not the other way around.

Comment: Yes, I missed the difference between pack expansion and fold expressions at first, but I do now understand the difference expressed in **code**, and I accept your answer. We just can't agree on how to express some trivial semantics in English, so please let's just leave it.