# Swap two parameters in variadic template

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

I'm trying to swap two items of a parameter pack.

Ideally, I would like to do something like this:

```
template<int i1, int i2, class... Args>
void swapped_copy(some_class a, some_class b, Args... args) {
    a(args...) = b(/* 'args...' where parameters with indices i1 and i2 are swapped */);
}
```

Any idea?

Many thanks.

Comment: I know this is a dupe but I can't recall the context in which it came up, so I don't know what to search for any more.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a `std::tuple` to pack the args and unpack by index, and a `std::index_sequence` to generate the indexes to use.  Then it's just a matter of doing the swap on indices.  Something like this:

```
namespace swapped_copy_detail {
    constexpr std::size_t swap_one_index(
        std::size_t i1, std::size_t i2, std::size_t index) {
        return index==i1 ? i2 : (index==i2 ? i1 : index);
    }

    template <std::size_t i1, std::size_t i2, class Tuple, std::size_t... Inds>
    void do_swapped_copy(
        some_class& a, some_class& b,
        Tuple&& args,
        std::index_sequence<Inds...> inds ) {
        a(std::get<Inds>(args)...) =
            b(std::get<swap_one_index(i1, i2, Inds)>(args)...);
    }
}

template <std::size_t i1, std::size_t i2, class ...Args>
void swapped_copy(some_class a, some_class b, const Args& ...args) {
    static_assert(i1 < sizeof...(Args) && i2 < sizeof...(Args),
                  "Index too large for swapped_copy");
    swapped_copy_detail::do_swapped_copy<i1, i2>(
        a, b, std::tie(args...),
        std::index_sequence_for<Args...>());
}
```

`index_sequence` and `index_sequence_for` are in the C++14 Standard, but your question is tagged [c++11].  If you need to stick with C++11, implementations of these utilities can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20101039), for one place.

Comment: Shoudl use forward_as_tuple for thsi sort of thing, not tie.

Comment: @NirFriedman I had essentially that earlier, but each argument is used twice, so forwarding them along would not be a good idea in this case.

Comment: Indeed, this seems to be the way to go. Thanks.