# Expand two parameter packs

Tags: c++, c++11

Consider following piece of code:

```
static constexpr size_t Num {2};
struct S {
    std::array<size_t, Num> get () { return {1, 2}; }
};

struct S1 : S {};
struct S2 : S {};

struct M {
    template <typename T>
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, S1>::value, S1>::type get () const { 
        return S1 {}; 
    }

    template <typename T>
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, S2>::value, S2>::type get () const { 
        return S2 {}; 
    }
};
```

I want to have a function which merges two or more `std::array`s making one `std::array`.

So far I ended with something like this:

```
template <typename Mode, typename... Rs, size_t... Ns>
std::array<size_t, sizeof... (Rs)*Num> get_array (const Mode& mode, Sequence::Sequence<Ns...>) {
    return {std::get<Ns> (mode.template get<Rs...> ().get ())...};
}
```

I want to have that the following code

```
M m;
auto x = get_array<M, S1, S2> (m, Sequence::Make<2> {});
```

produces `std::array<size_t, 4>` filled with `{1, 2, 1, 2}`.

Where `Sequence::Sequence` and `Sequence::Make` are [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17426611).

I know that placing `...` of `Rs` is incorrect in this context (If `sizeof... (Rs)` is 1 then it is fine, `std::array<size_t, 2>` with `{1, 2}` is returned) but I have no idea where to put it to make expansion which looks like this:

```
std::get<0> (mode.template get<Rs[0]> ().get ()), 
std::get<1> (mode.template get<Rs[0]> ().get ()),
std::get<0> (mode.template get<Rs[1]> ().get ()), 
std::get<1> (mode.template get<Rs[1]> ().get ());
```

Of course `Rs[0]` I mean first type from parameter pack.

Is it even possible?

Comment: Strictly C++11 solutions? No C++14?

Comment: @AndyG unfortunately in the place where I need this I have only access to  C++11 compiler, sad but true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start with, this is basically asking to concatenate an arbitrary number of arrays. Which is very similar to concatenate an arbitrary number of tuples, for which there is a standard library function, even in C++11: [`std::tuple_cat()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tuple_cat). That gets us almost there:

```
template <class... Ts, class M>
auto get_array(M m) -> decltype(std::tuple_cat(m.template get<Ts>()...)) {
    return std::tuple_cat(m.template get<Ts>()...);
}
```

Note that I flipped the template parameters, so this is just `get_array<T1, T2>(m)` instead of having to write `get_array<M, T1, T2>(m)`.

Now the question is, how do we write `array_cat`? We'll just use `tuple_cat` and convert the resulting `tuple` to an `array`. Assume an implementation of `index_sequence` is available (which is something you'll want in your collection anyway):

```
template <class T, class... Ts, size_t... Is>
std::array<T, sizeof...(Ts)+1> to_array_impl(std::tuple<T, Ts...>&& tup,
                                             std::index_sequence<Is...> ) {
    return {{std::get<Is>(std::move(tup))...}};
}

template <class T, class... Ts>
std::array<T, sizeof...(Ts)+1> to_array(std::tuple<T, Ts...>&& tup) {
    return to_array_impl(std::move(tup), std::index_sequence_for<T, Ts...>());
}

template <class... Tuples>
auto array_cat(Tuples&&... tuples) -> decltype(to_array(std::tuple_cat(std::forward<Tuples>(tuples)...))) {
    return to_array(std::tuple_cat(std::forward<Tuples>(tuples)...));
}
```

And that gives you:

```
template <class... Ts, class M>
auto get_array(M m) -> decltype(array_cat(m.template get<Ts>()...)) {
    return array_cat(m.template get<Ts>()...);
}
```

which handles arbitrarily many types.

Comment: `tuple_cat` is allowed but not required to handle non-`std::tuple` tuple-like types, such as `std::array`.

Comment: Thank you, even though other solutions were in my opinion easier than yours, this one works with arbitrary number of arrays, so that is what I wanted.

Comment: Barry, do you know if tuple_cat creates the new tuple purely in place? I.e. it does not create any intermediate tuples? If so, I need to see how it does it. I cannot think how I would pass a variadic number of integer sequence packs...

Comment: @NirFriedman Have I got the blog post for you! http://ericniebler.com/2014/11/13/tiny-metaprogramming-library/

Comment: @Barry  Brilliant! Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that we're using [Xeo's index sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17426611/27678) implementation, we can do something like this:

First create a function for concatenating two arrays. It receives the arrays, plus an index sequence for each one (`detail::seq` is the `index_sequence` type)

```
template<class T, size_t N, size_t M, size_t... I, size_t... J>
std::array<T, N + M> concat(const std::array<T, N>& arr1, const std::array<T, M>& arr2, detail::seq<I...>, detail::seq<J...>)
{
     return {arr1[I]..., arr2[J]...};
}
```

Next, call this function from your `get_array` function, except we're going to double the `seq` that we received from the call in `main`:

```
template<class MODE, class... T, size_t... I>
auto get_array(MODE m, detail::seq<I...>) ->decltype(concat(m.template get<T>().get()..., detail::seq<I...>{}, detail::seq<I...>{})){
    return concat(m.template get<T>().get()..., detail::seq<I...>{}, detail::seq<I...>{});
}
```

The call in `main` looks just like it did in your code:

```
M m;
auto x = get_array<M, S1, S2>(m, detail::gen_seq<2>{});
```

Where `detail::gen_seq` is the implementation of `make_index_sequence` that Xeo had.

### [Live Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/cc13pOWaXyT7JW5r)

Note that I replaced `unsigned` with `size_t` in Xeo's index sequence impl.

In C++14 we don't need to implement `seq` or `gen_seq`, and we also wouldn't need a trailing `-> decltype()` after our function.

In C++17 it would be even easier to generalize our concatenation for an arbitrary number of arrays, using fold expressions.

Comment: I suspect the user was aware aware of this, but it involves default constructing and then copying, not so good for non trivial types and requires default constructible which shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: @NirFriedman: I see... So I suppose we'll need something like [this](https://wandbox.org/permlink/EtaYvHVU6OpPjlQh), only we need to replicate index_sequence in C++11 like OP did

Comment: @NirFriedman: Oh, I see you beat me to it :-) Nice code. I'll upvote yours and delete mine.

Comment: Nah yours has some more relevant details, don't delete it! Leave both up :-).

Comment: @AndyG Thanks, the solution works, but only for two arrays, right? I need also more arrays to be involved.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this can be done, with the standard `index_sequence` tricks:

```
template <class T, std::size_t N1, std::size_t N2, std::size_t ... Is, std::size_t ... Js>
std::array<T, N1 + N2> merge_impl(const std::array<T, N1>& a1,
                                  const std::array<T, N2>& a2, 
                                  std::index_sequence<Is...>,
                                  std::index_sequence<Js...>) {
    return {a1[Is]..., a2[Js]...};
}

template <class T, std::size_t N1, std::size_t N2>
std::array<T, N1 + N2> merge(const std::array<T, N1>& a1, const std::array<T, N2>& a2) {
    return merge_impl(a1, a2,
                      std::make_index_sequence<N1>{}, 
                      std::make_index_sequence<N2>{});
}
```

`index_sequence` is only in the 14 standard, but can be easily implemented in 11; there are many resources (including on SO) that describe how to do so (edit: it's basically equivalent to your `Sequence` stuff, may as well get used to the standard names for them). Live example: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/54dce4a695357359.

Comment: Fine, but it is still for merging two arrays, what about merging arbitrary number of arrays?

Answer (score 1):

So here's for an arbitrary number of same-type arrays. We are basically implementing a highly restrictive version of `tuple_cat`, made substantially easier because the number of elements in the arrays is the same. I make use of a couple C++14 and 17 library features that are all readily implementable in C++11.

```
template<class, size_t> struct div_sequence;
template<size_t...Is, size_t Divisor>
struct div_sequence<std::index_sequence<Is...>, Divisor>
{
   using quot = std::index_sequence<Is / Divisor...>;
   using rem = std::index_sequence<Is % Divisor...>;
};


template<class T, size_t...Ns, size_t...Is, class ToA>
std::array<T, sizeof...(Ns)> array_cat_impl(std::index_sequence<Ns...>,
                                            std::index_sequence<Is...>,
                                            ToA&& t) 
{
    // NB: get gives you perfect forwarding; [] doesn't.
    return {std::get<Is>(std::get<Ns>(std::forward<ToA>(t)))... }; 
}

template<class Array, class... Arrays,
         class VT = typename std::decay_t<Array>::value_type,
         size_t S = std::tuple_size<std::decay_t<Array>>::value,
         size_t N = S * (1 + sizeof...(Arrays))>
std::array<VT, N> array_cat(Array&& a1, Arrays&&... as) 
{
     static_assert(std::conjunction_v<std::is_same<std::decay_t<Array>,
                                                   std::decay_t<Arrays>>...
                                      >, "Array type mismatch");

     using ind_seq = typename div_sequence<std::make_index_sequence<N>, S>::rem;
     using arr_seq = typename div_sequence<std::make_index_sequence<N>, S>::quot;
     return array_cat_impl<VT>(arr_seq(), ind_seq(), 
                               std::forward_as_tuple(std::forward<Array>(a1),
                                                     std::forward<Arrays>(as)...)
                               );
}
```

---

We can also reuse the `tuple_cat` machinery, as in @Barry's answer. To sidestep potential QoI issues, avoid depending on extensions and also extra moves, we don't want to `tuple_cat` `std::array`s directly. Instead, we transform the array into a tuple of references first.

```
template<class TupleLike, size_t... Is>
auto as_tuple_ref(TupleLike&& t, std::index_sequence<Is...>)
    -> decltype(std::forward_as_tuple(std::get<Is>(std::forward<TupleLike>(t))...))
{
    return std::forward_as_tuple(std::get<Is>(std::forward<TupleLike>(t))...);
}

template<class TupleLike,
         size_t S = std::tuple_size<std::decay_t<TupleLike>>::value >
auto as_tuple_ref(TupleLike&& t)
    -> decltype(as_tuple_ref(std::forward<TupleLike>(t), std::make_index_sequence<S>()))
{
    return as_tuple_ref(std::forward<TupleLike>(t), std::make_index_sequence<S>());
}
```

We can then transform the `tuple_cat`'d references back into an array:

```
template <class R1, class...Rs, size_t... Is>
std::array<std::decay_t<R1>, sizeof...(Is)> 
   to_array(std::tuple<R1, Rs...> t, std::index_sequence<Is...>) 
{
   return { std::get<Is>(std::move(t))... };
}

template <class R1, class...Rs>
std::array<std::decay_t<R1>, sizeof...(Rs) + 1> to_array(std::tuple<R1, Rs...> t) 
{
   static_assert(std::conjunction_v<std::is_same<std::decay_t<R1>, std::decay_t<Rs>>...>,
                 "Array element type mismatch");
   return to_array(t, std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Rs) + 1>());
}
```

Finally, `array_cat` itself is just

```
template <class... Arrays>
auto array_cat(Arrays&&... arrays) 
    -> decltype(to_array(std::tuple_cat(as_tuple_ref(std::forward<Arrays>(arrays))...))) 
{
    return to_array(std::tuple_cat(as_tuple_ref(std::forward<Arrays>(arrays))...));
}
```

Any decent optimizer should have little difficulty optimizing the intermediate tuples of references away.

Comment: That's cool, I wish I would like to understand something from this :P. Anyway, maybe for some people who knows better all this template-magic poem, this will be helpful :)