# Make loop variable a constant in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, template-meta-programming, constexpr

I am currently creating arithmetic operators libraries for high level synthesis.

For this, I am also creating a library to manipulate bits and bit vectors like it would be done in VHDL. To make my libraries synthesizable, nearly everything must be resolved at compile time.

However, I have an issue with loops.

Indeed, I would like to be able to write things like that:

```
const int N = 5;
for(int i = 0; i < N-2; i++) {
    x.bit<i+2>() = x.bit<i>();
}
```

Of course, it does not compile since `i` is a variable and not a constant determined at compile time.

However, `N` being a constant, this code is strictly equivalent to:

```
x.bit<2>() = x.bit<0>();
x.bit<3>() = x.bit<1>();
x.bit<4>() = x.bit<2>();
```

which compiles and works perfectly.

Is there a way to make the compiler (gcc in my case) unroll the loop since `N` is constant? Or to define a macro or a `constexpr` which could do it with a clean syntax? This would be the equivalent of *for generate* in VHDL.

Comment: Do you mean something like `for(const auto i : {0, 1, 2}) {...}`? However I'm not sure this will be unrolled either.

Comment: you might be interested in [`std::integer_sequence`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence)

Comment: Probably something like that (though I don't know this structure), but I'm more looking for something where you don't need to write 0, 1, 2, ..., N-1, but only 0 and N-1.

Comment: For std::integer_sequence that would be ideal but i'd like to be C++11 compatible.

Comment: @BenjaminBarrois You can implement that yourself. Or upgrade to C++14, which just makes your life easier

Comment: apart from a recursive solution you could probably do something with http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence and fold expressions.

Comment: @PasserBy I would love to but unfortunately the HLS tools the final code is supposed to be used with are not C++14 compatible.

Comment: see how to implement [integer_sequence in c++11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17424477/implementation-c14-make-integer-sequence) yourself

Answer (score 3):

While `constexpr` has got much more powerful in C++14/17 it is not yet possible to mix this kind of compile time / template code with an ordinary loop. There is some talk of introducing a construct that might enable that in a future version of C++. For now you have a few choices, either recursive calls to a function with an integer template argument or probably simpler in this case a C++17 [fold expression](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold). You could also use C++11 variadic template expansion to get a similar result to fold expressions in this example, though fold expressions are more powerful.

Just saw your comment about being stuck with C++11, you're probably better off using the recursive function approach I think. I've added that approach to the example.

If you were able to use C++14 you might also want to consider moving entirely into `constexpr` function / type land so your `bit<I>()` function would not be templated but would be just a `constexpr` function `bit(i)`. You could then use normal functions and loops. Given the C++11 restrictions on `constexpr` functions that is probably less useful in your case however. I've added an example using that approach.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

template <size_t N>
struct bits {
    bool bs[N];

    template <size_t I>
    constexpr const bool& bit() const {
        return bs[I];
    }
    template <size_t I>
    constexpr bool& bit() {
        return bs[I];
    }

    constexpr bool bit(int i) const { return bs[i]; }
    constexpr void bit(int i, bool x) { bs[i] = x; }
};

// Using C++17 fold expressions

template <size_t N, size_t... Is>
constexpr bits<N> set_bits_helper(bits<N> x, std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
    ((x.bit<Is + 2>() = x.bit<Is>()), ...);
    return x;
}

template <size_t N>
constexpr bits<N> set_bits(bits<N> x) {
    return set_bits_helper(x, std::make_index_sequence<N - 2>{});
}

// Using recursive template function, should work on C++11

template <size_t I, size_t N>
constexpr bits<N> set_bits_recursive_helper(bits<N> x, std::integral_constant<size_t, I>) {
    x.bit<N - I>() = x.bit<N - I - 2>();
    return set_bits_recursive_helper(x, std::integral_constant<size_t, I - 1>{});
}

template <size_t N>
constexpr bits<N> set_bits_recursive_helper(bits<N> x, std::integral_constant<size_t, 0>) { return x; }

template <size_t N>
constexpr bits<N> set_bits_recursive(bits<N> x) {
    return set_bits_recursive_helper(x, std::integral_constant<size_t, N - 2>{});
}

// Using non template constexpr functions
template <size_t N>
constexpr bits<N> set_bits_constexpr(bits<N> x) {
    for (int i = 0; i < N - 2; ++i) {
        x.bit(i + 2, x.bit(i));
    }
    return x;
}

// Test code to show usage

template <size_t N>
void print_bits(const bits<N>& x) {
    for (auto b : x.bs) {
        std::cout << b << ", ";
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}

void test_set_bits() {
    constexpr bits<8> x{ 1, 0 };
    print_bits(x);
    constexpr auto y = set_bits(x);
    static_assert(y.bit<2>() == x.bit<0>());
    print_bits(y);
}

void test_set_bits_recursive() {
    constexpr bits<8> x{ 1, 0 };
    print_bits(x);
    constexpr auto y = set_bits_recursive(x);
    static_assert(y.bit<2>() == x.bit<0>());
    print_bits(y);
}

void test_set_bits_constexpr() {
    constexpr bits<8> x{ 1, 0 };
    print_bits(x);
    constexpr auto y = set_bits_constexpr(x);
    static_assert(y.bit<2>() == x.bit<0>());
    print_bits(y);
}

int main() {
    test_set_bits();
    test_set_bits_recursive();
    test_set_bits_constexpr();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Also without `std::integer_sequence` (but I suggest to implement a substitute and use it), in C++11 you can use template partial specialization.

I mean that you can implement something like

```
template <int I, int Sh, int N>
struct shiftVal
 {
   template <typename T>
   static int func (T & t)
    { return t.template bit<I+Sh>() = t.template bit<I>(),
             shiftVal<I+1, Sh, N>::func(t); }
 };

template <int I, int Sh>
struct shiftVal<I, Sh, I>
 {
   template <typename T>
   static int func (T &)
    { return 0; }
 };
```

and your cycle become

```
shiftVal<0, 2, N-2>::func(x);
```

The following is a full working example

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

template <std::size_t N>
struct foo
 {
   std::array<int, N> arr;

   template <int I>
   int & bit ()
    { return arr[I]; }
 };


template <int I, int Sh, int N>
struct shiftVal
 {
   template <typename T>
   static int func (T & t)
    { return t.template bit<I+Sh>() = t.template bit<I>(),
             shiftVal<I+1, Sh, N>::func(t); }
 };

template <int I, int Sh>
struct shiftVal<I, Sh, I>
 {
   template <typename T>
   static int func (T &)
    { return 0; }
 };

int main ()
 {
   foo<10U>  f { { { 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29 } } };

   for ( auto const & i : f.arr )
      std::cout << i << ' ';

   std::cout << std::endl;

   shiftVal<0, 2, 10-2>::func(f);

   for ( auto const & i : f.arr )
      std::cout << i << ' ';

   std::cout << std::endl;
 }
```

Comment: @W.F. - well... I confess that I've added `constexpr` by force of habit; I don't know if is dangerous but, effectively, I can't imagine a compile time use of these methods. Removed; thanks.

Comment: well from logical point of view constexpr function is actually constexpr iff parameters passed to it are constexpr. Now if we pass the non-constexpr parameters the function is not constexpr like in case of your example. On the other hand we cannot create instance of the constexpr function that would allow to modify they constexpr parameters (unless we overload assign operator constexpr'ly). Either way +1 'cause the approach solves OPs problem.

Answer (score 0):

Nobody else produce an example based on a C++11 simulation of `std::integer_sequence` (as suggested by W.F., Passer By and Sopel and the simpler solution, IMHO) so I propose the following one (of `std::index_sequence` and `std::make_index_sequence` in reality: simulate `std::integer_sequence` is more complicated)

```
template <std::size_t ...>
struct indexSequence
 { };

template <std::size_t N, std::size_t ... Next>
struct indexSequenceHelper : public indexSequenceHelper<N-1U, N-1U, Next...>
 { };

template <std::size_t ... Next>
struct indexSequenceHelper<0U, Next ... >
 { using type = indexSequence<Next ... >; };

template <std::size_t N>
using makeIndexSequence = typename indexSequenceHelper<N>::type;
```

So a function (with function helper) to reproduce the asked loop can be written as

template

```
void shiftValHelper (T & t, indexSequence<Is...> const &)
 {
   using unused = int[];

   (void)unused { 0,
      (t.template bit<Is+Sh>() = t.template bit<Is>(), 0)... };
 }


template <std::size_t Sh, std::size_t N, typename T>
void shiftVal (T & t)
 { shiftValHelper<Sh>(t, makeIndexSequence<N>{}); }
```

and called ad follows

```
shiftVal<2, N-2>(x);
```

The following is a full working example

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

template <std::size_t ...>
struct indexSequence
 { };

template <std::size_t N, std::size_t ... Next>
struct indexSequenceHelper : public indexSequenceHelper<N-1U, N-1U, Next...>
 { };

template <std::size_t ... Next>
struct indexSequenceHelper<0U, Next ... >
 { using type = indexSequence<Next ... >; };

template <std::size_t N>
using makeIndexSequence = typename indexSequenceHelper<N>::type;


template <std::size_t N>
struct foo
 {
   std::array<int, N> arr;

   template <std::size_t I>
   int & bit ()
    { return arr[I]; }
 };


template <std::size_t Sh, typename T, std::size_t ... Is>
void shiftValHelper (T & t, indexSequence<Is...> const &)
 {
   using unused = int[];

   (void)unused { 0,
      (t.template bit<Is+Sh>() = t.template bit<Is>(), 0)... };
 }


template <std::size_t Sh, std::size_t N, typename T>
void shiftVal (T & t)
 { shiftValHelper<Sh>(t, makeIndexSequence<N>{}); }


int main ()
 {
   foo<10U>  f { { { 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29 } } };

   for ( auto const & i : f.arr )
      std::cout << i << ' ';

   std::cout << std::endl;

   shiftVal<2, 10-2>(f);

   for ( auto const & i : f.arr )
      std::cout << i << ' ';

   std::cout << std::endl;
 }
```

Comment: This "implementation" is a nice demonstration, but one should note that it is not "efficient": It does not use memoization for different sequence lengths and it uses linear (instead of logarithmic) recursion. A [logarithmic implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17426611/2615118) is also simple.

Comment: @Julius - I didn't know that logarithmic implementation; very nice the `concat`; yes, your right: this implementation isn't really efficient and the real problem is the linear recursion.