# How to make a variadic function of smart pointers?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to make <s>an interface</s> an abstract class which would be implemented by derivated childs. One of methods in that class has to be variadic (children get one ore more `QSharedPointer<QObject>` depending on implementation)

The problem is that:

1. templated methods cannot be virtual
2. I cannot make a variadic method taking `QSharedPointer<QObject>... args` arguments because of `error: expansion pattern ‘QSharedPointer<QObject>’ contains no argument packs.`

Less words, more code:

```
class BaseClass {
public:
    virtual void foo(QSharedPointer<QObject>... args) = 0;
}

class ChildClassA : public BaseClass {
public:
    void foo(QSharedPointer<QObject> arg1);
}


class ChildClassB : public BaseClass {
public:
    void foo(QSharedPointer<QObject> arg1, QSharedPointer<QObject> arg2);
}
```

I would like to use above classes to things like that:

```
template <class T = BaseClass>
class Controller<T>{
    void callFoo(QSharedPointer<QObject>... args){
        T* = new T();
        T->foo(args);
    }
}
```

As you can see the BaseClass is only to say: use one of my children as generic type.

How do I make such things work? Is it even possible in C++?

Comment: How about taking in a vector of smart pointers?

Comment: @Quentin kinda 'meh' for me because you can pass empty vector. Also, it's pointless to wrap only one object into wrapper every time when using `ChildClassA`

Comment: If you want to optimize for known-child access, you can keep the N-parameters function but use a vector to override the virtual one. The issue is that when calling `foo` on an object with static type `BaseClass`, C++ doesn't know how many parameters the child expects. Which is kind of a weird design as well: how do *you* know the number of parameters? What should happen in case of a mismatch? Would separating the children by arity be a solution?

Comment: You could always resort to `virtual void foo(...) = 0;`, but I don't know if you really want that.

Comment: @Quentin actually I know how many parameters the child method will take because  a generic 'controller' class works for specified Child class. E.g. `template <class T = BaseClass> class GenericClass{}` The only purpose of BaseClass is to be interface that says that one of Child classes must be used for that generic slot.

Comment: Then use that controller to decide on calling one of the many overloads of the function?

Comment: @Luke that's great! Then we can have children inherit from `BaseClass<N>` and implement the corresponding N-parameters function, and not much changes because you're already in a template. Right?

Comment: @Quentin I think I don't exactly get what you mean. I extended the sample code. Is your idea still applicable?

Comment: @PasserBy overloaded methods in Controller is a nice idea but isn't what I am looking for. Both methods will be accessible while I want only one method accessible depending on the class specified in the generic template

Comment: What I meant was, since the number of arguments is known from the controller, just use the controller to call the right overload of the function, and overload all the possible number of arguments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since (per the comments) you already have separated the children by arity, and they're managed by separate instantiations of a `Controller` class template, there is no point in trying to force them all into the same hierarchy -- that only means workarounds and runtime overhead.

Instead, let's make `BaseClass` a template, and use its parmeter to generate `foo`'s signature.

```
namespace detail {
    template <std::size_t, class T>
    using expandHook = T;
}

template <std::size_t N, class = std::make_index_sequence<N>>
struct BaseClass;

template <std::size_t N, std::size_t... Idx>
struct BaseClass<N, std::index_sequence<Idx...>> {
    virtual void foo(detail::expandHook<Idx, QSharedPointer<QObject>>... args) = 0;
};
```

`detail::expandHook` is kind of a syntactic trick to repeat the `QSharedPointer<QObject>` type as many times as there are `Idx`es, which are `0` to `N - 1` thanks to the work of `std::index_sequence`.

Then, children inherit from the corresponding `BaseClass`:

```
struct Child : BaseClass<2> {
    void foo(QSharedPointer<QObject>, QSharedPointer<QObject>) override;
};
```

Bonus: a child can inherit from several `BaseClass` specializations if you want it to support several arities!

Finally, a controller will be parameterized by the adequate `BaseClass` type, and everything clicks in.

[See it live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/96a70b95a03561a5) (with stubbed types, and `main`'s content would be what's inside a `Controller`).

Comment: **Note: you need to use C++14 or newer, QT in 2017 uses C++11 by default**
Nevertheless, great solution! Thanks!

Comment: @Luke ... and [here's the Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17424477/implementation-c14-make-integer-sequence) about implementing `std::index_sequence` in C++11 :)

Answer (score 1):

If you follow the guideline that public functions should be non-virtual and virtual functions should be private, then you can solve this problem by turning the base function into a variadic template function which delegates to a virtual private function taking a `std::vector`.

This also has the advantage that all the unpacking happens in one place and derived classes are easier to implement.

Here is an example (I've replaced `QSharedPtr` with `std::shared_ptr` and added dummy implementations for `QObject` so that the example can be compiled without 3rd-party stuff):

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>

struct QObject { virtual void sayHi() const = 0; };
struct DerivedQObject1 : public QObject { void sayHi() const override { std::cout << "1\n"; } };
struct DerivedQObject2 : public QObject { void sayHi() const override  { std::cout << "2\n"; } };

class BaseClass {
public:
    template <class... Types>
    void foo(std::shared_ptr<Types>... args)
    {
        std::vector<std::shared_ptr<QObject>> vector;
        pushBack(vector, args...);
        assert(!empty(vector));
        doFoo(vector);
    }

private:
    virtual void doFoo(std::vector<std::shared_ptr<QObject>> const& args) = 0;

    template<typename LastType>
    static void pushBack(std::vector<std::shared_ptr<QObject>>& vector, LastType arg)
    {
        vector.push_back(arg);
    };

    template<typename FirstType, typename ...OtherTypes>
    static void pushBack(std::vector<std::shared_ptr<QObject>>& vector, FirstType const& firstArg, OtherTypes... otherArgs)
    {
        vector.push_back(firstArg);
        pushBack(vector, otherArgs...);
    };
};

class ChildClassA : public BaseClass {
private:
    void doFoo(std::vector<std::shared_ptr<QObject>> const& args) override;
};

void ChildClassA::doFoo(std::vector<std::shared_ptr<QObject>> const& args) {
    for (auto const& arg : args) {
        arg->sayHi();
    }
}

int main() {
    ChildClassA child;
    auto obj1 = std::make_shared<DerivedQObject1>();
    auto obj2 = std::make_shared<DerivedQObject2>();
    child.foo(obj1, obj2);
}
```