# Declaring a member function with a typedef coming from a metafunction

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++17

Consider the following code:

```
template <class>
struct Foo_s {
    using type = void();
};

template <class>
using Foo_u = void();

template <class T>
struct Bar {
             Foo_u<void>       foo1; // OK
    typename Foo_s<void>::type foo2; // OK
             Foo_u<T>          foo3; // OK
    typename Foo_s<T>::type    foo4; // Boom.
};

template struct Bar<void>;
```

The declaration of `foo4` fails on GCC 7.2, Clang 5.0.0 and MSVC 19.10.25017.

GCC:

```
<source>: In instantiation of 'struct Bar<void>':
18 : <source>:18:17:   required from here
15 : <source>:15:29: error: field 'Bar<void>::foo4' invalidly declared function type
     typename Foo_s<T>::type foo4;
                             ^~~~
```

Clang:

```
15 : <source>:15:29: error: data member instantiated with function type 'typename Foo_s<void>::type' (aka 'void ()')
    typename Foo_s<T>::type foo4;
                            ^
18 : <source>:18:17: note: in instantiation of template class 'Bar<void>' requested here
template struct Bar<void>;
                ^
```

MSVC:

```
15 : <source>(15): error C2207: 'Bar<T>::foo4': a member of a class template cannot acquire a function type
18 : <source>(18): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'Bar<void>' being compiled
```

All of them seem to think that I am trying to declare a data member with a function type. As you can see, this only happens when the type is nested (not a `using` template), and is dependent on the parameter of the class. This looks like a bug, but the fact that for once all of these three compilers agree has me doubting.

Is this standard behaviour? If so, is there a rationale behind disallowing this, and is there a way to declare a member function whose type is computed with a metaprogram?

Comment: Yes, it's standard. See https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/temp#spec-8. Don't know the rationale or why `Foo_u<T>` is accepted though.

Comment: Is it possible to define such a function? For example, how would you define `foo3`?

Comment: @geza you can only use this for declarations, definitions need the usual syntax..

Comment: That's why I'm asking, what is this construct good for?

Comment: @geza [declaring pure virtual functions with a generated signature](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47460334/3233393) :)

Comment: @Rakete1111 so that's a "no, maybe, no"... Now I'm sad :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[[temp.spec]/8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/temp#spec-8):

> If a function declaration acquired its function type through a dependent type without using the syntactic form of a function declarator, the program is ill-formed.

This makes your last line decidedly ill-formed. Which makes sense, since, as in other cases of dependent constructs, we don't want the meaning of a phrase to depend too strongly on template arguments.

However, [[dcl.fct]/13](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.decl#dcl.fct-13):

> A typedef of function type may be used to declare a function but shall
>   not be used to define a function.

This makes your first three lines well-formed---the first two directly, and for the third one, note that

> When a *template-id* refers to the specialization of an alias template,
>   it is equivalent to the associated type obtained by substitution of
>   its *template-argument*s for the *template-parameter*s in the *type-id* of
>   the alias template.

by [[temp.alias]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/temp.alias#2).