# Aliasing a template parameter pack

Tags: c++, templates, parameter-passing, variadic-templates, type-alias

**Pre-Dramatic**

Hi, 
maybe this question is a duplicate, but I am relative new to template programming  and actually I am not able to find a **simple** and **short solution** (-> only finding megabytes of "*roxxor-template-magic*" which I don't understand) matching my concrete and simple problem and so I feel a little bit lost now.

**Pre-Information**

I want to use a "type_container" as template parameter for a class. The container is a simple struct, which should also contain some **typedefs for template parameter packs**.

**Question: (related to the example at the bottom)**

How can I define and alias the type-lists in the container-struct and how can I access and forward them to the needed entities in the factory-class?
(*No boost and only C++11/14/17*)

**Example: (Would compile, If I would know a solution)**

```
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <stack>

struct MY_TYPE_CONTAINER
{
    using TYPE_MAP            = std::map<int, int>;
    using TYPE_VECTOR         = std::vector<double>;
    using PARAMETER_PACK1 = //? -> ...T -> int, std::stack<int>, int
    using PARAMETER_PACK2 = //? -> ...T -> double, int, std::string
};

template <typename TYPES>
struct Factory
{
    typename TYPES::TYPE_MAP                       m_map;
    typename TYPES::TYPE_VECTOR                    m_vector;
    typename std::tuple<TYPES::PARAMETER_PACK1...> m_tuple;
    typename std::tuple<std::shared_ptr<TYPES::PARAMETER_PACK1>...> m_tuple2;
    void handlePack2(TYPES::PARAMETER_PACK2... args) { }
};


int main()
{
    Factory<MY_TYPE_CONTAINER> oStaticFactory;
    oStaticFactory.handlePack2(2.0, 1, "hi");
    return 0;
}
```

**Current (best?) elaborated solution (compilable) (Based on John Zwinck's answer)**

```
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <stack>
#include <memory>

struct MY_TYPE_CONTAINER
{
    using TYPE_MAP                    = std::map<int, int>;
    using TYPE_VECTOR                 = std::vector<double>;
    using PARAMETER_PACK1             = std::tuple<int, std::stack<int>, int>;
    using PARAMETER_SHARED_PTR_PACK_1 = std::tuple<std::shared_ptr<int>, std::shared_ptr<std::stack<int>>, std::shared_ptr<int>>;
    using PARAMETER_PACK2             = std::tuple<double, int, std::string>;
};

template <typename TYPES>
class Factory
{
    typename TYPES::TYPE_MAP                    m_map;
    typename TYPES::TYPE_VECTOR                 m_vector;
    typename TYPES::PARAMETER_PACK1             m_tuple;
    typename TYPES::PARAMETER_SHARED_PTR_PACK_1 m_tuple2;

    void handlePack2Impl(typename TYPES::PARAMETER_PACK2 tup) {};

public:
    template <typename... Args>
    void handlePack2(Args... args) { handlePack2Impl(std::make_tuple(args...)); }
};

int main()
{
    Factory<MY_TYPE_CONTAINER> oStaticFactory;
    oStaticFactory.handlePack2(2.0, 1, "hi");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: C++17, 14 or 11?

Comment: Added it to my question.

Comment: Handling that type pack around to declare data members is reasonably easy, but [you'll be grinding your teeth on the member functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47473986/declaring-a-member-function-with-a-typedef-coming-from-a-metafunction)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually use `tuple`:

```
using PARAMETER_PACK1 = std::tuple<int, std::stack, int>;
using PARAMETER_PACK2 = std::tuple<double, int, std::string>;

typename TYPES::PARAMETER_PACK1 m_tuple;
```

Then you're left with one problem--how to declare something like this:

```
void handlePack2(TYPES::PARAMETER_PACK2... args);
```

Perhaps:

```
void handlePack2Impl(typename TYPES::PARAMETER_PACK2 tup);

template <typename... Args>
void handlePack2(Args... args) { handlePack2Impl(std::make_tuple(args...)); }
```

For more ideas, start here: [Tuple to parameter pack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36612596/tuple-to-parameter-pack) (but beware, there is template meta-programming!

Comment: C++17 adds [`std::apply`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/apply) which will also do the work of expanding a tuple to a series of parameters.

Comment: @DrewDormann: we are converting a set of arguments to a tuple, not the other way around.  I'm not sure how `std::apply` applies.

Comment: @John Zwinck: That means, I cannot avoid to specify those member-types of the factory in the type-container? I extended the code with another member m_tuple2. How can I handle 
this type of member? Should I transfer this full-type also to the type-container?

Comment: Added your solution to my question, if that is allowed here?!

Answer (score 1):

Basically you can't do that. The closest thing you can do is to save `std::tuple<type, type, type>` (or your own `variadic_class<type, type, type>` which may have empty body) and then retrieving the list back by little templates magic