# Are member function declarations with signatures from non-deduced template parameters allowed?

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to prune back combinatorial explosion of specializations by passing const-ness transparently through a template parameter:

```
template <typename Sig>
struct IFoo { virtual Sig operator() = 0; }; // XXX, but OK with non-templated aliases...
```

The compilers are treating `Sig` as a non-function type before instantiation, so I think I am just looking for a way to coerce the system out of that early belief about the type. Is this not possible, or have I just not stumbled across the correct grammar yet?

I explicitly want to avoid the usual style of specialization-induced deduction:

```
template <typename Sig> struct IFoo;

template <typename R, typename... Args>
struct IFoo<R(Args...)> { virtual R operator()(Args...) = 0; };

template <typename R, typename... Args>
struct IFoo<R(Args...) const> { virtual R operator()(Args...) const = 0; };
```

Alternately, is there anything available for `const` along the lines of the `noexcept` extraction made available in C++17?

```
template <typename Sig> struct IBar;

template <typename R, typename... Args, bool IsNoExcept>
struct IBar<R(Args...) noexcept(IsNoExcept)> {
    virtual R operator()(Args...) noexcept(IsNoExcept) = 0;
};
```

I am unfortunately stuck in C++14, but AFAIK there is no magic `if constexpr` equivalent in C++17 that is usable from within class definition scope anyway.

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47473986/declaring-a-member-function-with-a-typedef-coming-from-a-metafunction), possibly a reverse-duplicate.

Comment: Can you elaborate why the specialization-undiced deduction is to be avoided?

Comment: I have no idea if this is any closer to what you want, but for a fixed number of arguments (i.e. non-variadic), [this](https://godbolt.org/z/BAZ28F) would not rely directly on specialization of `IFoo`. But it's still unclear to me what the ultimate goal is here.

Comment: So you want `template <typename Sig>
struct IFoo { virtual Sig operator() = 0; };` to really be something like `template <typename Sig>
struct IFoo { virtual return_type_of_Sig operator()(argument_types_of_Sig) constness_of_Sig = 0; };`?

Comment: @NathanOliver Yes, exactly.

Comment: @NathanOliver that's actually what it is already, but there seems to be a special standard rule to stop the madness before it plunges into templates :)

Comment: @MaxLanghof The helper trait type you give was my backup plan. My primary goal is readability for a non-trivial templated base class (the real `IFoo` has dozens of other methods and half a dozen template parameters), and I am trying to avoid both of boilerplated specializations and (too a lesser extent) throwing too much SFINAE around the interface.

Comment: @MaxLanghof Actually I cannot successfully alias a parameter-pack either, so the type-trait approach may not work either.

Comment: @Jeff Yeah, that's why it would only work for the non-variadic case. I don't know how many arguments you have to support at max but you could probably work around it with fixed-length parameter list sizes. But I'm not sure.

Comment: @MaxLanghof It's a public API, so it really need full generality even more than compactness/readability. I expect to end up with a specialization bonanza until we ever see parameter-pack aliasing or parameterized operators/specifiers added for const/volatile/&& like noexcept().

Comment: I see a problem; if you want a `const` operator when the template type is `const` and a non-`const` operator (only) when the template parameter is non-const, you have that when you define (to make an example) `IFoo<int(int)> const  f;`, you have that `f` has a non-const operator but can't use it because is a `const` object.

Comment: @max66 Yes, that's the point of `const` specifiers on member functions... That's no different than `struct X { int foo(int) const; };`.

Comment: @MaxLanghof - sure; but isn't clear to me if the OP take in count this point

Comment: @Max66 If those weren't the semantics I needed, I would not have used const member function qualification in the specialized `IFoo<R(Args...) const>` counter-example.