# Initialize std::array of std::array

Tags: c++, arrays, initialization

I have and `std::array` of `std::array`, and say that I want to initialize all the arrays to `{1,2,3}`. We write:

```
std::array<std::array<int,3>,3> x{{1,2,3},{1,2,3},{1,2,3}};
```

This is not very handy. It becomes really messy when you have more than 3 arrays, or each array has more than 3 elements.

However, it becomes even worse if the size of the array is not known *a priori*:

```
template <size_t n, size_t T> struct foo{
  std::array<std::array<int,n>,T> x;
}
```

How can you initialize `x`? To make it clearer, I would like to initialize all the arrays in `x` to an array of a certain parameter that is given. That is, something like:

```
template <size_t n, size_t T> struct foo{
  static constexpr int N{20};

  std::array<std::array<int,n>,T> x;

  foo() : x{ {N,N,...}, {N,N,...}, ...} {}
}
```

(If that were possible). Any suggestion or ideas? I can always iterate through `x` and call the method `fill`, as in the following piece of code:

```
for (size_t idx = 0; idx < x[0].size(); idx++)
  x[idx].fill(N);
```

But that is not initialization, right? I am new to using `std::array` and I do not know whether I am asking something dummy here :/

Comment: Do you really need to initialize all the elements to a specific value? `std::array<std::array<int,3>,3> x{}` will make them all `0`'s if you are okay with that.

Comment: Does `foo` know what it should initialize the elements to? Should this be delegated to the caller? You're sort-of implying you know what the values should be, but don't actually say.

Comment: @NathanOliver, @Useless you are both correct. I know that all the elements should be initialized to some value other than `0`. I will change the question.

Comment: What kind of values are you dealing with?

Comment: @Holt The inner arrays consist on numerical values (be them `int`, `bool`, `double`,...). No tricks here ;)

Comment: If you really write `std::array<std::array<int,3>,3> x{{1,2,3},{1,2,3},{1,2,3}};` you get a compilation error.  You should add an extra pair of braces around the construct. (Why?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `std::index_sequence`, you might do something like:

```
template <std::size_t ... Is, typename T>
constexpr std::array<T, sizeof...(Is)>
make_array(const T& value, std::index_sequence<Is...>)
{
    return {{(void(Is), value)...}};
}

template <std::size_t N, typename T>
constexpr std::array<T, N> make_array(const T& value)
{
    return make_array(value, std::make_index_sequence<N>());
}
```

and then:

```
template <size_t n, size_t T>
struct foo{
    static constexpr int N{20};

    std::array<std::array<int,n>,T> x;

    foo() : x{make_array<T>(make_array<n>(N))} {}
};
```

Comment: I just tested it, it is insane (insanly good, I mean). Only issue here is that I need C++14 to make it work. Is there a way of fitting your solution to C++11? I am very thankful for your answer, though :)

Comment: `index_sequence` might be implemented in C++11 too.

Comment: For example: [implementation-c14-make-integer-sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17424477/implementation-c14-make-integer-sequence)