# Insert value to a std::map from a tuple

Tags: c++, c++11, stdmap, stdtuple

I am just learning data structure of graph.And i'm trapped in such a situation.
I have written my `Graph` class like

```
template <char... Args>
    class Graph{};
```

where the `Args` of type `char` means the vertex of my `Graph`.
However, when i want to search in my Graph,i need to insert each vertex of `char` and its index in `Args` as a `std::pair<char,size_t>` into a `std::map<char,size_t>`.What i have done is that i constructed a `std::tuple` like

```
 std::tuple<decltype(Args)...> t(Args...);
```

Then i want to do like this

```
 for(size_t i =0;i<sizeof...(Args);++i)
      Map.insert({0,std::get<i>(t)});
```

which Map means a `std::map<size_t,char>`.
It certainly doesn't work because the `i` used in `std::get<>` is not a `constexpr`.
What can i do now is to insert into the Map one by one like

```
Map.insert({0,std::get<0>(t)});
Map.insert({1,std::get<1>(t)});
Map.insert({2,std::get<2>(t)});
```

But it is not the result i want.So are there any other solutions for me?
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

`std::map<char,size_t>` or `std::map<size_t,char>`?
I'll go with `std::map<size_t,char>`.

You need C++14's [std::index_sequence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence)<sup>1</sup>.

```
template <char... Chars, std::size_t... Ints>
void fill_map(std::map<size_t, char> & your_map, std::index_sequence<Ints...>) {
    using swallow = int[];
    (void)swallow{0, (your_map.emplace(Ints, Chars), 0)... };
}

template <char... Chars>
void fill_map(std::map<size_t, char> & your_map) {
    fill_map<Chars...>(your_map, std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Chars)>{});
}
```

use:

```
std::map<size_t,char> your_map;
fill_map<Args...>(your_map);
```

---

<sup>1</sup> [implementation for C++11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17424477/implementation-c14-make-integer-sequence).

Comment: Thank you!That is exactly what i need.