# How does integer_sequence get unfolded to generate a sequence?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, variadic-templates

I have this code that generates an compile-time array of 1 to 10

```
template <int... Is> // when called below, Is will be 0 - N
constexpr std::array<int, sizeof...(Is)>
make_inc_array_impl(std::integer_sequence<int, Is...>) {
    return {{(Is + 1)...}}; // +1 to start at one instead of [0, 1, ...]
}

template <std::size_t N>
constexpr std::array<int, N> make_inc_array() {
    return make_inc_array_impl(std::make_integer_sequence<int, N>{});
}

constexpr auto a = make_inc_array<10>(); // [1, 2, ..., 10]

int main() {
    for(int itr = 0; itr < 10; ++itr)
        printf("%d ", a[itr]);
}
```

Well, I've got some experience and knowledge of how meta-programming works. But still I don't get how this amazing example really works.

1. From the `make_inc_array_impl()`, I see that, it returns `(Is+1)...` So should the result be `[11, 10, 9, 8, 7, ... 2]` since `Is` value starts from `10`?
2. How is the variadic template function `make_integer_sequence(parameter pack)` unfolds/expands the `std::integer_sequence<int, Is...>`? In a normal meta-programming, template deduction works recursively from `N` to `N-1`, down to `1`. But here why it results from `1` to `N`?

Could you help to explain what the principle behind?

Comment: Why do you think `Is` starts at 10?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The call to `make_inc_array<10>()` returns `make_inc_array_impl(std::make_integer_sequence<int, 10>{})`. `std::make_integer_sequence` is an alias template. In particular, it's implemented so that `std::make_integer_sequence<int, 10>` is an alias for the type `std::integer_sequence<int, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9>`. Thus, when `make_inc_array_impl` is called with an argument of this type, `Is...` gets deduced to `0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9` in order to make the parameter type `std::integer_sequence<int, Is...>` equal to the argument type. Finally, this pack is expanded in the body of `make_inc_array_impl`. The pack expansion is guaranteed to occur in order, so it becomes `0 + 1`, `1 + 1`, ..., `9 + 1`.

The most tricky part of this is `std::make_integer_sequence`. How does it expand to an `std::integer_sequence` specialization with the actual consecutive integers desired? Well, this was inserted into the standard library so that you don't have to remember how to do it yourself, but if you want to see the answer, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17424477/implementation-c14-make-integer-sequence).

You generally need a helper function which is invoked with the result of `std::make_integer_sequence<int, N>{}` so that there is a place to put the individual integers in the sequence, *i.e.,* the pack `Is...`. Now that you're aware of this trick, you'll start seeing many places where you can use it.

Comment: Note that at least some major compilers implement `make_integer_sequence` by cheating; an intrinsic.  This is because the intrinsic is easy, and much faster/cheaper than even fancy manual implementations.