# Variadic templates and Tree

Tags: c++11, templates, tree, variadic-templates, variadic

I have next command:

```
auto result = Builder::get(
        ObjKey("key1"),
        ObjVal("test1"),
        (ObjKey("key2"), ObjVal("test21"), (ObjKey("key3"), ObjVal("test31"), ObjVal("test32")), ObjVal("test22")),
        ObjVal("test2")
    );
```

I expect to get the following result:

```
{key1, test1, {key2, test21, {key3, test31, test32}, test22}, test2}
```

but I get this result:

```
{key1, test1, test22, test2}
```

The program code is below  (standard 11):

```
#include <iostream>

class ObjKey {
public:
    ObjKey() = delete;

    ObjKey(const std::string& key) : m_key(key) { }

    std::string get() const {
        return m_key + ", ";
    }

private:
    std::string m_key;
};

class ObjVal {
public:
    ObjVal() = delete;

    ObjVal(const std::string& value) : m_value(value) { }

    std::string get() const {
        return m_value + ", ";
    }

private:
    std::string m_value;
};

class Builder {
public:
    template<typename... Args>
    static std::string get(ObjKey&& objKey, Args&& ...args) {
        std::string resultValue;
        get(resultValue, std::forward<ObjKey>(objKey), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        return resultValue;
    }

private:
    Builder() {}

    template<typename... Args>
    static void get(std::string& resultValue, ObjKey&& objKey, Args&& ...args) {
        resultValue.append("{");
        resultValue.append(objKey.get());
        std::string values;
        get(values, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        resultValue.append(values);
        resultValue.append("}");
    }

    template<typename... Args>
    static void get(std::string& resultValue, ObjVal&& objVal, Args&& ...args) {
        resultValue.append(objVal.get());
        get(resultValue, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }

    static void get(std::string& resultValue) {}
};

int main()
{
    auto result = Builder::get(
        ObjKey("key1"),
        ObjVal("test1"),
        (ObjKey("key2"), ObjVal("test21"), (ObjKey("key3"), ObjVal("test31"), ObjVal("test32")), ObjVal("test22")),
        ObjVal("test2")
    );
    std::cout << result << "\n";
}
```

What am i doing wrong?

And is it possible to solve with templates?

Comment: `(ObjKey("key2"), ObjVal("test21"), (ObjKey("key3"), ObjVal("test31"), ObjVal("test32")), ObjVal("test22")))` what do you think the value of this expression is?

Comment: It is tree: 
ObjKey("key1")
ObjVal("test1"),
        ObjKey("key2")
        ObjVal("test21")
                ObjKey("key3")
                ObjVal("test31")
                ObjVal("test32")
        ObjVal("test22")
ObjVal("test2")

Comment: I hope you understand it isn't a tree. Nothing in your code creates trees. I would recommend making a Tree class.

Answer (score 0):

> What am i doing wrong?

As suggested by n.m., you have to consider what the comma operator do to the following expression

```
(ObjKey("key2"), ObjVal("test21"), (ObjKey("key3"), ObjVal("test31"), ObjVal("test32")), ObjVal("test22"))
```

The comma operator discard all values but the last, so the expression become

```
(ObjVal("test22"))
```

> And is it possible to solve with templates?

Yes, but the best I can imagine involve `std::tuple`.

I mean... if you accept that the `get()` call become

```
   auto result = Builder::get(
      ObjKey("key1"),
      ObjVal("test1"),
      std::make_tuple(ObjKey("key2"), ObjVal("test21"),
                      std::make_tuple(ObjKey("key3"), ObjVal("test31"),
                                      ObjVal("test32")),
                      ObjVal("test22")),
      ObjVal("test2"));
```

so with a `std::make_tuple` before the grouping `(`, you can add a couple of private `get()` to manage the tuple case.

So, renaming `getH()` (for "get helper") the private versions of `get()`, the tuple-managing versions of `getH()` can be written as follows (a C++14 solution, because use `std::index_sequence` and `std::make_index_sequence`; but if you need a C++11 solution, isn't difficult to write C++11 substitutes)

```
  template <std::size_t ... Is, typename ... Ts, typename ... As>
  static void getH (std::string & rV, std::index_sequence<Is...> const &,
                    std::tuple<Ts...> const t, As ... as)
   { 
     getH(rV.append(", "), std::get<Is>(t)...);
     getH(rV, as...);
   }

  template <typename ... Ts, typename ... As>
  static void getH (std::string & rV, std::tuple<ObjKey, Ts...> const t,
                    As ... as)
   { getH(rV, std::make_index_sequence<1u+sizeof...(Ts)>{}, t, as...); }
```

The key and value versions are managed as follows

```
  template <typename ... As>
  static void getH (std::string & rV, ObjKey const & oK, As ... as)
   {
     getH(rV.append(1u, '{').append(oK.get()), as...);
     rV.append(1u, '}');
   }

  template <typename ... As>
  static void getH (std::string & rV, ObjVal const & oV, As ... as)
   { getH(rV.append(", ").append(oV.get()), as...); }
```

and, obviously, the ground case

```
  static void getH (std::string &)
   { }
```

The public `get()` version become

```
  template <typename ... As>
  static std::string get (As ... as)
   {
     std::string resultValue;
     getH(resultValue, as...);
     return resultValue;
   }
```

Observe that I've transfered the management of the comma from `ObjKey` and `ObjVal` to `getH()` and that I've removed the forwarding semantics (you never used `std::move`).

The following is a full C++14 example

```
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>

class Obj
 {
   public:
      Obj() = delete;

      Obj (std::string const & v0) : v{v0}
       { }

      std::string const & get () const
       { return v; }

   private:
      std::string  v;
 };

struct ObjKey : public Obj
 { ObjKey (std::string const & v0) : Obj{v0} { } };

struct ObjVal : public Obj
 { ObjVal (std::string const & v0) : Obj{v0} { } };

class Builder
 {
   private:
      template <std::size_t ... Is, typename ... Ts, typename ... As>
      static void getH (std::string & rV, std::index_sequence<Is...> const &,
                        std::tuple<Ts...> const t, As ... as)
       { 
         getH(rV.append(", "), std::get<Is>(t)...);
         getH(rV, as...);
       }

      template <typename ... Ts, typename ... As>
      static void getH (std::string & rV, std::tuple<ObjKey, Ts...> const t,
                        As ... as)
       { getH(rV, std::make_index_sequence<1u+sizeof...(Ts)>{}, t, as...); }

      template <typename ... As>
      static void getH (std::string & rV, ObjKey const & oK, As ... as)
       {
         getH(rV.append(1u, '{').append(oK.get()), as...);
         rV.append(1u, '}');
       }

      template <typename ... As>
      static void getH (std::string & rV, ObjVal const & oV, As ... as)
       { getH(rV.append(", ").append(oV.get()), as...); }

      static void getH (std::string &)
       { }

   public:
      template <typename ... As>
      static std::string get (As ... as)
       {
         std::string resultValue;
         getH(resultValue, as...);
         return resultValue;
       }
 };

int main()
 {
   auto result = Builder::get(
      ObjKey("key1"),
      ObjVal("test1"),
      std::make_tuple(ObjKey("key2"), ObjVal("test21"),
                      std::make_tuple(ObjKey("key3"), ObjVal("test31"),
                                      ObjVal("test32")),
                      ObjVal("test22")),
      ObjVal("test2"));

   std::cout << result << "\n";
 }
```

Comment: I can not use C+14 and I can not make a more harder request (according to the requirements): auto result = Builder::get(....

Comment: @Ivan - for a C++11 solution, you can use a C++11 replacement for `std::make_index_sequence` and `std::index_sequence`; I suggest the following [question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17424477/implementation-c14-make-integer-sequence/17426611#17426611); for the not-more-harder-request... I don't understand what do you mean.