# Expand std::vector into parameter pack

Tags: c++11, variadic-templates, stdvector, index-sequence

I have methods with the following signature:

```
void DoStuff(int i);
void DoStuff(int i, k);
void DoStuff(int i, int k, int l);
```

I have a method from where I would like to call the DoStuff methods as follows:

```
void CallDoStuff(const std::vector<int>& vElements) {
  // What magic is supposed to happen here to make vElements an expandable pack?
  DoStuff(vElemets...);
}
```

Is there any chance to achieve this?
Is using std::index_sequence the right way? If yes, could you please provide me a simple example how to apply this to my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible, as long as you provide an upper bound to the number of arguments.

Using [Xeo's implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17426611/3233393) of `std::index_sequence` for C++11:

```
template <unsigned... Idx>
void trampoline(const std::vector<int>& vElements, seq<Idx...>) {
    return DoStuff(vElements[Idx]...);
}

template <std::size_t Arity>
void trampoline(const std::vector<int>& vElements) {
    return trampoline(vElements, typename gen_seq<Arity>::seq{});
}

template <unsigned... Idx>
void CallDoStuff(const std::vector<int>& vElements, seq<Idx...>) {
    using trampoline_t = void (*)(const std::vector<int>&);
    constexpr trampoline_t trampolines[]{
        trampoline<Idx>...
    };
    trampolines[vElements.size()](vElements);
}

template <std::size_t Max>
void CallDoStuff(const std::vector<int>& vElements) {
    assert(vElements.size() <= Max);
    return CallDoStuff(vElements, typename gen_seq<Max + 1>::seq{});
}
```

[See it live on Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/457ukmsODF1blCmI)

Comment: This answer solves my problem best, because I can wrap the function call CallDoStuff<3u>(vElements). But all other answers are also correct.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that, from a `std::vector`, you can't -- **compile** **time** -- extract the `size()` value.

So you can obtain what you want only if you pass, as a compile-time known value, to `CallDoStuff()` the number of elements that you want to use from the vector.

You can pass it as, by example, a template value.

Using an helper function, you can write something as follows

```
template <std::size_t ... Is>
void CallDoStuff (std::vector<int> const & vElements,
                  std::index_sequence<Is...> const &)
 { DoStuff(vElements[Is]...); }

template <std::size_t N>
void CallDoStuff (std::vector<int> const & vElements)
 { CallDoStuff(vElements, std::make_index_sequence<N>{}); }
```

The call could be something as

```
CallDoStuff<5u>(v);
```

If you can use a `std::array`, instead of `std::vector`, the answer is different: you can extract the `size()` from the type itself, so

```
template <std::size_t N, std::size_t ... Is>
void CallDoStuff (std::array<int, N> const & vElements,
                  std::index_sequence<Is...> const &)
 { DoStuff(vElements[Is]...); }

template <std::size_t N>
void CallDoStuff (std::array<int, N> const & vElements)
 { CallDoStuff(vElements, std::make_index_sequence<N>{}); }
```

that is callable without explicating `N` as follows

```
std::array<int, 5u>  arr { 2, 3, 5, 7, 11 };

CallDoStuff(arr); // no more <5u>
```

End note: observe that `std::make_index_sequence` and `std::index_sequence` are available only starting from C++14. In C++11 you have to substitute them in some way.

Comment: I totally agree with you, templates need to know the size at compile-time and the size of the vector is only known at run-time.

Comment: If you use std::array then std::apply is an easy solution.

Comment: @JakeDenham-Dyson - Do you mean `std::apply(DoStuff, arr);`? Unfortunately, in this case, doesn't works in a so easy way: `DoStuff()` is a overloaded function so the compiler can't select the correct version. Moreover, `std::apply()` is introduced in C++17 and the question is tagged C++11 (but this is also a problem of my answer that is C++14).

Comment: Can someone break this down for a noob

Answer (score 0):

This can't be done, a template method call is bound at compile time but a `std::vector` doesn't know how many items it contains until runtime so there's no way to mix the two concepts.

```
DoStuff(vElemets...);
```

Here the compiler should choose the correct implementation according to how many elements `vElements` has. You see the flaw in this kind of thinking since `std::vector` is just an object that could contain any amount of items at point of invocation.

Comment: As already replied to max66, I totally agree with you Jack, templates need to know the size at **compile-time** and the size of the vector is only known at **run-time**.