# Unexpanded parameter pack in function signature

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, template-meta-programming

Newer GCC introduced a new builtin `__integer_pack` to help it implement `std::make_integer_sequence` and friends. For Reasons(tm), I am unable to use this function, so I'm trying to reimplement it (and then use #define to replace the standard library usage)

It's used in the form `__integer_pack(N)...`, which expands its "return value". However I can't convince the type of my own templates to match this, with clang (10) erroring with:

```
error: pack expansion does not contain any unexpanded parameter packs

using make_integer_sequence = integer_sequence<_Tp, integer_pack(_Num)...>;
```

Is this even possible?

Here's what I've got so far:

```cpp
#include <cstddef>


template <std::size_t...> struct index_sequence {};

template <std::size_t N, std::size_t... Is>
struct integer_pack : integer_pack<N - 1, N - 1, Is...> {};

template <std::size_t... Is>
struct integer_pack<0u, Is...> : index_sequence<Is...> { using type = index_sequence<Is...>; };


// Assume nothing below here can be changed.
#include <iostream>

/// Class template integer_sequence
template<typename _Tp, _Tp... _Idx>
struct integer_sequence
{
    typedef _Tp value_type;
    static constexpr size_t size() noexcept { return sizeof...(_Idx); }
};

// debugging aid
template<typename T, T... ints>
void print_sequence(integer_sequence<T, ints...> int_seq)
{
    std::cout << "The sequence of size " << int_seq.size() << ": ";
    ((std::cout << ints << ' '),...);
    std::cout << '\n';
}

template<typename _Tp, _Tp _Num>
using make_integer_sequence = integer_sequence<_Tp, integer_pack(_Num)...>;

int main()
{
    print_sequence(make_integer_sequence<int, 20>{});
}
```

Comment: As it says, you try to expand an instantiation of template rather than a pack. Plain vanilla C++ packs don't work this way, you'll need an extra step.

Comment: `__integer_pack` is a intrinsic to allow unique instantiation for `std::make_integer_sequence` instead of `O(n)` or `O(log(n))`. You cannot replicate that intrinsic, and you have to re-implement `std::make_integer_sequence` another way.

Comment: Why do you think `integer_pack(_Num)...` should work?

Comment: Perhaps [Implementation C++14 make_integer_sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17424477/implementation-c14-make-integer-sequence) can help?

Comment: @user253751 because `__integer_pack(_Num)...` is what is used in the `utility` STL header

Comment: @LordAro Is `__integer_pack` defined the same way as `integer_pack`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this is not possible. `__integer_pack` is not a function, it is a placeholder that is expanded by the compiler into a parameter pack. This is not something you can replicate within the language.

You can look at how gcc implements replacing the call to `__integer_pack` with its expansion in gcc/cp/pt.c, [starting at line 3750](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/c850a642e1dfd3a15335d86976015c4a5064b5df/gcc/cp/pt.c#L3746) currently. `builtin_pack_fn_p()` identifies calls to `__integer_pack` (the `_p` suffix means "predicate"), and `expand_integer_pack` performs the expansion.

You will need to write your own implementation (or copy an existing one) within the language.