# How to simulate std::array<15,int &> with tuples

Tags: c++, c++11, tuples, template-meta-programming

It is clear that `std::array<type,count>` can't store references. However it is possible to write

```
std::tuple<int &, int &, int &, int &, int &>
```

and get what you expect. See

```
#include <array>
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    int a = 10;
    int b = 20;
    int c = 20;

    // Does not compile
    //std::array<int&,3> x = {a,b,c};

    using TInt3 = std::tuple<int&,int&,int&>;
    TInt3 y = {a,b,c};

    std::cout << sizeof(TInt3) << std::endl;
    std::get<0>(y)=11;
    std::cout << "a " << a << std::endl;
}
```

where `a 11` is output. It is however tedious writing it out long hand. How can I generate a type ( in c++11 )

`TupleAllSame<type, count>`

so that the following are equivalent

```
TupleAllSame<int &, 2>   <--> std::tuple<int &, int &>
TupleAllSame<double, 4>  <--> std::tuple<double, double, double, double>
TupleAllSame<std::string &, 3>  <--> std::tuple<std::string &, std::string &, std::string &>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on a [C++11 implementation of `std::index_sequence`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32223343/3233393) (that I stuffed into the `std14` namespace):

```
namespace impl {
    template <class T, class Idx>
    struct TupleAllSame;
    
    template <class T, std::size_t... Idx>
    struct TupleAllSame<T, std14::index_sequence<Idx...>> {
        template <class U, std::size_t>
        using depend = U;
    
        using type = std::tuple<depend<T, Idx>...>;
    };
}

template <class T, std::size_t Size>
using TupleAllSame = typename impl::TupleAllSame<T, typename std14::make_index_sequence<Size>::type>::type;
```

[See it live on Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/G5X5wSGArFejPNoq)

Comment: @Scheff clarified :)

Answer (score 4):

`std::reference_wrapper` can be used as element of array. Syntax will be a little convoluted sometimes, but it works:

```
#include <functional>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    int a = 10;
    int b = 20;
    int c = 20;

    using rint = std::reference_wrapper<int>;
    std::array<rint,3> x = {a,b,c};

    std::cout << "a " << a << std::endl;
    x[0].get()=11;
    std::cout << "a " << a << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution without index_sequence based on **recursion** ( [Wandbox Live](https://wandbox.org/permlink/pL8vWYwUDljTyqLI))

```
#include<iostream>
#include <tuple>
using namespace std;

template <int N, typename T, typename SeqWithArgs>
struct append;

template <int N, typename T, template <typename...> class Seq, typename... Args >
struct append<N, T, Seq<Args...> >
{
    using type = typename append<N - 1, T, Seq<T, Args...> >::type;
};

template <typename T, template<typename...> class Seq, typename... Args>
struct append<0, T, Seq<Args...> >
{
    using type = Seq<Args...>;
};

template <typename T, size_t Size>
using TupleAllSame = typename append<Size, T, std::tuple<> >::type;

int main()
{
    int a = 0, b = 1, c = 2;
    TupleAllSame<int&, 3> t = { a,b, c };

    get<0>(t) = 10;
    cout << "a = " << a << endl;

    return 0;
}
```