# C++ initialize array class with default value

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to create an open hash table.
And i want to use an array of lists, where the size of the array is a template parameter, but the problem is i don't know how to pass an allocator to all of the list instances, and i cannot use vector, because i will need another allocator for list allocation (alloception), is there a way to initialize a whole array of lists with the same value?
I know i can initialize like this `list<int> mylist[] = {{allocator}, {allocator}, {allocator}}`

But the idea is to have size as a template variable.
Example:

```
template<typename KEY, typename VAL, typename ALLOC=std::allocator<struct _internal>, size_t TBL_SIZE=100>
class open_hash_table{
private: 
   std::list<struct _internal, ALLOC=ALLOC> _table[TBL_SIZE];
public: 
    open_hash_table(ALLOC allocator=ALLOC())
    :_table({allocator, allocator ... allocator}){}
};
```

P.s. my compiler supports upto c++11

Comment: Since the table size is rather large (100), I think a loop is better than aggregate initialization.

Comment: If you can afford it, the easiest way would be to just default construct elements and then [`std::fill()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill) (or [`.fill()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/fill) for `std::array`) it with elements constructed with allocators. Otherwise, you'd probably need to wrap `std::list` with some class that will default-construct `list` with your allocator.

Comment: You can create storage array for lists, and then initialize all the lists there using placement new.

Comment: You can create a initializer list recursively with vardiac templates. It's really ugly. My suggesti9on would be to get a newer compiler. This is so much simpler with more modern c++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This uses C++14 for [`std::make_index_sequence`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence) and the `std::index_sequence` it produces but you can make your own implementation as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17424477/implementation-c14-make-integer-sequence).  Using a [delegating constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor) you can add another constructor that takes an `index_sequence` so you can then expand the sequence and get a variadic list of values like

```
template<typename KEY, typename VAL, typename ALLOC=std::allocator<struct _internal>, size_t TBL_SIZE=100>
class open_hash_table{
private: 
    std::list<struct _internal, ALLOC> _table[TBL_SIZE];
    template <std::size_t... Is>
    open_hash_table(ALLOC allocator, std::index_sequence<Is...>) 
    : _table{ std::list<struct _internal, ALLOC>{((void)Is, allocator)}... } {}
public: 
    open_hash_table(ALLOC allocator=ALLOC())
    : open_hash_table(allocator, std::make_index_sequence<TBL_SIZE>{}) {}
};
```

Your public constructor will call the private helper constructor and pass along an `index_sequence` that will have `TBL_SIZE` number of elements in it.  Then in the delegating constructor the `((void)Is, allocator)` part uses the comma operator to use each element of the `index_sequence` but we discard that in instead let the expression resolve to `allocator`.  The `(void)Is` part casts the result of `Is` to `void` to suppress that it is unused.  We have to use `std::list<struct _internal, ALLOC>{ ... }` as well because the constructor that takes an allocator is `explicit` so the type needs to be specified, no implicit conversion allowed.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to initialize `_table` directly in member initializer lists through some metaprogramming techniques, but since `TBL_SIZE`'s default value is `100`, this will make the compile-time overhead slightly larger. It is more appropriate to just default construct `_table` and initializes its value in the constructor body.

And since `TBL_SIZE` is a compile-time constant, instead of using a raw array, you can just use `std::array`:

```
template<typename KEY, typename VAL, typename ALLOC=std::allocator<_internal>, size_t TBL_SIZE=100>
class open_hash_table{
private:
  std::array<std::list<_internal, ALLOC>, TBL_SIZE> _table;
public:
  open_hash_table(ALLOC allocator=ALLOC()) {
    _table.fill(std::list<_internal, ALLOC>(allocator));
  }
};
```

Also since this is C++, the `struct` keyword in `struct _internal` is unnecessary.