# Including "vector.h" or "vector" causes warnings or errors

Tags: c++

If I put `#include <vector.h>` in my source file, I get this warning:

```
make -f Makefile CFG=Debug 
g++ -c    -g -o "Debug/mynn.o"  "mynn.cpp"
In file included from C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.5/../../../../include/c++/3.4.5/backward/vector.h:59,
                 from mynn.h:7,
                 from mynn.cpp:1:
**C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.5/../../../../include/c++/3.4.5/backward/backward_warning.h:32:2: warning: #warning This file includes at least one deprecated or antiquated header. Please consider using one of the 32 headers found in section 17.4.1.2 of the C++ standard. Examples include substituting the <X> header for the <X.h> header for C++ includes, or <iostream> instead of the deprecated header <iostream.h>. To disable this warning use -Wno-deprecated.**
g++  -g -o "Debug/mynn.exe" Debug/mynn.o
```

and if I just add regular `#include <vector>` (without .h, like the warning suggests), I get the following errors:

```
make -f Makefile CFG=Debug 
g++ -c    -g -o "Debug/mynn.o"  "mynn.cpp"
In file included from mynn.cpp:1:
**mynn.h:12: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of `vector' with no type
mynn.h:12: error: expected `;' before '<' token
mynn.h:13: error: `vector' has not been declared
mynn.h:13: error: expected `,' or `...' before '<' token
mynn.h:13: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of `parameter' with no type
mynn.h:20: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of `vector' with no type
mynn.h:20: error: expected `;' before '<' token
mynn.h:21: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of `vector' with no type
mynn.h:21: error: expected `;' before '<' token**
```

Is there a better way to include the vector header this so that it doesn't complain? Here's the source file that generates the warnings/errors:

```
// mynn.h
#ifndef _MYNN_H_
#define _MYNN_H_

#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <vector>

class neuron {
public:
    neuron();
    vector<int> weights;
    int compute_sum (vector <int> &input);
};

class layer
{
public:
    layer();
    vector <neuron> nrns;
    vector<int> compute_layer (vector <int> &input);
};

#endif /*_MYNN_H_*/
```

Comment: if you are writing c++ code, don't mess up with c style headers. use <cstdio> & <cmath>. the c style headers <module.h> can be used as c++ style header: <cmodule>.

Comment: `_MYNN_H_` is a reserved identifier, [don't use it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier).

Answer (score 31):

The problem is that `vector<T>` lives in the `std` namespace and you're attempting to use the type without any qualification or appropriate `using` statement.  The safest fix is to explicitly qualify uses of the type with the `std` prefix.

```
std::vector<neuron> nrns;
```

This can also be fixed by explicitly importing the type via a `using` statement.

```
using std::vector;
```

I would avoid this approach though.  Adding `using` statements to header files, while legal, is bad practice because it can change how items are compiled.  This form safer than a blanket import of `std` but is still not great.

Comment: You mean `using namespace std;`

Comment: `using namespace ...` is frowned up by enough people to consider the alternative - only `using` what you really need. I.e. `using std::vector;`.

Comment: Sorry Jared, but a heartfelt `-1` from me for listing the worst alternative first. (Many won't read any further.)

Comment: @sbi, it's your decision but it's a matter of personal preference and opinion that you're downvoting me on.  The answer is correct (all 3 of them I provided).  If you feel you have a better answer then add it and your reasons.  Downvoting seems inappropriate.

Comment: @Jared: You just ran into [one of my pet peeves](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2879555/c-stl-how-to-write-wrappers-for-cout-cerr-cin-and-endl/2880136#2880136). Sorry for that, but it's not as if your answer would need my vote. (Usually a public down-vote seen as unjustified is more than made up for by the community.) Also, Kirill has already given the answer I would have (which is why I up-voted his).

Comment: Because when I include `mynn.h` I want the entire `std` namespace thrown into the global one...sorry, I'm with @sbi on this. Obviously this is all subjective in an ivory tower, but in practice you've listed the worse solution first.

Comment: @GMan, @sbi, fine, changed my answer order.  I still think it's bad practice to downvote a valid answer on a matter of personal preference.  All my answers are valid.  If you think there is a better answer then provide it vs. downvoting a correct one.

Comment: @Jared: It's not a personal preference. Qualifying `std::vector`, `using std::vector` and `using namespace std;` do *different* things, and the last two are regarded as bad practice in a header; and often times in a source file. Personal preference is brace style, not completely different behaviors. If someone asked "how do I get a dynamic array" and an answer said "use `new int[size]`" either first or without mentioning `std::vector<int>` it would also get a downvote, because teaching people something besides idiomatic C++ isn't helpful. Same here. Don't put using declarations in a header.

Comment: @GMan, My bad.  I read this as being a source file (not a header) file.  Agree it is evil in a header file.

Comment: @Jared: It's okay. I'll still say I disagree with `using std::vector`, but you've removed the bad part so -1 goes away. (Also, the answer feels a bit weird with "The problem is that you haven't imported the std namespace", since that's the bad part and not what your answer does.)

Comment: Jared, I hadn't seen your reply (why, oh why does SO not show replies to several commentators?), but your Twitter rant brought me back here. `:)` Turned my down-vote into an up-vote.

Comment: @sbi, I think it was my fault for not putting your alias in the comment response.  I believe it just looks at the names listed directly in every comment.  But yeah, total misread of the question by me.

Comment: @Jared: You did list my name, you even properly @attributed it, but GMan's name was first, and SO only notifies the first commenter you @address. (FWIW, I would have down-voted even if it wasn't a header. SO you're still entitled to your rant. `:)`)

Answer (score 14):

`vector` belongs to `std` namespace. You need to fully qualify its name as `std::vector<int>`.

I need to clarify that the C++ Standard allows you to use all options that JaredPar gave in his answer, but I would strongly recommend not to use `using namespace std` and especially in the header files. About `using namespace std` you can find well described opinion in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265039/using-std-namespace/1265092#1265092) question. Personally I'm agree with it, so allow me to link it in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed,
you need to specify std::vector as vector is not global.
But I would rather advice you to NOT use `using` keyword.

The problem is the scope of the using, and the conflicts that could raise after.
MOREOVER if you're planning to have a portable apps (code), (especially for library) you should avoid sush a thing because you can't be sure of the side effects on other plateforms, for the future users of your code.