# C2146 Missing ; in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am getting the following the following errors when I try to compile in VS 2010. It is also complaining that string is undefined, which makes no sense, as I clearly included it. I understand what the errors mean, but they don't seem to make any sense:

`1>c:\users\jon\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\project 2\project 2\userfactory.cpp(11): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'profession'
1>c:\users\jon\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\project 2\project 2\userfactory.cpp(11): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\users\jon\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\project 2\project 2\userfactory.cpp(11): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\users\jon\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\project 2\project 2\userfactory.cpp(16): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'
1>c:\users\jon\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\project 2\project 2\userfactory.cpp(16): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\users\jon\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\project 2\project 2\userfactory.cpp(16): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
1>c:\users\jon\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\project 2\project 2\userfactory.cpp(23): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'string'
1>c:\users\jon\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\project 2\project 2\userfactory.cpp(19): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'map'`

This is my code:

```
#include "objbase.h" //I found this recommendation while googling, but had the errors prior to adding this.
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <utility>

class UserFactory {
public:
    class User {
        char gender;
        int id;
    string profession;// line 11
    int zip;
    friend class UserFactory;
};
private:
map<int,User*>* map;

public:
UserFactory() : map(new map<int,User*>()) { }

virtual ~UserFactory(void);

void process(string s) {
    //user id | age | gender | occupation | zip code

}
};
```

Any help would be appreciated before I rip my hair out!

Thanks!

Comment: should that not be std::string profession?

Answer (score 5):

string is part of the std namespace, so you must refer to it as std::string. The same applies to map.

Comment: Or you could use `using namespace std;`.

Comment: or `using std::string;` to import only `string` into the default namespace.

Comment: @Fabian: That's something [I'd advice against](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2879555/2880136#2880136).