# Need help with my recursive program that reverses the input

Tags: c++, string, recursion, reverse, std

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Write a recursive function that reverses the input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5760774/write-a-recursive-function-that-reverses-the-input)

Recently, I've been reading the book C++ For Everyone and I've been having trouble putting together a recursive function (Confusing to think about...)

The question was: Write a recursive function `string reverse(string str)` that returns the reverse of `str`

This is what I have so far:

```
string reverse(string str)
{
    string word = "";

    if (str.length() <= 1)
    {
        return str;
    }
    else
    {
        string str_copy = str;
        int n = str_copy.length() - 1;
        string last_letter = str_copy.substr(n, 1);

        str_copy = str_copy.substr(0, n);
        word += reverse(str_copy);
        return last_letter;
    }
    return word;
}
```

My problems now is:

If I enter `wolf`, it returns `f`

If I change `return last_letter` to `return word`, I get `w`

If I change to `return str_copy`, I get `wol`

Comment: Is this question different from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5760774/write-a-recursive-function-that-reverses-the-input? It looks pretty similar.

Comment: Well, people stop answering after around 45 mins

Comment: That's a wrong perception. If you don't satisfy with the kind of answers given, wait at least for half a day. Then, you could start bounty for the same question instead of posting it again.

Comment: Heh, repost because 45 minutes passed. I lol'd.

Comment: No. Repost 'cause nobody's posting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would do the work:

Delete return last_letter;

Change         `

```
word += reverse(str_copy);
```

to

```
word = last_letter+reverse(str_copy);
```

I'll leave the thinking to you!

Best.

Comment: YES. IT WORKS!!!!!! Started this yesterday and can't figure it out. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You need to return the combination of the the last character (`last_letter`) and the reversal of the rest of the string, but you don't do that in any of your attempts. You only ever return one part or the other.

```
string reverse(string str)
{
    int len = str.length();
    if (len <= 1)
    {
        return str;
    }
    else
    {
        return str.substr(len-1, 1) + reverse( str.substr(0, len-1) );
    }
}
```

Comment: Off by one error -- should be `reverse( str.substr(0, len-1) );` otherwise the inner `reverse` has the same `str` as the outer `reverse`.