# gcc: is there no tail recursion if I return std::string in C++?

Tags: c++, g++, compiler-optimization, tail-recursion, clang++

As per my answer in [Write a recursive function that reverses the input string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5760774/write-a-recursive-function-that-reverses-the-input-string/36900592#36900592), I've tried seeing whether `clang++ -O3` or `g++ -O3` would make a tail-recursion optimisation, using some of the suggestions from [How do I check if gcc is performing tail-recursion optimization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/490324/how-do-i-check-if-gcc-is-performing-tail-recursion-optimization), but it doesn't look like any tail recursion optimisation is taking place.  Any idea why?

Does this have to do with the way C++ objects are created and destroyed?  Is there any way to make it work?

The programme:

```
% cat t2.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::string
rerev1(std::string s)
{
        if (s.empty())
                return s;
        return rerev1(s.substr(1)) + s[0];
}

std::string
rerev2(std::string s, std::string b = "")
{
        if (s.empty())
                return b;
        return rerev2(s.substr(1), s[0] + b);
}

int
main()
{
        std::cout << rerev1("testing") << std::endl;
        std::cout << rerev2("testing") << std::endl;
}
```

The testing (if the tail recursion optimisation would have been taking place, I'd expect there'd only be one call to each version of the function, not two):

```
% clang++ -Wall -O3 t2.cpp
% objdump --disassemble a.out | fgrep rerev | fgrep callq
  400d8f:       e8 ac ff ff ff          callq  400d40 <_Z6rerev1Ss>
  400fd1:       e8 5a ff ff ff          callq  400f30 <_Z6rerev2SsSs>
  401168:       e8 d3 fb ff ff          callq  400d40 <_Z6rerev1Ss>
  40128d:       e8 9e fc ff ff          callq  400f30 <_Z6rerev2SsSs>

% g++ -O3 t2.cpp
% objdump --disassemble a.out | fgrep rerev | fgrep callq
  400c93:       e8 28 02 00 00          callq  400ec0 <_Z6rerev1Ss>
  400cfa:       e8 11 03 00 00          callq  401010 <_Z6rerev2SsSs>
  400f25:       e8 96 ff ff ff          callq  400ec0 <_Z6rerev1Ss>
  4010ca:       e8 41 ff ff ff          callq  401010 <_Z6rerev2SsSs>

% clang++ -v
Debian clang version 3.0-6.2 (tags/RELEASE_30/final) (based on LLVM 3.0)
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix

% g++ --version
g++ (Debian 4.7.2-5) 4.7.2
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

Comment: It may be hard to do TRO if you need to call destructors before returning a value. Try `const string&` parameters, but there's no guarantee...

Comment: @n.m., changed `s` to be of type `const std::string&` as you suggest, but still getting the same thing

Comment: You still have to destroy the temporary you are returning.

Comment: You may have better luck with moving, try `string&&`.

Comment: @n.m., i don't think `string&&` is even valid...

Comment: It most definitely is valid. You need to enable C++11 because it is still mot the default with g++. You also need to read up on C++11.

Comment: I think you need to update your version of clang. The current release is 3.8. I am using apple clang 7.3 and the whole program gets inlined.

Comment: @RichardHodges, I'm running the latest clang on Debian wheezy; how exactly did they get from no tail-recursion-optimisation to inlining the whole thing in a couple of releases?  And does it imply that gcc/g++ is now that much behind, too?

Comment: @cnst I don't think anyone is using gcc lower than 5.3 if they can help it. version 6 is due out this summer.