# Enforce constness for pointed data in C++?

Tags: c++, oop, pointers, constants

Let there be a `Foo` class with some const and non-const methods

```
struct Foo
{
    Foo ();
    ~Foo();

    void noSideEffect() const;
    void withSideEffect();

};
```

I also have a `Bar` class, that need to refer to `Foo` in some way. To be more precise, maybe too precise for this question, Bar implements operators `||` and `&&` for union and intersections, so **two `Bar` instances need to kwow they are working on the same instance of `Foo`**.

The simplest solution I found was to use a pointer to a `Foo` object:

```
struct Bar
{

   Foo * p_foo;

   Bar (Foo& foo)
     : p_foo(&foo) {};

}
```

Now two bar instances can play together and see if they are both handling the same Foo. I'm almost happy.

But now I would like to sometimes use Bar with `const Foo` instances. Well, it might be easy, I just have to create a `const Bar` instance, right? There we go:

```
const Bar createBarFromConstFoo(const Foo& foo)
{
   Foo* newfoo = const_cast<Foo*>(&foo);
   const Bar newbar (*newfoo);
   return newbar;
}
```

And now the nightmare begins (see [Why doesn't C++ enforce const on pointer data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5945507/why-doesnt-c-enforce-const-on-pointer-data)). I think I understand the *why* (the standard says so), my main problem is *how* to best cope with it.

Except this little standard thing, the createBarFomConstFoo does almost what I want since it is returning a `const Bar`. 
Is there a way to prevent a `const Bar` to do nasty things with my (initially) `const Foo` (ie only call const methods of Foo) while allowing a non-const Bar to do everything?

Maybe there is no way to do that and it's an object design issue, but I do not see a simple alternative.

Edit: to downvoters, can you please explain why, I may be able to progress from your remarks...

**Edit 2**: Maybe obfuscating the real classes behing Foo and Bar was a bad idea, I just wanted to simplify things.

So `Foo` is in fact a Molecule (and in fact a Protein), which contains Atoms (many for a protein). Being able to select some atoms is the reason to create Bar, which is a `SelectionOfAtoms`.

It is sometimes convenient to select, from example, all hydrogens and oxygen atoms, so Bar implements unions and intersections. I want to be able to extract those atoms so SelectionOfAtoms implements a createNewMolecule() methods from the selected atoms. It therefore need a way to refer to the original molecule (maybe some kind of copy would do here but maybe not with the other requirements below).

But I recently felt the need to modify atoms of a selection, while keeping other atoms unmodified. Doing it through SelectionOfAtoms (Bar) was conveninent: it already knows where to find the Atoms (using the pointer) and the index of these atoms (internal implementation detail), so everything needed to change atoms is almost already here, except that I can either use Selection only on Molecule (non-const) or work on const Molecule and forget about modifying them or go into the const_cast horror.

I'm sure it's a pretty bad design, but it is what is already there, it can surely be improved a lot.

Comment: with a `Foo * const ptr` Bar can never modify Foo if I'm correct. I want a non-const `Bar` to do anything with its `Foo` while preventing a `const Bar` to call methods modifying the data pointed by `ptr`.

Comment: You may do something like `const_iterator`/`iterator`. (maybe make `Bar` a template class which use a some `policy`).

Comment: The nightmare begins the minute you type `const_cast`

Comment: Do the `Bar` instances need to ever modify the contents of the `Foo` object? Or do they just care about the identity (address) of the object?

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas I know const_cast is a code smell, but I was soooo close...

Comment: *I know shooting a gun inside the house is a bad decision, but I was so close to turning the light off from the couch...*. If you can answer the questions in the above comment we might be able to help there.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas It would be way more convenient in my case to allow Bar to modify the Foo. I used a `const Foo*` before and I found this problem when I wanted to allow Bar to modify Foo.

Comment: You should use `shared_ptr` to const types. See this question for an explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17793333/difference-between-const-shared-ptrt-and-shared-ptrconst-t

Comment: @RobK correct me if I'm wrong but than `Bar` would never be able to modify `Foo`

Comment: If I have understood correctly, either you will not modify Foo and you can store a const reference in your Bar class or you want to modify Foo and you shouldn't accept a const reference as input of your function in the first place.

Comment: Correct, `Bar` would not be able to modify `Foo`. But if you want to have a Bar that can have (point to) a constant Foo, there's simply no way around it. You just can't cleanly have a non-const pointer or reference which points to a const object. An object is not really const until construction is complete. N.B. my point with making the comment was to encourage you to use smart pointers instead of raw pointers, not to answer the general question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the STL as a guide, consider your molecule as a container, and your selection as something like an iterator or iterator range.

Now, in this scheme you'd have *separate types* for the const and non-const selections/iterators, which makes sense since they have different semantics. Making the constness a template parameter is probably a false economy unless there's a lot more code in the selection than you've suggested.

Now, you start off with either a const or a non-const `molecule`, and you know statically that you're getting ether a `const_selection` or (non-const) `selection`.

Comment: To be clear you are suggesting creating classes Bar and const_Bar. Correct?

Comment: Yes, that's the simplest idea.

Answer (score -1):

It `Bar` is not overly complex, you can make it a class template.

```
template <typename FooType>
struct Bar
{

   FooType * p_foo;

   Bar (FooType& foo)
     : p_foo(&foo) {};

}

template <typename FooType>
Bar<FooType> makeBar(FooType& foo)
{
   return Bar<FooType>(foo);
}
```