# C++ command line strings like Java?

Tags: c++

Is there a way to get c++ strings from the commandline like in Java?

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

where args is an array of C++ strings?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Not precisely but you can come close easily.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

typedef vector<string> CommandLineStringArgs;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    CommandLineStringArgs cmdlineStringArgs(&argv[0], &argv[0 + argc]);

    for (int i = 0; i < cmdlineStringArgs.size(); ++i)
    {
        cout << cmdlineStringArgs[i] << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This just uses the overloaded constructor for std::vector that takes a begining/ending iterator pair to copy the command line arguments into the vectors.  It is much the same as java from there on.

You can likewise build and object around that vector with utility methods to convert arguments but there is almost no point.  Also there are plenty of packages with object that deal with interpreting command line switches and such.  ACE, POCO, QT, etc.. all come with such facilities.

Comment: What is the purpose of first copying all arguments into a `std::vector`? The same loop could just as well iterate over `argv` directly.

Comment: @sbi - the point is that it answered OP's question.  What he wants to accomplish is better directed to OP.

Comment: That's nonsense. Indexing into `argv` would have answered sean's question just as well. Nowhere was he asking how to get that arguments into a vector. You've just shown him a needlessly roundabout way.

Comment: He specifically wrote "where args is an array of C++ strings", not C strings.

Comment: what's the point of that `typedef`? If you ask me, it does nothing but obfuscate the code...

Answer (score 11):

You can use a vector to get the char array into strings.

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
    vector <string> args (argv, argv + argc);
}
```

Comment: I'd upvote this if it wouldn't be `using namespace std`. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2879555/c-stl-how-to-write-wrappers-for-cout-cerr-cin-and-endl/2880136#2880136)

Comment: @sbi That's not necessarily a bad thing to be doing inside a .cpp file. If this were a header or anything more complicated than an example 1-function file I might tend to agree with you. He is not at the same time using Boost or any other huge library, so name collisions should not be a problem.

Comment: This really isn't the standard way to pass arguments to a C++ program.

Comment: @xDD: I disagree even in a cpp file. And I provided a link to an explanation _why_ I think so.

Comment: @Sevis: Indeed! I overlooked that. I went in and fixed this. It's not as if there was a controversy about that as with the other issue.

Answer (score 3):

Yes the main function can take 2 arguments

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
```

Where `argc` is the number of arguments and `argv` contains a list of the arguments.

For example if you run your program as:

```
MyProgram.exe hello
```

Then

```
argc = 2
argv[0] = MyProgram.exe
argv[1] = "hello"
```

Answer (score 1):

Not built in to the language, but its very easy to implement:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) {
    vector <string> args;
    for ( int i = 0; i < argc; i++ ) {
        args.push_back( argv[i] );
    }
    // do something with args
}
```

Comment: You don't need that loop, `std::vector` has a nice ctor for that.

Comment: @sbi I know, but the OP will probably understand my code more easily.

Comment: You could simple use : `std::vector<string> args(argv, agrv+argc);`.

Comment: @Nawaz Isn't that what @sbi just said, and to which I replied?

Answer (score 0):

In C, your main function signature looks like this:

`int main(int argc, char** argv)`.

`argc` contains the number of arguments passed in by the command line. The name of the executable is in position 0, and adds one to `argc`.

`argv` contains an array of strings containing the arguments. Again, position 0 is the name of the executable.

Answer (score 0):

The standard C++ `main()` signature is

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
```

where `argc` denotes the count of commandline arguments and `argv[]` is an array of primitive C strings holding the commandline arguments. `argv[0]` is the executable, as invoked from the commandline.

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing a win32 application, you can use GetCommandLineW http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683156(VS.85).aspx and CommandLineToArgW http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776391(VS.85).aspx

There is a comment on the CommandLineToArg page about special handling that is needed if your executable has spaces in the path and there are no arguments that you might have to handle.