# C++ String Class Input

Tags: c++, string

I'm attempting to read in user inputted values about put them into a string class array, but I'm getting a `BAD EXCESS` error, I'm guessing its something really simple that I'm doing wrong. Here is what I got. Any help would be great

```
int main()
{
   const int SIZE = 5;
   string fruity[SIZE];
   int i;

   cout << "Enter the names of five kinds of fruit:" << endl;
   for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
   {
      cout << "Enter Name of Fruit" << endl;
      getline(cin, fruity[i]);
   }

   cout << fruity[i] << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's "bad excess"...? Overeating?

Comment: not technically homework since I'm trying to self-teach

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
cout << fruity[i] << endl;
```

This is invalid. Do this instead:

```
for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
     cout << fruity[i] << endl;
```

Because at that point your `i` will be equal to `SIZE`, and `fruity[SIZE]` is invalid.

Comment: so is the `fruity` array now populated with the user inputted values?

Comment: `fruity[0]` should be `fruity[i]`??

Comment: Als, yes, a typo.
jooMLA, yes yes it is. In the loop, you don't create a temporary variable but use an existing one, therefore after the loop i = SIZE, and you cannot fruity[size], so you need another loop.

Comment: @LaurynasTretjakovas - would there be a more efficient way to do it, so that I didn't have to use `i` ? Somehow I could just use `SIZE` ? it all seems kind of sloppy and yes I'm new to this.

Comment: You mean: `cout << fruity[i] << endl;`. Use `@muntoo` to notify me once you're done so you can get the upvote.

Comment: @jooMLA there is. Delete the i variable then change the loops from for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) to for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) - notice the int in the beginning, a temporary variable will be created and you won't have to declare it in main.

Answer (score 2):

After the for loop, the variable `i` has the value `SIZE` and so when you try to access it you go out of bounds. You will have to use another loop if you want to output it like so:

```
for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
    cout << fruity[i] << endl;
}
```

Comment: `i` is declared outside the `for` loop.

Comment: Eugh. What happened there. Edited to fix the real problem.

Comment: so is the array now populated by the inputs? so if I wanted to send it to a selection sort I could?

Comment: What happened? What happened is, Your previous answer was wrong and that was what my comment pointed out. Then you edited the answer and cameback to ask What happened? Really?

Comment: @jooMLA Yes. You populated it with input in the previous `for` loop.

Comment: @Als What? I'm just saying "Oops. I made a mistake but I've seen the problem now so I'll edit my answer so it's still useful"

Comment: @quasiverse - Thx. What would be the arguments for the function? `function(string fruit[], int SIZE)` ?

Comment: @jooMLA Yes. That would be correct although many others here would strongly prefer that you use something like a `vector<string>`.

Answer (score 1):

In the following statement

```
cout << fruity[i] << endl;
```

"i" is out of range. The value of "i", when exiting the for loop "5" And your compiler should have warned you about using "i" outside the scope of the for-loop. Your for-loop sets fruity[0], fruity[1], fruity[2], fruity[3], fruity[4], but "fruity[5]" is out of range.  Hence, garbage data when you try to print "fruity[i]".  This leads to a seg fault crash.

Answer (score 1):

*Always* make variables ***as local as possible***. C++ allows you to define loop variables within the loop

```
 for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
 {
   ...
 }
 // i no longer in scope
```

so that they fall out of scope at the end of the loop, which is as local as it gets.

Doing this will reveal that you are currently using `i` for accessing the array *after the loop*, at which point `i` has the value `SIZE`, resulting in an ***access out of bounds***. (Remember, arrays have the indexes `0..SIZE-1`.)

I have no idea what the final line in your program

```
cout << fruity[i] << endl;
```

is supposed to do, but if you want to output the array's conetent (as other answers suggest), you will indeed need another loop.

Other, more minor points:

1. We don't really know what string class you are using, because you omitted the `std::` prefix. (The same goes for all the other identifiers from the std library you are using.) [I disapprove of that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2879555/c-stl-how-to-write-wrappers-for-cout-cerr-cin-and-endl/2880136#2880136).
2. The correct type for array indexes is `std::size_t`.
3. The `std::endl` manipulator will insert a `'\n'` into an output stream *and flush the stream's buffer*. In an interactive console program as yours is this usually doesn't do any harm. Remember it, though, as flushing the buffer prematurely might considerably slow down a program. (I have seen a case were a program writing a lot of data into a file stream in trickles of a couple of bytes was slowed down by an order of magnitude due to this.) In your case, flushing the output stream#s buffer manually is never really necessary. (Of course, you do want your prompts to appear before you read from the input stream, but this is achieved by `std::cout` being tied to `std::cin` by default, making `std::cout` flush whenever the program attempts to read from `std::cin`.)

The program, as I would write it, would look like this:

```
// Beware, brain-compiled code ahead!
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   const std::size_t size = 5;
   std::string fruity[size];

   std::cout << "Enter the names of five kinds of fruit:" << '\n';
   for(std::size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
   {
      std::cout << "Enter Name of Fruit" << '\n';
      std::getline(std::cin, fruity[i]);
   }

   for(std::size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
   {
     std::cout << fruity[i] << `\n`;
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
{
   cout << fruity[i] << endl;
}
```

Comment: A loop or `std::for_each` with `#include <algorithm>`.