# Should `using std::cin` and `using std::cout` be avoided or encouraged?

Tags: c++, coding-style, code-readability

I searched this site and people says you should avoid using `using namespace std`. I totally agree. However, what about `using std::cin` and `using std::string`? Should this be avoided or encouraged?

I know always type `std::cin` is the safest choice, but it is very tedious to type them again and again.

However, when you type `using std::cin` etc in the begining of the file, it seems very crowd. For example, this simple program read and calculate student grade, in front of it, there are **too many** `using std::`, it look very uncomfortable.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ios>
#include <iomanip>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <vector>
using std::cin;             using std::cout;
using std::istream;         using std::vector;
using std::setprecision;    using std::domain_error;
using std::string;          using std::getline;
using std::streamsize;

istream& read_hw(istream& in, vector<double>& homework);
double grade(double mid_exam, double final_exam, \
        const vector<double>& homework);

int main()  {

    std::string name;
    std::getline(std::cin, name);
    std::cout << "Hello, " + name + "!" << std::endl;

    double mid_exam, final_exam;
    std::cin >> mid_exam >> final_exam;

    std::vector<double> homework;
    read_hw(std::cin, homework);

    try {
        double final_grade = grade(mid_exam, final_exam, homework);
        std::streamsize prec = std::cout.precision();
        std::cout << "your final grade is:" << std::setprecision(3)
            << final_grade << std::setprecision(prec) << std::endl;
    }
    catch(std::domain_error)    {
        std::cout << std::endl << "No homework entered!" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}

std::istream& read_hw(std::istream& in, std::vector<double>& homework)   {
    if(in)  {
        homework.clear();
        double x;
        while(in >> x)  {
            homework.push_back(x);
        }
    }
    in.clear();

    return in;
}

double grade(double mid_exam, double final_exam, \
        const std::vector<double>& homework)    {
    std::vector<double>::size_type i, size;
    size = homework.size();
    if(size ==0)    {
        throw std::domain_error("no homework grade entered!");
    }
    double sum = 0;
    double average = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < size; ++i)   {
        sum += homework[i];
    }
    average = sum/size;

    return mid_exam*0.3 + final_exam*0.3 + average*0.4;
}
```

In [python's tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package), it says:

> Remember, there is nothing wrong with using `from Package import
>   specific_submodule`! In fact, this is the recommended notation unless
>   the importing module needs to use submodules with the same name from
>   different packages.

I want to know what I should do in c++ programs.

Comment: Personally I would recommend you always use `std::string` and such unless you scope the using statements to a function scope.  Even then I like to just use std:: to be explicit.

Comment: I notice you have a `using std::vector`, but then you refer to `std::vector` in the code.  Having both cannot be right.

Comment: Also, that line continuation for the arguments of `grade` is unneeded/undesirable

Comment: Finally, you don't restore the precision if writing the output throws.

Comment: @MartinBonner I haven't got time to delete those `std::` in the program...

Comment: @buzhidao: find the time. We all have the same amount of time.

Comment: you mean `\\` symbol? I remembered that I should use it when split lines? in python or some other cases?

Comment: This backslash isn't necessary neither in python or C++

Comment: @GabrielVasconcelos Only necessary when in middle of a string?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2879555/c-standard-library-how-to-write-wrappers-for-cout-cerr-cin-and-endl/2880136#2880136

Comment: @buzhidao neither in this case, [see](http://ideone.com/jg2uk6)

Comment: @GabrielVasconcelos Thank you very much!

Comment: @buzhidao you answered your own question with the quote from python. This is not really a c++ question

Comment: @MuhammadAhmad That link is really helpful, thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Never** use `using namespace std;` or similar in a **header file** as it can cause all sorts of ambiguity issues that arise due to namespace *pollution*. If you obey that rule then folk who have to include your headers will thank you for it. I'd also avoid any sort of `using std::...` in headers for similar reasons. Learn to love the more verbose `std::` notation.

What you get up to in a source file is largely down to you. Any recommendations here are largely opinion-based, but personally, I *never* use `using` just to save typing, but rather when it's unavoidable such as bringing shadowed functions back into a namespace, and in template metaprogramming.

Comment: You should vote to close as POB if all the OP is going to get is Opinions.

Comment: I believe the first paragraph is not opinion based.

Comment: if you are writing a simple hello world or tutorial type program, it helps to **using namespace std** so long as no other library has cin or cout as types. No need to complicate tutorials with std::this std::that ....

Comment: Thank for your advice, I think I should raise a good habit from the beginning.

Comment: @DrDeo: I couldn't disagree more. I think the fact that textbooks seem to despise writing `std::` is the cause of this. It incepts that style into the minds of all our beginner programmers!

Comment: @DrDeo one could (or should?) argue that there is no need to introduce bad habits in tutorials without any good reason (other than lazyness)

Comment: `std::` is such a huge namespace with so many commonly used names that I would still recommend avoiding it in `.cpp` files, it can cause hard to find bugs even in begginer, example type problems.

Answer (score 3):

Imho this question is rather opinion based. However, this is my opinion:

Dont use:

```
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::string;
```

or the like. My argument is rather simple and is better demonstrated with

```
using std::sort;
using std::vector;
```

Imagine you have a code that contains a bug and now you are supposed to find it. Any object or function used, that has a `std::` in front is very very unlikely to contain a bug. Thus I always prefer to see a

```
std::vector<double> x;
std::sort(x);
```

instead of

```
vector<double> x;
sort(x);
```

because the latter requires me to look up what `vector` and `sort` actually is (remember we are talking C++, ie it could be literally anything), just to find out that it is `std::vector` and `std::sort`. Conclusion: The time I spend for writing `std::` each and every time saves me double or more time for debugging.

To make it a bit less opinion based: The definite trade-off you have to make is readability vs less typing. Opinion based is what you value more....

Comment: I think `coding-style` questions are all opinion based, however there are good ones and bad ones. Besides, almost all the code are opinion based, because code is the way to **the** answer, however there are many ways.

Comment: @buzhidao as I said, what imho is not opinion based is the advantage and disadvantges of one approach vs the other. Which one you choose is purely opinion based